# Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com

Tags: debate

Esta comunidade e este site são seus, são diferentes, são únicos. Aproveite! Nós nos preocupamos com a possibilidade do pessoal que já conhece o SO se sentir na obrigação de aplicar aqui as mesmas regras existentes no site em inglês, então vamos esclarecer: não tem porquê!

## Este site não é o caçulinha do Stack Overflow

Vocês são uma comunidade diferente, com necessidades diferentes… e agora com o *seu próprio site*. Ele é todo de vocês, então não se sintam na obrigação de adotar aqui as regras de um site grande e experiente como o SO. Vocês são uma comunidade com características próprias e que não tem porque copiar o caminho de uma outra. Além disso, lembrem-se que muitas das coisas proibidas hoje no SO um dia foram permitidas, e ajudaram o site a crescer e se fortalecer.

## O que faz bem para o *seu* site?

Nós acreditamos que o um escopo maior, englobando outros assuntos de interesse de desenvolvedores, pode fazer bem ao Stack Overflow em Português. Obviamente, cabe à comunidade decidir sobre que assuntos são permitidos aqui, mas pense nos benefícios de permitir alguns outros assuntos relacionados a programação. Durante o início do site, talvez seja interessante permitir os seguintes temas:

- Áreas relacionadas ao dia a dia de programadores, como **administração de sistemas, carreira profissional, tópicos gerais para profissionais de TI**.
- Questões conceituais, menos concretas, como design de software e metodologia de testes. Coisas que vão além da programação.
- Perguntas menos rígidas sobre boas práticas ou como aprender mais sobre um assunto. Desde que essas perguntas não envolvam somente discussões sobre opiniões pessoais. Questões amplas, não-específicas, não costumam dar certo no Stack Exchange.
- Pedidos de recomendação, com requisitos bem definidos, de ferramentas, bibliotecas, etc.
- Perguntas básicas de programação.
- Perguntas específicas demais, que só ajudariam a quem perguntou; Você decide o que quer responder, mas não há necessidade de remover essas perguntas do site.

## Isso não quer dizer que vale-tudo

Nós aprendemos bastante com o crescimento do Stack Overflow. Mesmo no começo foram vários os erros que cometemos, então aprendam com nossos erros e tentem não divergir muito do que a engine do Stack Exchange foi projetada para fazer (e não fazer). Por exemplo:

- **Qual seu quadrinho favorito de programação?** e outras perguntas parecidas garantiram boas risadas para um monte de programadores estressados, mas quando a diversão acabou, foi difícil se desfazer do hábito… Pessoas começaram a ganhar bastante reputação postando só brincadeiras, e as perguntas mais votadas não tinham nada a ver com programação. Quase ninguém se interessava em tomar conta desses posts, e ainda menos pessoas queriam ser responsáveis por apagá-los. No final de uma longa, penosa e rancorosa discussão, nós acabamos proibindo esse tipo de conteúdo.
- **Questões puramente subjetivas**, tipo “qual a melhor linguagem de programação”, raramente provém algum conteúdo útil.
- **Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow**, desde que elas beneficiem a *sua* comunidade. Tenha sempre em mente, porém, que traduções automatizadas ou mal escritas não são permitidas.

## Deixe para amanhã uma regra que você não precisa hoje

A infância de um site é um período divertido. Não há motivo para antecipar problemas, criando um monte de regras cedo demais, só porque elas existem no Stack Overflow em inglês. O SO tem o que nós chamamos de “problemas de cidade grande”, e tratar a sua comunidade recém-nascida como uma metrópole é bastante desgastante para todos, principalmente os novos usuários.

Talvez quando o SOPT chegar a 1 milhão de perguntas, vocês decidam que certas perguntas não valem a pena pelo pouco retorno que dão. E essa é a hora de usar o Meta. Se você vir algum comportamento começando a realmente atrapalhar o bom andamento do site, aí sim converse sobre o assunto com a comunidade. Tomara que um dia o SOPT se torne uma cidade grande… Até lá, é melhor curtir sua cidade pequena.

Via de regra, por enquanto é melhor permitir qualquer pergunta que satisfaça as seguintes condições:

- **Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?**
- **Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?**

Pra finalizar, aproveitem a liberdade de ser um site pequeno. Há toda uma vida pela frente pra se estressar com as coisas, então por enquanto sejam jovens!

Comment: Excelente! Rapaz, que coisa boa um SO em português. =)

Comment: O segundo subtítulo está escrito como: "O que é faz bem" -- não consigo propor edição aqui, mas acho que o "é" está sobrando ali.

Comment: Por que não podemos editar/sugerir edições aqui? Queria aplicar minhas habilidades de grammar nazi! :-)

Comment: Perfeito, é tudo o que eu gostaria de ver aqui no SOpt. Uma comunidade como o SO sem os erros deles que não conseguem mais ser sanados. @bfavaretto: Faça uma questão sobre isso! ;)

Comment: @bigown http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/21/por-que-nao-podemos-sugerir-edicoes-em-perguntas-e-respostas

Comment: Acredito que para estimular ainda mais, poderiam unificar a reputação, acho que seria melhor e mais motivador para continuar a colaboração tanto em inglês como em português.

Comment: Há, eu já tinha minhas dúvidas sobre *what's on-topic/what-did-you-try* com minha "mentalidade SO". Tudo azul então, é aproveitar a infancia e ir afinando!

Comment: Ainda não tenho permissão pra edição, então aqui vai:
"Vocês são uma comunidade **com** características" (2o. parágrafo); " **relacionados** " (3o. parágrafo)

Comment: Acho que *br.SO* é melhor do que *SOPT*

Comment: @DanielSerodio Valeu

Comment: @NetoMarin Não é viável unificar a reputação, são comunidades completamente diferentes, não só com outros usuários, mas critérios que não combinam. De uma certa forma até há unificação. Se você considerar sua reputação total na rede, ambas estão lá somadas (a reputação daqui estará em alguns dias). Mas se o que você deseja é ganhar reputação em uma comunidade e parecer que está bem ou ganhar privilégios na outra, isso definitivamente não beneficiaria nenhuma comunidade.

Comment: @NetoMarin Unificar as reputações foi discutido e não faz muito sentido... O que o bigown falou abrange grande parte dos motivos de não ter sido feito

Comment: Não concordo muito. Somos todos uma mesma comunidade, desenvolvedores, ou não ? Falar/escrever inglês é um skill que tenho e me permite ajudar tb no SO. Acredito que todo o trabalho que é feito aqui em PT (ou em EN), deve ser refletido nas outras redes. Por exemplo, quero ajudar a comunidade brasileira e vou dar prioridade para isso, mas seria interessante carregar essa reputação qnd estiver respondendo uma pergunta na SO en inglês.

Comment: @NetoMarin São sites diferentes, com comunidades diferentes, regras diferentes e nada garante que participar bem em um te gabarita a ser top user no outro. O mesmo vale para Math/MathOverflow,  ou qualquer outro conjunto de sites da rede que compartilhem o tema.

Comment: Parabéns pelo Stack BR. Só uma crítica, essa questão da pergunta estar em "Suspenso" acho desagradável, eu por exemplo entendi uma pergunta que quero responder mas ela está em suspenso por alguém que não entendeu e quer que o perguntador forneça mais detalhes.

Comment: @reinaldo o site ainda não tem um movimento muito alto... então pelo menos eu estou comentando e dando um tempo para que o usuário tenha a chance de melhorar a questão. Depois de uns minutos se não melhora eu voto para fechar... Entendo você perfeitamente, isso acontece muito seguido no [so], eu voto para reabrir e/ou tento ajudar como puder pelos comentários.

Comment: @DanielSerodio existem alguns países além de Portugal e Brasil que utilizam tal idioma (sem bem que tem dois países que eu não consigo entender o português deles de maneira alguma). Eu acredito que "BR" não se aplica, acho que os portugueses também fazem parte disto (mesmo que ao meu ver em menor porcentagem).

Comment: Excelente iniciativa fazer o forum em nossa língua. Nos facilita bastante. No que puder contribuir, podem contar comigo, embora saiba muito pouco.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você está certo, desculpe pelo "brasilcentrismo" :-)

Answer (score 14):

Creio que o conteúdo aqui descrito foi bem esclarecedor e nos leva a perceber que o crescimento do SOPT deve ser orgânico, e não algo baseado no SO, que é uma comunidade formada por pessoas diferentes. Não é só a língua que nos une, mas uma série de comportamentos e atitudes que são únicos.

Isso tudo me faz lembrar o motivo que me fez encontrar o SO. Não havia fóruns suficientemente maduros para encontrar ajuda. Os poucos que existiam estavam repletos de "sabichões": usuários prontos em mandar respostas do tipo: "procure no google" ou "vá pesquisar" ou então mandavam o link da documentação da API. Não há nada de errado em ler a documentação, mas claramente é uma resposta evasiva, de pouca utilidade. No SO encontrei colegas experts, prontos em dar respostas precisas e completas.

Creio que o grande trunfo disso tudo é a meritocracia: se você é um bom "respondedor", será reconhecido pela comunidade. O outro aspecto fundamental é a discussão livre e aberta. Isso é muito importante e é o que fará o site crescer de forma orgânica, natural.

Answer (score -9):

De forma alguma acho que devemos alargar o âmbito (escopo/scope).

Pego numa das frases da pergunta para justificar a minha opinião:

> Além disso, **lembrem-se que muitas das coisas proibidas hoje no SO um dia foram permitidas**, e ajudaram o site a crescer e se fortalecer.

Se passaram a ser proibidas por alguma razão foi: **bagunçada**!

Comment: O Stack Overflow hoje é um site maduro e gigantesco, com necessidades muito diferentes das que ele tinha 5 anos atrás. Não há nenhum tipo de garantia de que ele seria tão bem sucedido se abrisse imediatamente com todas as regras que possui hoje. A comunidade teve tempo de se adaptar às mudanças, e ver porque elas valiam a pena ser feitas. O processo foi orgânico e benéfico, ao invés de restritivo e impositivo logo de largada.

Comment: Por isso mesmo é que devemos aproveitar o que a experiência ensinou ao StackOverflow.com. Porquê inventar a roda se esta já foi inventada. Ninguém usa uma roda quadrada sabendo que uma redonda é que funciona bem!

Comment: O que devemos fazer é propostas para melhor o que o StackOverflow.com tem de menos bom e não propor aquilo que se sabe que não funcionou bem.

Comment: E você não sabe o que vai funcionar aqui. Funcionamento de comunidades não é uma ciência exata. Devemos colocar regras quando o problema ocorrer. Os problemas ocorridos lá podem não ocorrer aqui. E podemos ter problemas aqui que não existem lá. Uma roda de pedra funciona melhor em uma estrada de pregos. O que o SO nos ensinou, que podemos aplicar aqui, é que devemos começar abrangentes e ir restringindo aos poucos, conforme nossas necessidades.

Comment: Ok, talvez esteja a ser radical de mais. De qualquer forma espero que, ao postar uma opinião contrária, possa levar outros a tomarem partido e/ou expressarem as suas opiniões.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @ramaral deveriamos sim adotar as mesmas regras, pelo menos de início e remove-las, adapta-las ou criar mais à medida da necessidade. Do mesmo modo que o ramaral não sabe oquê vai funcionar aqui ninguém sabe, nem eu nem você. Usar regras maduras de um site madura seria um bom começo!

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Note que o que eu digo na resposta é que a mudança(proibição) se deve à bagunça e não que mudar é bagunça. Se o SO "voltou atrás com algumas decisões a respeito de proibição", nas circunstâncias que refere, vem confirmar a opinião subjacente à minha resposta : é melhor, mais tarde, mudar uma regra no sentido de liberar do que vir a ter que mudar para restringir.

Comment: Gostaria que o post do Gabe fosse escrito por uma conta tipo anonima userxyz com reputação bem baixinha que não fosse possível identifica-lo será que o post teria tantos adeptos as suas ideias...? Existe uma **tendência** não digo todos, mas talvez a maioria em ficar do lado de quem tem mais "autoridade" ou "pontuação", não sei, posso estar errado, mas, será que isso se passa só na minha cabeça ?

Comment: Parabens @ramaral sua resposta é sim útil, não sei porque esta sendo negativada, é um bom ponto de vista, é uma questão bem subjetiva onde ninguém pode dizer que esta errado ou certo, apenas que isso é uma possibilidade tão possível de dar certo quando a linha em que já estamos caminhando

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Os votos expressam acordo ou desacordo com a opinião passada na resposta, neste momento 7 concordam e 12 discordam.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta se é assim então estão  votando errado, não deveriam votar pensando se concordam ou discordam, votos refletem a **utilidade percebida**: as publicações bem escritas, bem fundamentadas e com boa pesquisa recebem mais atenção e mais votos a favor. Então volto a dizer estão votando olhando para o **eu** interior quando na verdade deve-se votar pensando na utilidade disso para com os outros.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA O que se aplica aqui é o parágrafo que começa com: "Ao contrário dos sites normais......."

Comment: Só no caso da tag recurso-solicitação ao meu entender

Comment: abri uma pergunta p/ tirar essa dúvida http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4788/votos-a-favor-e-votos-contra-o-que-o-voto-significa-para-voc%C3%AA