# Como construir o site que você quer ser quando crescer

Tags: debate

## Este é o seu site, e o seu Meta - Faça-os crescer

O Meta (onde você está agora) é o lugar onde você pode conversar e discutir sobre o seu site. Sobre o que ele precisa, como ajudá-lo a crescer, e como ele deve amadurecer.

### Precisamos mesmo do “Meta”?

Pessoas possuem uma habilidade incrível de se organizar, mesmo sem a existência de regras ou hierarquias formais. Faz parte da natureza humana. Quando você faz parte de um debate sobre de uma nova idéia, é possível notar pelo entusiasmo e energia de todos que aquele pode ser o início de algo importante. Algo que pode fazer a diferença.

Os novos sites no Stack Exchange não dependem somente das perguntas e respostas que são postadas. Dependem também de uma grande colaboração nos bastidores, quando a própria comunidade passa a se gerenciar. É aqui no Meta que isso acontece. Essa participação no Meta é especialmente importante para o nosso site, já que essa é a primeira vez que criamos um site para programadores que não falam inglês.

### Como eu posso ajudar?

**Adote sua comunidade - É a melhor forma de garantir que ela se torne útil e importante para os programadores de língua portuguesa.** Se alguma coisa boa aconteceu no site, elogie e incentive a todos no Meta, para que ocorra mais e mais vezes. Se você está preocupado com alguma coisa, pergunte no Meta o que os outros acham. A equipe do SE sempre vai ajudar, e compartilhar o que nós aprendemos até agora, mas o propósito desse site é construir um lugar dedicado a vocês, a comunidade de programadores de língua portuguesa. Todos que fazem parte do beta privado estão aqui porque nós acreditamos que vocês tem a motivação e habilidade de discutir sobre a comunidade, e encontrar boas soluções.

### Como construir um ótimo site:

Aqui vão algumas dicas sobre como começar com o pé direito, e criar um bom site:

- **Pergunte.**  Pode parecer besteira mas um dos principais desafios nos novos sites, mesmo com um bom grupo inicial de pessoas, é que muita gente está disposta a ajudar, mas ninguém faz perguntas. Parece um ótimo problema para se ter - contar com mais gente querendo ajudar do que precisando de ajuda - mas é algo que pode atrapalhar o crescimento do site. Então:

  - **Quando você tiver um problema, pergunte.**  Mesmo que você acabe descobrindo a resposta, vai ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema no futuro. Se possível, espere um dia para ver se alguém aparece com uma solução tão boa quanto a sua, se não acontecer, responda você mesmo.
  - **Faça perguntas sobre coisas que te deram dor de cabeça no passado.**  Lembre-se das vezes em que você simplemente não conseguiu encontrar uma boa resposta online para o seu problema, ou quando a resposta era incompleta e precisava de mais detalhes, e escreva sobre elas aqui.
  - **Quando em dúvida, poste. Pelo menos por enquanto.**  Nossos sites são ótimos para descobrir o que a comunidade pensa, através do voto e as discussões no Meta. Um problema que parecia besta (depois que você resolveu) pode estar acontecendo com outras milhares de pessoas, desesperadas por uma resposta. Você só vai saber o quão importante é o problema quando os votos começarem a aparecer.
- **Não se preocupe com problemas que não existem ainda**  Na dúvida, é melhor dar apoio e ver o que acontece. Dê uma olhada no post que fala sobre as [coisas que não são mais permitidas no Stack Overflow em inglês, mas que podem acontecer aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com). Não fique se preocupando com o pior ramificação possível de toda decisão...

Por enquanto, as principais preocupações são:

- **Essa pergunta vai ajudar outros programadores?** Se a resposta for sim então melhor que sejam permitidas, sempre observando os tipos de perguntas que continuam a ser benéficas para o site, e quais estão criando problemas.
- **Edite e encoraje.** Encoraje novos usuários sempre que possível. Se você vir um post incompleto, faltando algo que você saiba, evite só deixar um comentário falando que o post está errado. Se você tiver tempo, tente algo como: “Eu vi que faltavam alguns detalhes sobre os quais eu tenho conecimento, então eu editei o post para adicioná-los. Espero que ajude”. A qualidade dos posts é fundamental para o sucesso do site, então é preciso que os novos usuários sejam *encorajados* a sempre melhorar.

## Seja gentil e divirta-se!

Se o tempo que você passa no site não é prazeroso, alguma coisa está errada. Brinque, divirta-se e aproveite a satisfação de ajudar outros desenvolvedores. Vamos construir algo grandioso juntos.

Comment: Gabe, apesar se solicitar perguntas, temos que ter 5 pontos de reputação pra começar. Já tenho 26 em outros sites SE, não podem vir a se aplicar, pra dar um ponta-pé inicial?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti eu ganhei um bônus de 100 pela reputação nos outros sites, talvez você precise de mais reputação neles pra ganhar aqui também. De qq forma, respostas podem ser dadas sem reputação nenhuma, eu acho.

Comment: @VitorDeMario aqui embaixo dos nossos comentários diz que precisa de 5 pontos, checa ali. =) EDIT: talvez não apareça pra você que tem os pontos suficientes pra isso.

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Você precisa de 5 de reputação pra postar no Meta, mas não no site principal.

Comment: Quem tem reputação de pelo menos 200 em qualquer outro site da rede recebe automaticamente 100 pontos para começar em um site em outro site.

Comment: "Não se preocupe com problemas que não existem ainda" -- boa! :)