# Tradução de perguntas e FAQs

Tags: suporte, faq, tradução

Qual política deveremos adotar quanto a tradução de perguntas "famosas" ou mesmo pertencentes aos FAQs do SO.com original?

Como por exemplo: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c
entre outras do tag [c++-faq]?

Devemos pro ativamente começar a traduzir?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Eu acho que tem gente que gosta de ter os nomes cheio de pontinhos de reputação. As pessoas se acham mais importantes por terem mais pontos que os outros. Por outro lado os pontos fazem com que as pessoas respondam rápido as perguntas que é uma coisa muito boa.

Comment: Se a pessoa criar a pergunta, colocar a fonte do SO e responder a própria pergunta não teria problema.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A questão é passar para todo mundo a intenção correta...

Não podemos dizer que todos devem "ativamente começar a traduzir" perguntas do SO, senão rapidinho a página inicial fica repleta de perguntas basicas/famosas/bem-votadas do site original, e isso não é bom. Primeiro porque dessa forma nós não estamos criando o *nosso* site, e segundo porque isso cria um ambiente muito pouco amistoso para quem está chegando... Já que as perguntas "verdadeiras" acabam sumindo no site em meio a um monte de perguntas famosas.

Ao mesmo tempo, existem toneladas de ótimos conteúdos no SO, que seriam realmente benéficos ao SOPT e que gostaríamos de vê-los aqui. Então se você acha que uma pergunta (tipo a que o hexa citou) faria bem ao site, pode traduzir à vontade. Sempre lembrando que nada de tradução automática.

Comment: Concordo contigo, e com a resposta do @bfavaretto. Mas é inevitável que algum desavisado acorde amanhã e resolva que vai ganhar rep com perguntas clássicas. Como será então?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Vai depender de cada caso... Se alguém decidir que vai passar a vida criando traduções excepcionais de perguntas boas e que estão ajudando um monte de programadores que falam português, então ótimo.

Comment: Concordo em número, gênero e grau!

Answer (score 15):

Também me pergunto isso. No ["post inaugural"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com) aqui do meta, Gabe diz:

> **Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow**, desde que elas beneficiem a *sua* comunidade

Porém, há uma opinião contrária em [uma discussão recente na Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12451/is-it-ok-to-translate-my-questions-answers-from-so-and-post-in-so-in-portuguese):

> In the long run, I think it's perfectly acceptable to translate not only yours but other people's questions too. However, in the beta phase (especially in the private beta) it's important to focus on expert questions and actual, real-world problems. IMHO simply cataloging popular questions, no matter how useful they are, will do little to create a healthy community.

<strike>Eu pessoalmente acho bom que certas perguntas frequentes entrem no site desde já. Não acho que isso vá influir negativamente na "saúde" do beta.</strike>

**Estou em dúvida se ainda concordo com o que eu disse no parágrafo acima...**

Answer (score 10):

Eu acho que a **fase Beta**, principalmente a privada deveria ser usada para um crescimento mais orgânico e essas perguntas deveriam ser evitadas. Depois eu não vejo tantos problemas, se as perguntas forem muito boas e respeitem os critérios mostrados em outras respostas.

O único benefício **nesse momento** é o usuário ganhar reputação fácil.

O malefício é que rapidamente vamos encher o site de questões que podem não ser o que ESTA comunidade está precisando e procurando.

Acho que em algum momento isso pode ser mais aceito, no momento esse tipo de ação pode levar a comunidade para um caminho errado.

Não estou dizendo que deva ser proibido mas apenas apelando aos usuários que evitem isso no começo. Quem conhece o nascimento de outros sites da rede sabe que isso pode ser prejudicial.

**Nós não precisamos crescer artificialmente!**

Afinal [você vai construir o site que deseja](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-construir-o-site-que-voce-quer-ser-quando-crescer)

Obviamente é apenas minha opinião pessoal e não tenho problemas se a comunidade decidir ir por outro caminho.

**Edição:**
Estou cada vez mais propenso a aceitar questões **muito boas** vindas do SO original. O maior problema que vejo depois de algumas postagens é que estão traduzindo perguntas muito básicas.

Comment: Discordo da ideia de que o único benefício seja o usuário ganhar reputação fácil. Se a pergunta/resposta original tem qualidade, e a tradução está bem feita, é bem alta a probabilidade de que o conteúdo irá ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Além disso você pode postar uma tradução como wiki da comunidade, e assim não vai aumentar a reputação.

Comment: @elias Note que eu disse *nesse momento*. Pode colocar como wiki mas deveria? Nem sempre é o ideal. E as pessoas vão fazer isso para ganhar reputação. Você é experiente e sabe disso.

Comment: Então, mas ainda assim não vejo problema que as pessoas ganhem reputação com isso. Como já falei na minha resposta, acho que traduzir é positivo, basta respeitar o original e que a tradução seja completa o suficiente para ser útil.

Comment: Acho mais problemático as perguntas populistas (piadas, "qual é melhor?", etc) do que traduções úteis de assuntos técnicos.

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta que você citou agora já é ponto pacífico, elas não podem em nenhum site da rede e continuará não podendo aqui. Elas tem qualidade muito baixa. Veja a terceira seção: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com

Comment: Sim, estou a par. Quis dizer que ainda é um "perigo" importante, mais do que traduções de perguntas para ganhar reputação.

Answer (score 9):

Entendo que a autoresposta e transcrição de outras línguas seria uma forma de iniciarmos o site com um bom material e já servindo de referência para os novos usuários, mas na prática percebo que algumas pessoas estão pegando perguntas às vezes até mal formuladas e colando a resposta logo em seguida sem muita preocupação com a relevância.

Acho que já que é pra pessoa fazer "farming" de pontuação, deveria ao menos fazê-lo com qualidade. Além disso imagino que é razoável que a pessoa dê ao menos um intervalo de tempo para a autoresposta, para que outros da comunidade possam ter tempo de dar uma resposta original e pensada, que na prática pode ter até mais qualidade por não ser enlatada.

Finalmente sugeriria aos colegas que nesse período inicial revisassem os votos já dados nesses casos, pois às vezes a autoresposta está bem votada por diferença de tempo e não por qualidade tão superior assim. Melhor o quanto antes desincentivar o mau uso.

Answer (score 7):

Não vejo problema em perguntas traduzidas, e vejo até como positivo traduzir pró-ativamente.

Mas acho legal que se observe o seguinte:

- **Respeitar a fonte**: é bom que tenha um link pra pergunta/resposta original, não simplesmente por crédito, mas para que seja fácil de rastrear atualizações, por exemplo.
- **Traduzir a resposta completamente**: não é legal traduzir pela metade e jogar um link que o OP precise seguir e entender pra que a resposta ser útil. É bom que as respostas sejam auto-contidas, a ideia é que o site ajude quem tem problemas com o inglês.

Talvez uma forma simples de respeitar a pergunta/resposta original seja postá-la como *wiki da comunidade*, assim você deixa clara a intenção de ajudar, todo mundo se sente livre para fazer correções e você não vai ganhar pontos "de graça" por isso. =)

Answer (score 4):

Apoio a proposta de **não incentivarmos tradução**.

Já estou vendo várias perguntas simples (que o autor parece já saber a resposta), mas que ajudarão estudantes e programadores iniciantes.
Não vejo motivo para traduzirmos mais perguntas simples.

Voltando a questão das traduções, me preocupo por considerar isso uma forma artificial de gerarmos conteúdo.
Meu medo é depois isso passar a ser geração artificial de reputação (como o brasileiro tem costume de abusar nas redes sociais, adicionando amigos que nem conhece).

Do que adianta dizer que não somos stackoverflow.com, e citar o tempo todo que tal conteúdo foi extraído de lá?

Comment: Tentei evitar falar do jeitinho brasileiro, mas é isso mesmo :)

Comment: Lembrando aqui que não tem nada de errado em alguém perguntar uma coisa que já sabe a resposta, inclusive o SO *encoraja* você a responder suas próprias perguntas. O argumento de "geração artificial" não me parece convincente, todo site começa com um pouco de conteúdo artificial. Além disso, os brasileiros são gente boníssima, nosso problema não é abusados, mas ter auto-estima baixa. =)

Comment: Não questiono em nenhum momento a capacidade do brasileiro. Por acreditar nesse potencial, prefiro apoiar um crescimento natural. Não adianta a gente querer adicionar linguiça, pra inglês ver. Não sou muito a favor de perguntas auto-respondidas quando começam a parecer traduções de livros didáticos. Quando são questões que demandaram muito sacrifício e conhecimento do autor, eu apoio, pois essas são aquelas difíceis de encontrar na internet.

Comment: Entendo, mas acho que o site não precisa ser um repositório somente de informações raras e valiosas. Reparando no uso do SO, você pode notar que frequentemente ele é útil simplesmente por ter a pergunta elaborada de uma maneira mais fácil de encontrar via Google, mesmo para coisas que seriam relativamente fáceis de achar na documentação no site oficial (pelo menos, para quem sabe o caminho).

Comment: Concordo, é comum a informação mais simples demandar o maior sacrifício. Também entendo que isso é subjetivo, pois o que é valioso para um, para outro é comum. A questão é: essa informação surgiu por meios naturais ou artificiais?