# Perguntas/respostas traduzidas devem conter link para o conteúdo original?

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas, proposta-para-faq

Devemos cobrar os links em respostas/perguntas traduzidas do SO em inglês, ou deixemos isso à escolha do autor da mesma?

Comment: Sim se realmente a pessoa vai fazer isso, eu particularmente evitaria isso por agora: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs/23#23

Answer (score 12):

Na minha opinião, sim, especialmente se for uma tradução mesmo, e não adaptação livre da pergunta ou resposta original. Os próprios termos da licença CC devem exigir isso em caso de tradução.

Também acho positivo haver links para perguntas relacionadas no SO, mesmo que a daqui não seja uma tradução.

Ver também: [Tradução de perguntas e FAQs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs)

Comment: Exatamente. Infelizmente nós não temos como avaliar todos os posts, checando por traduções, então se você encontrou alguma coisa que viu ser traduzida, sinta-se à vontade para editar e adicionar a fonte.