# É correto responder uma pergunta no SOpt com uma tradução de uma boa resposta no SOen?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, proposta-para-faq

Acabei de dar esta reposta: [Como tratar requisições Ajax com erro de negócio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43842/como-tratar-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ajax-com-erro-de-neg%C3%B3cio/43845#43845)

Gostaria de saber se é correto fazer basicamente uma tradução de uma boa reposta no SOen para o SOpt.

Comment: Acho que não tem problema, desde que seja feita uma referência para o conteúdo original.

Comment: Relacionado: [Perguntas/respostas traduzidas devem conter link para o conteúdo original?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25/91) e [crossposting](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1072/91)

Comment: De acordo com a resposta aceita [nesta pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs), dada por um moderador, vejo que não há problemas em traduzir, desde que citada a fonte.

Answer (score 4):

Já o fiz algumas vezes, particularmente no inicio do SOpt (Beta Privado), mas num modo geral, não existe diferença entre responder com base numa resposta do SOEN ou com base numa resposta de um outro site qualquer.

Se o conteúdo já existente lida bem com o problema colocado no SOpt, não temos que estar a "inventar" uma resposta nova.

O importante é atribuir sempre o devido crédito à fonte da nossa resposta, não esquecendo que a resposta deve conter o que é necessário para que ao ser lida apresente a solução para o problema em mãos.

No tópico referido nos comentários da pergunta, este assunto é aprofundado:

[Perguntas/respostas traduzidas devem conter link para o conteúdo original?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/25/223)

Ver também:

[Tradução de perguntas e FAQs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/223)