# O que você pensa sobre a tradução de perguntas do Stack Overflow em Inglês?

Tags: debate

A lot of thanks to [@Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/357/piovezan) for the translation.

---

Como falantes não-nativos de inglês, nós tendemos a trabalhar com duas bases de conhecimento quando procuramos por uma resposta: uma em português e outra em inglês. Quando usamos sites de Q&A em inglês, cada um de nós cria suas próprias traduções de uma forma ou de outra. Não achamos isso o ideal. Para evitar fazer o mesmo trabalho diversas vezes, podemos compartilhar com as pessoas nossas traduções adicionando-as manualmente para a base de conhecimento em português se... a comunidade achar essa iniciativa útil.

*Por favor, compartilhe com a comunidade o que você acha de traduzir perguntas do Stack Overflow em Inglês e adicioná-las ao Stack Overflow em Português.*

Se acha que a comunidade *não irá* se beneficiar de ter traduções, por favor compartilhe com a comunidade por que você pensa assim. Se você pensa que ter mais perguntas em idioma português irão ajudar alguns de seus colegas a entender melhor os materiais, por favor compartilhe sua opinião sobre isso também.

**(Comentário traduzido):**

@Maniero obrigado pelos links. Eu não vi essas discussões acontecerem anteriormente. Meu ponto era quase sumarizar esse tipo de discussões e adicionar um novo artigo na central de ajuda que explique o que a comunidade pensa sobre traduções, quando é ok traduzir, e quando não é. Poderia por favor me dizer se a comunidade precisa disso e de que forma? Eu tenho um modelo para isso que eu posso compartilhar em uma resposta aqui, se você quiser.

---

Texto original:

As not native English speakers we tend to work with two knowledge bases when we look for an answer: one in Portuguese and another in English. When we use Q&As in English, each of us creates their own translations in one form or another. I don’t think this is optimal. To avoid doing the same work multiple times, we can share with folks our translations by manually adding them to the knowledge base in Portuguese if ... the community finds such an initiative useful.

*Please, share with the community what you think about translating questions from Stack Overflow in English and adding them to Stack Overflow in Portuguese.*

If you think that the community will *not* benefit from having translations, please share with the community why you think this way. If you think that having more questions in the Portuguese language will help some of your colleagues understand materials better, please share your thoughts on this matter as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly are proposing here. Automatically? Mannually but actively (as a call to action)? Organically? We already do: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/101 and https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/125/101 and https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/25/101. Are you proposing something new?

Comment: Também achei o tópico bem indefinido. Hoje já é feito a "tradução" de perguntas do SOen para o SOpt quando há demanda e a discussão é interessante para nós. São públicos distintos, com interesses distintos, não vejo muito sentido em fazer algo do gênero além do que já é feito; caso contrário, bastaria ter apenas uma comunidade com ferramentas de internacionalização decentes. Isso evitaria conteúdos duplicados, visto que seria o mesmo conteúdo traduzido.

Comment: Já é, de certa forma, dispendioso para a comunidade ter que ficar traduzindo as publicações no Meta que são discussões simples, imagina ter que traduzir ainda perguntas avulsas vindas do SOen. Ao meu ver isso só abrirá brecha para poluir a comunidade com conteúdo porcamente traduzido, com o risco de estar traduzido errado, e possivelmente sem demanda. Resumindo, desnecessário.

Comment: E ainda tem o "ponto" de que uma boa pergunta, que mereça ser traduzida, talvez já tenha uma resposta. E esse resposta dada na pergunta do SOen tb deve vir para o SOpt traduzida? Como fica os "direitos autorais", será que eu mereço ganhar esses pontos só por ter traduzido uma questão bem pontuada, mas que eu nem ao menos domino o assunto? O que evitaria das pessoas trazerem uma avalanche de perguntas (e respostas) apenas com fins de acumularem pontos?? Eu particularmente sou contra essa iniciativa, pelo menos até o momento...

Comment: Tem ideias existentes lá que eu sou a favor de serem migradas, como pode exemplo o [guia definitivo de autenticação baseado em formulário](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/4056678) (por conta das diversas perguntas que temos sobre o tema). Mas, traduzir pergunta só por traduzir e ter o mesmo conteúdo em comunidades diferentes com o único diferencial da linguagem, acho desnecessário. Lembrando que [aqui não é o stackoverflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/4808), #pas. 

Comment: (Please excuse me for using English) @Maniero thank you for the links. I have not seen those discussions before. My point was almost to summarise these kind of discussions and add a new help center article that explains what the community thinks about translations, when it's okay to translate, and when it's not. Could you please tell me if the community needs that and in what form? I have a template for it which I can share in an answer here, if you would like.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky All content could be useful.

Comment: @Maniero Sorry for clarifying. Could you please tell me if you mean that I should suggest a template for the new help center article?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky You can send here this template to us. Community could analyze and decide.

Comment: I still don't get what is the objective that this tries to achieve. Anyway, whatever is the proccess that you are suggesting to use (or hope someone to suggest), would either: (a) Produce those horribly automatically-translated documents that I see in some sites (like Microsoft docs of their APIs) that are so awful, that I have to switch back to English to actually make sense of anything written there. (b) Demand a lot of people to manually translate a lot of things and that is a big non-no because we have plenty of other more interesting things to do.

Comment: @VictorStafusa it seems to me that the objective is this to know what we (community) think about translations, to document it. This doesn't mean that something will be done regarding to the translations itself, but at current moment just understand and compile our community view about the subject in the official documentation. Can you confirm, @Nicolas? Also, I [think this comment](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7637/what-do-you-think-about-translating-questions-from-stack-overflow-in-english#comment29508_7637) should be adapted (if needed) and inserted in the question itself.

Comment: Por que todos estão falando em inglês? Viramos o meta em ingles agora? Estou tentando acompanhar a discussao, até pra criar uma opiniao propria a respeito, ja que nem a pergunta ta no meu idioma ne, mas o maximo que posso ler é até o comentario do renan.

Comment: @Bacco Thank you. This is the exact reason for the question. Other international sites have discussed it already, except SOja, where [the question had been raised for the first time](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2930/78), and either [added a help center article with the consensus on translations](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english) or [working the article right now](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3911/10).

Comment: If SOpt against the idea of translating questions from English, please put it in an answer to this question.

Comment: @ArticunoL posso falar por mim apenas: eu estava aguardando entender a idéia para saber como traduzir corretamente, para evitar retrabalho.

Answer (score 7):

Nada contra a tradução de conteúdo, desde que seja feita por demanda e não forçada.

A princípio a pergunta parecia sugerir que houvesse um movimento de tradução em massa de perguntas do SOen para o SOpt. Isso eu seria completamente contra. Somente nos comentários que se fez claro que a discussão é focada na necessidade ou não de se criar uma central de ajuda sobre o assunto. Isso sou a favor.

Não é raro termos que pesquisar no SOen por algo inexistente no SOpt e nesses casos sou a favor de trazer o conteúdo para cá em português. Houve demanda, então há justificativa para fazer a migração de conteúdo. Ter uma página que padronize o processo será bem-vinda.

Pontos que devem ser abordados:

- **A tradução deve ser feita sobre demanda.** Precisou de algo, não achou no SOpt mas achou no SOen? Beleza, fique livre para traduzir o conteúdo para português. Se você precisou, outros podem precisar. Não faça o processo apenas para ganhar pontos de reputação, isso tenderá a poluir a comunidade com perguntas/respostas avulsas e sem demanda.
- **Domínio do conteúdo.** Se o usuário não possui domínio do conteúdo, vejo ser mais indicado ele não fazer a tradução; não de respostas, pelo menos. A pergunta, por ele já ter pesquisado, provavelmente terá maior conhecimento sobre o problema em questão, o que geralmente implica que ele conseguirá traduzir a pergunta de forma adequada. Respostas devem ser traduzidas apenas quando houver domínio do conteúdo.

  - Em casos de tradução apenas da pergunta, será interessante o tradutor adicionar o link para a pergunta original no outro idioma, assim quem for responder terá uma base a mais de pesquisa e evitará retrabalho, podendo até permitir que outros usuários façam a devida tradução de respostas úteis no outro idioma.
- **A tradução não deve ser feita, sempre, *ipsis litteris*.** Mesmo que a área seja técnica e que comumente seja utilizado um linguajar mais técnico, diferentes idiomas possuem diferentes vícios de linguagem. Em certos momentos isso já é visto mesmo entre o pt-BR e o pt-PT, imagina entre em português e inglês. Se for traduzir, localize os termos também.
- **Muito cuidado ao traduzir respostas.** Pois traduzir respostas demandam muito mais domínio do assunto do que traduzir perguntas. Você obrigatoriamente precisará conseguir avaliar quais são respostas boas e quais são respostas ruins - e é importante lembrar que nem sempre quantidade de votos reflete qualidade. Também é desnecessário traduzir todas as respostas; uma resposta que englobe todos os pontos positivos (e às vezes pontos negativos) de todas as respostas no outro idioma será suficiente. Ou seja, sintetize (o que também demandará domínio do conhecimento). Ficou na dúvida, não traduza.
- **Seja ético.** Por mais que será você que ganhará (em reputação) com a tradução, não foi você o autor do conteúdo. Dê sempre os devidos créditos àqueles que se inicialmente se empenharam para elaborar a pergunta e respostas. Inclusive sempre deixe o link para as publicações originais. Novos conteúdos podem aparecer no tópico mesmo após a discussão.
- **Na dúvida, questione.** Para evitar que perguntas ruins sejam traduzidas e até fechadas na comunidade em português, busque ter certeza do que está fazendo antes de fazê-lo. Se tem dúvidas se o conteúdo/formato é pertinente para a nossa comunidade, pergunte! Existe o Meta e o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) que podem ser utilizados para isso. Lembre-se, por mais que sejamos da mesma rede, Stack Overflow em Português [NÃO É o Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/5878). São regras distintas com demandas distintas. Só porque uma pergunta/resposta foi bem aceita lá não significa que será bem aceita aqui.

Comment: (Sorry for using English) Thank you a lot for the answer! It's awesome! Could you please tell me if you can process it (if it's needed) to make a new help center article out of the answer? Could you look at [an initial draft for the help center article](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3911/6) that has been posted on SOes (in English) as well. I think if you compile the most important items from both posts the SOpt community will get a really great article. What do you think?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Better wait for other opinions. Having one or two more answers would be very interesting.

Comment: Thank you! Let's wait then.