# Este site está atendendo os critérios do licenciamento do nosso conteúdo?

Tags: debate, conteúdo, licença

Descobri [esse site](https://itqna.net/) por acaso.  Alguns exemplos de perguntas que estão lá:

- https://itqna.net/questions/22887/what-difference-between-tolistasync-and-tolist
- https://itqna.net/questions/17588/differences-between-name-and-qualname

Olhando por cima já percebo:

- Possuem respostas sem crédito para quem respondeu.
- Está em outra língua.
- Não há *link* para o conteúdo original.

O que acham? Devemos tomar providências?

Comment: Com certeza viola a licença. Tem uma opção pra denunciar isso no /contact, mas daí até algo ser feito é um longo caminho. Será que existiria outro caminho de notificar esse site sem ser via SE?

Comment: Parece uma replica exata do SO, mas ainda em fase inicial

Comment: E as [imagens de JOIN que eles "kibaram"](https://itqna.net/questions/4/what-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) eu fiz no Photoshop (as tabelas exemplo em ascii)  EDIT: Pior ainda, é hotlink! As imagens estão vindo do stack  imgur

Comment: Acho que era preocupante se nos tivesse a roubar utilizadores, assim não passa mais de um site que ninguém liga.

Comment: O [domínio](https://br.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=itqna.net) está registrado no [NameSilo](http://www.namesilo.com). E há contatos para denúncias de abuso:  Email: abuse@namesilo.com e Phone: +1.4805240066. Talvez seria uma alternativa de denúncia?

Comment: @danieltakeshi Acho que somente a SE consegue fazer isso, se for o caso.

Comment: Ao não publicarem a fonte do conteúdo publicado estão violando os termos descritos nos [Termos de Uso da API](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) **Atribuição da API**
Todos os aplicativos devem garantir que eles visualmente indiquem que a Stack Exchange Network é a fonte do conteúdo fornecido pelos Serviços de API. Os aplicativos que podem, de qualquer forma, ser indexados pelos mecanismos de pesquisa devem seguir todas as regras de atribuição definidas nos Termos de Serviço do Stack Exchange...

Comment: Também ferem os direitos dos dos usuários que estão protegidos pela licença [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/br/) (CC BY-SA) **Atribuição** — Você deve dar o crédito apropriado, prover um link para a licença e indicar se mudanças foram feitas. Você deve fazê-lo em qualquer circunstância razoável, mas de nenhuma maneira que sugira que o licenciante apoia você ou o seu uso.
**CompartilhaIgual** — Se você remixar, transformar, ou criar a partir do material, tem de distribuir as suas contribuições sob a mesma licença que o original.

Answer (score 11):

Fiz a notificação oficial à SE sobre o assunto já que está bastante claro que há violação. Recebi a resposta:

> Hi Maniero,
>
> Thank you for reporting this content. I've passed the information
>   along to the person at our company who handles such issues. It's the
>   diligence of users like you that helps us stay valuable!
>
> Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to
>   no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You
>   may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're
>   working on it.
>
> Due to the nature of this request and the amount of time it takes to
>   process them, it is unlikely that you will receive any further
>   follow-up emails regarding this issue.   Regards, Stack Overflow Team

---

Tradução em Português Brasileiro (por CypherPotato):

> *Olá Maniero,*
>
> *Obrigado por denunciar este conteúdo. Passei essa informação para o setor da*
>   *empresa que lida com estes problemas. É por pessoas como você que nos ajudam*
>   *a manter o site valioso!*
>
> *Por favor, note que levar estes sites à processos (ou fazendo-os deixar de*
>   *usar nosso conteúdo) é um processo longo e difícil. Você provavelmente não*
>   *verá resultados imediatos. Entretanto, estamos trabalhando nisso.*
>
> *Devido à natureza desta solicitação e o tempo que ela leva para ser concluída, é*
>   *improvável que você receberá alguma resposta por e-mail ressaltando essa denúncia.*
>
> *Saudações, Equipe Stack Overflow.*

Comment: Você tem a ideia de quanto tempo que outros casos similares levaram para ser solucionados?

Comment: @AugustoVasques  Não, mas tem uma quantidade enorme de coisas que não recebemos resposta. O único assunto que interessa pra SE atualmente é se as pessoas estão usando o pronome que meia dúzia de pessoas deseja que usem com ela. Os assuntos do site mesmo tá bem difícil e não muda, só piora.

Comment: Eu vi, para eliminarem a conta do usuário que na pergunta informou que "seus pronomes de preferência são ele e ela" foi uma ação quase imediata. Perguntei sobre o tempo pois como todo brasileiro sou frustrado com a demora do sistema legal com relação as minhas requisições, pelo menos uma vez na vida gostaria que algo que também me afligisse fosse resolvido em um prazo crível.

Comment: Você não tem ideia ideia da quantidade de fraudes que reportamos e que não temos informação suficiente para tomar uma ação e não recebemos resposta, nem mesmo para dizer que está tudo ok e não é fraude (só mandamos quando temos quase certeza, mas falta um aval extra para evitar uma punição equivocada), enquanto isso um monte de gente tem conseguido voto em postagens ruins porque tem uma conta pra ajudar.

Comment: Esse desamparo da rede com relação as fraudes afasta os usuários especializados. Pois de que adianta fazer uma pesquisa e elaborar uma resposta bibliograficamente respaldada e receber alguns upvotes orgânicos quando um texto qualquer recebe uma dezena de upvotes meio fraude. A Rede tem que olhar com mais atenção para os verdadeiros usuários, tanto os que publicam quanto os que consomem o conteúdo publicado aqui.

Answer (score 6):

Muito obrigado a [@Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/woss) pela tradução.

---

<sup>[Versão original (inglês)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8008/1)</sup>

Na minha opinião, este site viola a licença. Relatei o ocorrido aos meus colegas. Espero que os autores do site levem nossa licença em consideração em breve.

Por outro lado, sou cético em relação a sites com conteúdo traduzido automaticamente em geral. O site que você mencionou obviamente usa o mesmo software que o `qaru.site`, que há muito tempo entope a internet em russo com textos gerados automaticamente ([eu escrevi sobre isso antes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7637/)). Este caso é uma nova iteração de destruição: os autores do site criam traduções automáticas na direção oposta, de idiomas internacionais para o inglês. Eu acho que o significado permanece o mesmo - esses sites não são suportados, uma sobrecarga de textos não atualizados é gerada, não há objetivo de criar valor humano.

Por exemplo, veja como é o `qaru.site` com o Adblock desativado no meu laptop

[image]

Como somos confrontados com traduções do português para o inglês, as traduções do russo para outros idiomas provavelmente aparecerão em breve. Pessoalmente, não quero que [o conhecimento que eu criei](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=answers) seja distorcido pela tradução automática, transformado em algum tipo de spam, bombardeado com publicidade, porque esse conteúdo obstrui os resultados da pesquisa para outros desenvolvedores, dificultando a resposta para uma pergunta de programação. Independentemente da licença.

*Por favor, compartilhe o que você pensa sobre isso?*

Relacionada:

- [Should we block posting links to sites with machine translated content?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8007/17539)