# Uma feature de tradução semelhante ao Quora seria útil?

Tags: novo-recurso, tradução

Quem conhece o Quora sabe que é possível traduzir respostas de uma língua para outra. Isso pode ser muito útil e evitar perguntas duplicadas, reaproveitando o conhecimento de uma plataforma em outra. Além disso, sabemos que o conteúdo em inglês é muito mais rico. Gostaria de sugerir uma feature semelhante, onde uma pergunta e a resposta escolhida como resposta-padrão pudessem ser traduzidas do SO-EN para o SO-PT. Alguns detalhes precisariam ser avaliados, como marcar a tradução caso o original sofresse alterações, citar a pergunta original, etc. O que vocês acham disso?

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7637/112052, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/112052, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/125/112052 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/25/112052

Answer (score 3):

Não gosto da ideia, sei de muita gente que não gosta, e mais ou menos já foi discutido isto. Não vejo vantagem. Quando o conteúdo é muito bom é possível a pessoa fazer um parzinho de pergunta e resposta, mas o ideal é que não seja tradução literal e principalmente automática, seria melhor dar uma adaptada, melhorar o conteúdo, juntar partes, enfim, deixar mais com cara pro nosso público. Não recomendo as pessoas saírem traduzindo sem parar coisas sem esforço, especialmente só pra ganhar pontos, precisa ser algo que valha a pena com critério.

Acho que deve ler isto: [Central de Ajuda: Posso traduzir conteúdo de outro site no SOpt? Como?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7679/77665).