# É util fazer perguntas que geram conteúdo para a net?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq

Todos sabemos que os robots dos motores de busca "andam por aí".

Vale a pena fazer boas perguntas (justando ou não a resposta directamente) para gerar conteúdo em português, que por sua vez irá atraír mais utilizadores?

Ou é melhor deixar o site crescer naturalmente, com as perguntas que vão surgindo por necessidade da comunidade e das dúvidas dos utilizadores existentes?

Comment: pergunta capciosa essa. Não tenho resposta suficientemente embasada, mas estou ansioso por ver as manifestações. Se posso sugerir um edit na pergunta, queres escrever "robôs" em português, "robots" em inglês, ou "bots" pros algoritmos que ficam "andando por aí"?=)

Comment: Ainda outro comentário. Por "fazer perguntas para gerar conteúdo em português" você implica em saber a resposta e responder a própria pergunta, ou quer dizer que é interessante perguntar perguntas boas (que não são necessariamente pertinentes ao autor), ainda que não sabendo a resposta?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti, exacto. Ambas as situações. Vou editar para ser mais claro. Mas no fundo fazer perguntas, ainda que boas, movido por gerar conteudo e nem sempre por não saber a resposta. Essa é a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mais ou menos já respondi [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs/23#23).

Se a pergunta é muito boa, eu acho até que pode ser útil. Um dos problemas que vejo é que estão trazendo perguntas, até úteis, mas bobas para problemas já resolvidos em português. Não digo que nunca possa trazer essas perguntas para cá, mas acho melhor não encher delas no começo. Isso pode passar a imagem errada.

Algo que se pode perguntar é o seguinte: Essa resposta (solução para esse problema) não existe em português se der uma busca rápida? Se não existir, é uma boa candidata, se existir, para que trazer pra cá artificialmente ou fingir que é uma pergunta legítima? Só para ganhar reputação.

Podemos ter questões mais básicas, mas acho que não precisa trazê-las artificialmente nesse primeiro momento.

Se isso virar mais um site cheio de perguntas bobas como tem em muitos lugares, para que foi criado então? Não precisamos de mais um lugar para trocar conhecimento de qualquer jeito, precisamos de algo diferente que só o SO pode dar.

No futuro você tentar que aqui tenha sempre o primeiro link do Google em qualquer busca sobre programação, eu não só apoio, mas digo que é o objetivo de toda a rede do SE.

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei responder à própria pergunta é completamente normal e, se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo é algo até incentivado pelo sistema. Ver [este post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Esse tipo de ação serve como uma espécie de documentação de um problema que foi resolvido pela própria pessoa, caso a informação esteja de acordo com o conteúdo do site, agregue valor e seja útil para outras pessoas.

Note que ao fazer uma pergunta há um *check* com os dizeres "Responder sua própria pergunta – compartilhe seu conhecimento, no estilo de perguntas e respostas".

Comment: acontece que isso, nesse momento, pode virar uma forma de conseguir pontos de reputação facilmente. Isso é bom ou ruim?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Se as perguntas e respostas forem boas elas ganharão pontos naturalmente com os votos dos usuários. Se forem ruins, elas deveriam ser fechadas e o usuário perderia pontos com votos negativos.