# O que faremos com conteúdo de terceiros postado sem a devida citação?

Tags: debate, conteúdo, autoria

Dando desdobramento ao discutido no post [Tradução de perguntas e FAQs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs), se uma postagem for feita que é cópia ou tradução de um conteúdo já existente, devemos ter alguma ação?

- Faz diferença se foi pego em nossa língua ou traduzido de outra língua?
- Se for pego de uma pergunta ou resposta do SO original ou outro site da rede? É pior se for resposta?
- Deve haver exceção se a pessoa que está postando aqui é o autor original?
- Se a cópia for integral, basta ter a citação?
- No caso de alguém achar algum problema, qual a ação mais apropriada a ser tomada?
- E se o usuário insistir em continuar postando conteúdo sem citação, evidenciando que ultrapassou o erro de boa fé?

Algumas informações úteis:

Post no blog oficial sobre o [licenciamento do conteúdo](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/) de toda rede Stack Exchange, incluindo obviamente o Stack Overflow e o SOpt. Destacando:

> You let others copy, distribute, display, and perform your copyrighted work — and derivative works based upon it — but only if they give credit the way you request.

deixando claro que qualquer conteúdo só pode ser usado quando dado o devido crédito;

Outro post dando [mais detalhes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/):

> You are free:
>
> - to Share — to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> - to Remix — to adapt the work
>
> Under the following conditions:
>
> - Attribution — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor(but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
> - Share Alike — If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one.

reforça a ideia que a cópia, distribuição, transmissão ou adaptação do material deve obrigatoriamente atribuir a autoria e esse novo material deve seguir a mesma licença, e mesmo que o novo autor queira, ele não pode abrir mão dessa restrição. E o post ainda mostra como essa atribuição deve ser feita:

> Let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow**, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super Userin some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author** name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.

Portanto todos os membros desta comunidade tem obrigação de zelar para que essas regras sejam cumpridas e qualquer tentativa de burlar essas regras indicará uma mau comportamento do membro.

Todos aprendemos desde cedo que materiais criativos só podem ser idênticos ou quase idênticos, por cópia ou por serem extremamente simples (mais um motivo para classificar como indesejáveis as respostas apenas com links).

No MSO, temos mais informações de como proceder [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do). Destacando:

> In the context of Stack Exchange sites, **any** copying and pasting of any amount of text or code that wasn't written by you is plagiarism **if you fail to acknowledge the original author**, and to link to the original source. For a more detailed definition, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism).

E demonstra que não há desculpas:

> ## **But I only wanted to help!**
>
> Remember, Stack Exchange is not a support forum or a chat room. **The goal of "helping" the asker does not justify copying content from elsewhere without attribution**.
>
> Your motives may have been perfectly good, but to the site's users it looks like you were trying to gain reputation points without putting any work in it, or adding any valuable content to the site.

A não aceitação desse fato é um indicativo de falta de ética e qualquer tentativa de contornar a situação, atitude infelizmente consagrada com o nome "jeitinho brasileiro", é, no mínimo, uma incompreensão do que seja ajudar a comunidade.

Portanto a discussão aqui é sobre o que fazer nessa situação e não se devemos aceitar ou não essas regras universalmente aceitas.

Comment: AFAIK, as perguntas & respostas no SO são CC-BY-SA, então caso o conteúdo seja do SO acho que bastaria a atribuição.

Comment: elias, a pergunta não é sobre o caso contrário? De alguém postar aqui um conteúdo de fora, sem a devida permissão? Ou entendi errado?

Comment: @bfavaretto *acredito* que o que ele esteja falando é que no caso específico de trazer conteúdo original do SO (pai de todos) para cá.

Comment: Como vai determinar se um conteúdo é uma cópia ou uma resposta legitima? Só porque está no SO não necessariamente significa que uma resposta foi traduzida. Pode ter sido respondida pelo conhecimento do usuário.

Comment: Além disso, a moral de ter o site em português é que exista conteúdo de qualidade em português. Muitas respostas do SO foram respondida por pessoas que viram exemplos em blogs ou outros sites. Então todas aquelas questões são cópias de conteúdo? Ou foi passado o conhecimento adquirido?

Comment: _Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow, desde que elas beneficiem a sua comunidade. Tenha sempre em mente, porém, que traduções automatizadas ou mal escritas não são permitidas._ http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/a/1/40

Comment: Inclusive há um comentário seu que diz que o _post_ é perfeito.

Comment: Acho ser bem fácil determinar quando um conteúdo é cópia, sempre foi. O SO também não aceita cópia de material de terceiros sem a devida citação e dentro do que é permitido, e mesmo que aceitasse, não significa que devemos aceitar aqui. Não estamos discutindo se a cópia sem citação será permitida, apenas o que fazer quando ela aparecer.

Comment: O post é perfeito, só não trata do assunto que estamos discutindo aqui. São coisas diferentes. Ou você está sugerindo que o Gabe (representando oficialmente a SE Inc.) está incentivando a cópia de material de terceiros sem a devida atribuição?

Comment: Pelo que o Gabe falou e pelo que entendo do CC-BY-SA descrito no blog do [so], a atribuição é necessária para cópia do conteúdo em sites externos.

Comment: O fato é que ele está dizendo que é incentivado a tradução e abaixo coloca dois pontos importantes: `Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?` e 
`Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?`.

Comment: Por isso tem essa pegunta aqui. Para esclarecer a questão que você acha que não é relevante. Para saber se o SO original é site externo ao nosso ou não. Nessa pergunta nós não estamos discutindo outro ponto, só sobre a atribuição devida. Retirado do post do Jeff sobre o assunto: *"This is about the spirit of fair attribution. Attribution to the website, and more importantly, to the individuals who so generously contributed their time to create that content in the first place!"*

Comment: Não está claro o que você está defendendo. Você acha que deve ser aceito pegar o conteúdo que alguém produziu, usar como se fosse seu e isso ser considerado algo glorioso? Favor esclarecer.

Comment: Decidam o que quiserem, mas levem em consideração: - `o que é "tradução literal" e o que é "resposta a partir do conhecimento"?` - `traduções literais feitas pelo mesmo autor em ambos sites, precisa atribuição?` - `como uma resposta em inglês iria beneficiar um site em português feito para pessoas que se dão melhor com português e não tem grandes conhecimentos de inglês`. E lembrem-se, não é saudável apontar a arma para o pé.

Comment: E pessoalmente falando, se alguém pegasse todas minhas perguntas e respostas e traduzisse para Russo por exemplo, eu ficaria feliz que meu conteúdo é de qualidade e vai poder beneficiar mais pessoas.

Comment: Sim, é um direito seu, você só não pode decidir o que outras pessoas querem que façam com o material gerado por elas. Ao invés de você dar todas essas opiniões, você poderia dar uma resposta, mesmo que seja "não deve fazer nada, eu acho um procedimento válido" e talvez complementar com o que mais você desejar. É mais objetivo assim. Eu fiz uma pegunta legítima que você quer desqualificar, não fui tendencioso e espero qualquer tipo de resposta, mas esses comentários não estão produzindo nada útil, por isso encerro por aqui qualquer coisa que não leve a um avanço no assunto.

Comment: @BrunoLM Eu não entendo o que você está tentando defender. Só porque os leitores daqui podem não entender o original, não é preciso dar a referência? Se eu traduzo Hamlet para o português, tenho de dizer que é de Shakespeare! Para mim qualquer coisa que seja copiada, traduzida ou adaptada de outro autor merece uma citação. Mais do que uma questão legal, é de bom-senso e bom-tom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## O meu método

O método que tenho vindo a adotar ao longo destes anos a contribuir na StackExchange tem sido a seguinte:

### Conteúdo de → para StackExchange

Se estou a copiar o conteúdo dentro da própria rede da StackExchange, por exemplo, copiar da resposta no site A para facultar uma resposta no site B, o que faço é deixar um link para a resposta original.

Salvo o caso da resposta original se encontrar no mesmo site da StackExchange, onde aqui o que faço é votar para fechar como "Duplicada de...".

A forma como devemos agir nestes casos está clara o suficiente e pode ser consultada de forma rápida no rodapé das páginas do br.stackoverflow.com:

> contribuições do usuário com licença de cc-wiki com atribuição necessária

Ou seja, podemos copiar e utilizar o conteúdo das respostas de outros desde que seja dada a devida atribuição.

<sup>**Nota:**

Não interessa muito se a resposta que encontro na StackExchange a qual vou copiar é ou não originalmente criada por quem a colocou, como é que alguma vez vou conseguir provar isso se não existe atribuição?

*(existem raras exceções, continua a ler...)*</sup>

### Conteúdo externo à StackExchange

Se estou a copiar conteúdo externo à StackExchange para completar uma resposta que estou a dar, ou simplesmente para servir como a minha resposta, vou ter sempre em conta:

- De onde estou a copiar, deixam?

  Verifico sempre se posso copiar do site em questão.
- Atribuição

  **Sempre**, quer seja exigido quer não, a autoria não foi minha, por isso vou sempre indicar quem fez o trabalho.

---

<sup>resposta à pergunta:</sup>

## Como costumo agir

Na minha opinião, acho muito difícil a identificação de plagio, ainda mais no que respeita aos sites de programação.

Existem exceções onde quem fez a cópia além de não ter atribuído o trabalho a quem o realizou, fez uma cópia integrar de um plugin, função ou por vezes copiou o texto explicativo e o código relacionado, tendo aplicado tudo como uma resposta sua.

Ora bem, nestes casos, conseguimos identificar o plagio se já tivermos lido aquele mesmo texto num outro site. Conseguimos também identificar o plágio pois ao realizar uma pesquisa no Google, *por exemplo*, vamos passar por esse mesmo texto ou esse mesmo código num outro site e através da data de publicação identificamos quem apareceu primeiro.

As ações que tomo nestas situações:

- considero um **desrespeito grosseiro** do trabalho dos outros e levanto uma bandeira `Flag`, para sinalizar o problema.
- se a resposta tem votação positiva vou votar a negativo porque crédito indevido não é merecido.
- se tenho privilégios de edição no site em questão, vou editar a resposta e aplicar a atribuição ao autor real. Para garantir que a edição não vai ser anulada/revertida, deixo um comentário a dizer algo dentro desta linha:

  > Editei a tua resposta para dar crédito ao autor de onde copiaste o conteúdo.

  Se não tenho direito de edição, sugiro uma edição à pergunta. Se rejeitada, levanto uma `Flag`. Se ignorada, levo o caso à META.

Answer (score 4):

> Portanto a discussão aqui é sobre o que fazer nessa situação e não se devemos aceitar ou não essas regras universalmente aceitas.

### Sim, devemos aceitar essas regras

Quem concorda pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Deixar um comentário solicitando que o autor cite a fonte
2. Editar para incluir a citação

Em casos que considerar mais graves, sinalize o post para que os moderadores tomem conhecimento, escolhendo o motivo "outro" e acrescentando detalhes pertinentes.

> Se a cópia for integral, basta ter a citação?

Seria legal se alguém souber dizer as implicações jurídicas disso. Em caso de livros, lembro de que a reprodução (por exemplo, via Xerox) é permitida até determinado percentual de páginas.

Comment: Acho exclusão desnecessária e desencorajo, só caso esteja violando direitos autorais. A tradução de conteúdo é incentivada.

Comment: Você sabe que já tem vários posts assim, né? Fiz uma edição para complementar.

Comment: Que bom que tem, vários amigos meus que não são bons no inglês vão pode se beneficiar muito do site.

Comment: Pela discussão acima, acho que eu não tinha entendido bem a intenção do post, @bigown.

Comment: Mas faz diferença na sua resposta? Preciso deixar algo mais claro?

Comment: Não faz diferença, @bigown. Mas minha resposta é meio besta. Para mim é o óbvio. Copiou/traduziu/adaptou, merece referência. A falta dela é um problema. Se pudermos corrigir nós mesmos, ótimo. Caso contrário, passamos o problema para uma instância que tenha mais poder.

Comment: É bom deixar documentado. Deveria, mas nem todos acham óbvio.

Answer (score -9):

Não sei o que se deve fazer, só acho que apagar seria a pior escolha. O intuito de ter o Stack Overflow em português é justamente aumentar a quantidade de conteúdo em português, não faria sentido ficar impedindo o crescimento do site porque falta um link para o site inglês que o usuário que está lendo possível/provavelmente não iria entender o que está escrito e não estaria nem ai para o nome do autor da resposta.

Não quero decidir nada, mas a decisão que for tomada aqui vai implicar na minha participação no SOpt.

Só acho que os seguintes pontos são muito importantes e devem ser levados em consideração:

- O que é "tradução literal" e o que é "resposta a partir do conhecimento"?

  - Se eu postar uma resposta que eu montei e ela for similar a uma resposta do Stack Overflow, eu traduzi a resposta ou criei? Como vocês vão diferenciar isso?
  - Se eu lembrei de uma dúvida que tinha há muito tempo atrás e quiser compartilhar ela e minha solução, mas essa pergunta existe no Stack Overflow, essa dúvida é de alguém em especifico? Ou várias pessoas tiveram a mesma dúvida?
- Traduções literais feitas pelo mesmo autor em ambos sites, precisa atribuição?
- Como uma resposta em inglês iria beneficiar um site em português feito para pessoas que se dão melhor com português e não tem grandes conhecimentos de inglês?

Comment: Uma coisa ainda não ficou clara: você tem algo contra simplesmente colocar o link e mencionar o post original? Se deixar de fazer isso por um lapso, é compreensível. Intencionalmente, não. Sobre a tradução ser literal ou não, depende de quão próxima ela é do original. Agora, se um post do SO serviu de base para elaboração de outro aqui, independente de ser uma tradução literal ou não, é legal dar o devido crédito. Por exemplo, um link tipo "Tal resposta no SO tem uma solução interessante" (seguido da explicação da solução).

Comment: Ok. Vamos supor que eu respondi uma pergunta que eu resolvi com meus conhecimentos. Eu tenho que ir no Stack Overflow procurar questões similares e postar junto? E como isso é útil para quem não sabe inglês?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que os moderadores pensaram nisso. Vou esperar uma resposta oficial.

Comment: Se você responde de cabeça, é claro que não precisa procurar uma questão similar para citar. Mas se usou alguma outra fonte (total ou parcialmente), tem de citar. É simples assim. Duvido que os moderadores discordem disso. E isso não é uma regra do SO, se aplica a qualquer tipo de trabalho autoral. Ver também: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered

Comment: "Traduções literais feitas pelo mesmo autor em ambos sites, precisa atribuição?" se você é o autor, você é detentor dos direitos autorais sobre o conteúdo, então você pode "re-licenciar" como quiser. Não precisa de atribuição.

Comment: "Se eu postar uma resposta que eu montei e ela for similar a uma resposta do Stack Overflow, eu traduzi a resposta ou criei?" não posso falar sobre qualquer conteúdo, mas pelo menos relativo a código [a lei](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm) é clara: "Art. 6º **Não constituem ofensa** aos direitos do titular de programa de computador: III - a ocorrência de **semelhança** de programa a outro (...) quando se der por força (...) de **limitação de forma alternativa para a sua expressão**;" Ou seja, respostas curtas que dificilmente podem ser expressas de outra forma, não é cópia