# Comportamento incomum

Tags: debate, comportamento

Faz alguns dias que tenho notado um comportamento incomum de um usuário, notei por acaso antes do SOpt eu respondia no [gujperguntas](http://www.guj.com.br/perguntas) e lembro de ter respondido algumas perguntas de um [usuário](http://www.guj.com.br/usuario/121133/silvio-andorinha) com o mesmo nick no SOpt/en. Basicamente o que ele faz é copiar/traduziar e colar as respostas sem dar credito ao autor e isso parece ter acontecido mais de uma vez mesmo com outros usuários alertando sobre isso.

#### Situação 1

[(possível resposta original)](http://www.guj.com.br/8905-problemas-no-calculo-com-javascript)

[(mesmo conteúdo sopt)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-calculo-com-numeros-quebrados/5643#5643)

[(possível cópia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113310/inaccurate-calculation-in-browser-console/21113334#21113334) - note, perto do fim tem uma frase que esta `breaking a galhão.`

#### Situação 2

([resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git/179147#179147)) apontada pelo [erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908115/erik)

([possível cópia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085554/how-do-i-change-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git/18085696#18085696))

#### Situação 3

([possível resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986896/1342547))

([possível cópia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6139/91)), alguem deixeu o link(do SOen) na pergunta porém apagou o comentário, não lembro o nome do usuário.

O que me deixou realmente espantado foi esse comentário nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6363/91), parece que foi apagado. Tirei um print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e aqui tem outro [comentário na mesma linha](http://www.guj.com.br/4210-transformar-string-em-variavel)

Outro ponto preocupante é quando as respostas não são cópias, são apenas códigos. Lembro de já ter visto 4 ou 5 respostas dele nas análises classificadas pelo sistema como baixa qualidade (se não me engano isso pode contribuir para um ban)

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6364/91
[TinyMCE pegar e setar valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5871/tinymce-pegar-e-setar-valor/5872#5872)

[Como colorir aleatoriamente DIVs com um Array de cores em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5848/como-colorir-aleatoriamente-divs-com-um-array-de-cores-em-javascript/5850#5850)

Existe alguma coisa que possa ser feita além da orientação?

Comment: Putz, e eu ainda elogiei a pergunta dos floats. Cópia descarada...

Comment: Editei a respostas dos floats para atribuir autoria. Não pode ficar sem isso.

Comment: Lamentável essa troca de pontos que ele sugeriu no SO Pt e também no GUJ. Com relação ao `breaking a galhão` não sei nem o que falar.. Cara de pau no último. Só pra completar, também teve esse mesmo comportamento do mesmo usuário caçoando de outro em um comentário [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5536/parte-do-label-em-negrito#comment8908_5536), completamente desnecessário e errôneo, veja que eu até comentei abaixo à favor do comentário do fotanus.

Comment: A propósito, a pergunta no SO EN foi perguntada as 12:13 (de um dia qlqr) por um cara de São Paulo, 
Tuyoshi Vinicius, e respondida as 12:14 do mesmo dia pelo Silvio Andorinha. Será que em 1 minuto ele conseguiu achar a resposta correta no GUJ, copiar o texto, jogar no tradutor e dar a resposta ou será que eles combinaram de um perguntar e outro responder logo em seguida? Se for o segundo caso, é mais lamentável ainda...

Comment: @Math Reparou que esse Tuyoshi Vinicius é o mesmo cara do screenshot?

Comment: @Math, coloquei a outra imagem que tem todos os comentários, não parece que algo foi combinado entre os usuários, o Tuyoshi Vinicius da uma indireta no andorinha.

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim, eu reparei um pouco depois que eu adicionei meu comentario, mas o q eu nao entendo é q se os dois fossem tão amigos eles não precisariam ficar falando de votos em público, deveriam ter face ou skype um do outro, ainda não entendi o que se passa. Na mesma resposta do print screen o Tyoushi dá outra no Andorinha, na resposta do Andorinha. Vai entender..

Comment: Uma [nova resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-calculo-com-numeros-quebrados/6480#6480) foi publicada na pergunta do ponto flutuante. Ela está tão bem escrita que eu procurei por vários trechos dela no google para ver se não se tratava de outro cópia sem referência. Não achei nada e votei a favor dela. Espero que não descubram mais tarde que se trata de outro plágio, não quero me sentir enganado mais uma vez :/

Comment: Adicione esse comportamento _incomum_ para esse mesmo usuário: [reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5082/silvio-andorinha?tab=reputation), veja no dia 21/02/2014, 9 votos a favor entre 20:20 e 20:23. Não dá pra acusá-lo é claro, mas vamos dizer que é suspeito.. Talvez os moderadores poderiam dar uma mãozinha nessa? Dá pra saber qual o ip de onde vieram os votos talvez? @bfavaretto (só marquei seu nome pra ter ctz q mais uma pessoa além do OP veria meu comentário.)

Comment: @Math Se amanhã o sistema não tiver revertido esses votos em série (tem uma rotina pra isso), sinalizo pro Gabe dar uma olhada.

Comment: @bfavaretto imagino q o sistema vai reverter sim, o meu ponto maior é: tinha q acontecer isso justo com ele? por mais q _talvez_ ele não tenha culpa

Comment: Você tem razão, @Math. E até agora o sistema não reverteu. Sinalizei mais uma vez.

Comment: @bfavaretto pior q não reverteu mesmo! eu estava confiante que reverteria, nos mantenha informado sobre sua sinalização

Comment: Surgiu um novo usuário com comportamento mais ou menos igual e com nick quase que repetido, acho que vale pena checar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5592/kaique-andorinha

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, vc tem os links do possível conteúdo copiado?

Comment: Me expliquei mal, não houve cópia até o momento até porque ele tem poucas perguntas/respostas, mas notei um crescimento na reputação do Silvio Andorinha que pode ser que tenha sido feito pelo novo usuário que relatei agora que me parece um "ajudante" para conseguir pontos.

Comment: Na atribuição de votos, só tem 1 upvote até agora.

Comment: ufa... achei q daqui a pouco ia ter verão

Comment: posso até talvez estar pegando no pé do cara, mas será q ele tem compulsão em copiar coisas? [Vejam.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6884/ofuscando-codigo-java-com-proguard#comment11578_6884) Eu juro que não estava investigando ele, eu tava pesquisando sobre o ProGuard.

Comment: @Math, não entendi.

Comment: @perdeu não entendeu meu ultimo comentário ou o penultimo? no último eu pus um link de um comentário que ele copiou da resposta, pq o Paulo Roberto comentou que aquela resposta caberia mais como um comentário, só nao entendi pq o andorinha que nao tinha nada a ver com a historia resolveu copiar a resposta e colocar como comentário

Comment: Porque vocês estão falando mal de mim?

Comment: @perdeu eu solicito a exclusão desse post, e eu apago a pergunta e a resposta

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Ninguém está querendo "te pegar pra cristo" não, só queremos que siga as regras e a etiqueta da comunidade. Inclusive essa pergunta foi feita há mais de um mês atrás, alguém te tratou diferente nesse meio-tempo? Nós somos adultos aqui, recompensamos/punimos **ações** e não **pessoas**. Adeque suas ações, e ninguém vai guardar ressentimento. Podemos até retirar seu nome daqui, se isso te faz se sentir melhor (como já falei, a intenção não é te atacar pessoalmente). Se ninguém apresentar objeção, corrija os problemas mencionados no post e eu próprio sinalizo pra anonimizar.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, por favor, aproveite seu periodo de suspensão para ler *toda* a [help] e confira minha [sugestão abaixo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/910/comportamento-incomum/1172#1172).

Answer (score 24):

Obrigado por trazer isso à tona. Eu acabei descobrindo mais coisas do que eu achei que ia ver, o que é ótimo.

Sobre os casos de plágio, eram **bastante** evidentes e não há muita desculpa. Normalmente os posts seriam removidos, mas como esse é o primeiro caso no SOPT (Parabéns! Estamos crescendo!) e os posts já foram editados pra adicionar as referências, resolvemos deixá-los no site.

Quanto aos votos fraudulentos, sem entrar em detalhes, eles ocorreram sim (em diversos usuários) e os usuários falsos foram removidos e os votos invalidados.

## Corram para as montanhas! É o fim!

Esse tipo de coisa é **esperada** e ocorre o tempo todo nos sites da rede. Eu digo isso porque realmente não gostaria que fosse passada a impressão de que a qualidade, ou a comunidade, do SOPT é inferior à qualquer outra. Se os sites do SE fossem perfeitos, não teríamos Community Managers.

Quanto mais o site cresce, mais vão aparecer pessoas fazendo mau uso dele, propositadamente ou não. Cabe à **todos** manter o olho no site, como foi muito bem feito dessa vez, e à mim e os eventuais moderadores tomar as providências necessárias. A comunidade agiu muito bem e está de parabéns.

Os sites da SE funcionam sim como jogos, e o destino de todo jogo é ser explorado. Mas também somos comunidades sérias, de pessoas apaixonadas por um assunto, e que não pode ser afetada pelo mau comportamento de uns ou outros. É por isso que levamos esses casos à sério.

## O que fazer se eu encontrar um post plagiado?

O que foi feito nesse caso. Use flags para casos isolados ou venha ao Meta caso se depare com algo constante. Editar o post para adicionar a referência, como foi feito, também funciona muito bem, desde que você tenha certeza (dentro do possível) de que encontrou o conteúdo original. Caso a edição seja equivocada, ela será revertida e segue a vida.

## O que fazer se eu quiser usar o conteúdo de outro lugar?

De acordo com a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> Quando você encontrar um recurso útil que pode ajudar a responder a uma pergunta (em outro site ou em uma resposta do Stack Overflow em Português), certifique-se de tomar as seguintes providências:
>
> - Forneça um link para a página ou resposta original
> - Cite somente a parte relevante
> - Forneça o nome do autor original
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> > De acordo com esta biografia, Hemingway presenciou combates em sua adolescência. O texto afirma:
> >
> > > Depois que os Estados Unidos entraram na Primeira Guerra Mundial, ele alistou-se em uma unidade voluntária de ambulâncias do exército italiano. Servindo na linha de frente, ele foi ferido e condecorado pelo governo italiano, e passou um período considerável em hospitais...
> >
> > [outras fontes, citações, explicações etc. necessárias para concluir a resposta]

Repare que o conteúdo dessa seção é uma referência sobre como fazer referências. Há! Meta!

## O que fazer se eu não quiser atribuir a fonte?

[image: Que feio!]

Answer (score 22):

#### Sobre as respostas de baixa qualidade

Eu não sou totalmente contra respostas que só contêm código. [Na do TinyMCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5871/tinymce-pegar-e-setar-valor/5872#5872), por exemplo, o código é autoexplicativo, e ainda há comentários. Um dos outros dois códigos parece ser uma resposta errada (ironicamente é a  que contém mais texto que não é código). A outra parece estar correta. Seria bem melhor se houvesse uma explicação em vez de "tenta isso", mas não é tão grave assim.

#### Sobre a falta de citação das fontes

Este é um problema muito mais grave. O primeiro passo é dar **orientação** ao usuário. Como parte disso, eu editei as respostas das situações 1 e 3 (estou me restingindo ao SOpt), incluindo citações às devidas fontes. Ainda é possível deixar comentários alertando o usuário de que ele [precisa citar as fontes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319).

Se o usuário continuar a postar cópias ou traduções sem citação, é o caso de uma **repreensão** dos moderadores por meio de mensagem privada. E se ainda assim o comportamento persistir, pode-se aplicar **suspensão** por um curto período (e depois períodos maiores, se necessário).

#### Coisas estranhas

Fora isso, há [mais coisas estranhas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/910/comportamento-incomum/913#comment1871_910). É bom a comunidade e os moderadores ficarem atentos. Se forem comprovadas, também cabem repreensão e suspensão.

#### Pra não perder a piada

Espero que seja um caso isolado. Como diria a minha avó, "uma andorinha não faz verão".

Comment: *"uma andorinha não faz verão"*... Tem como dar +100 na resposta?

Comment: O usuário acabou de remover a citação que inseri. Reverti a edição dele. Espero que não comece uma guerra de edições...

Comment: @bfavaretto começou uma guerra de edições...

Comment: putz... a revisão de número 18 dele foi foda hein.. muito mau caráter, colocou um link errado achando que vai enganar alguém... [veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5643/revisions)

Comment: Putz, @Math. Eu desisti da briga e sinalizei a resposta.

Comment: Agora a resposta foi bloqueada, ninguém altera mais e o link ta la.

Comment: [histórico das revisões](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5643/revisions)

Comment: Não @utluiz, não é possível 1 usuário dar +100 em uma resposta. a não ser que 100 usuários de um ponto na resposta, que resultaria o totar de 100. referente a sua [pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/910/comportamento-incomum#comment1876_913) obrigado

Comment: @downvoter Na verdade isso foi uma ironia... rsrs

Answer (score 9):

Ele não apenas copiou código e *esqueceu* de citar a fonte. Ele literalmente chegou a copiar até mesmo piadas e comentários pessoais, e não citou fonte.

Numa situação como essa, eu pessoalmente entraria em contato com ele, avisaria o motivo de o quão grave é o que ele fez e, tão logo ele entendesse a gravidade, **daria um ban de 4 semanas pelo menos no SOpt**.

O único motivo para não dar ban nele é se ele se mostrar alguém que é muito novo, como uma pessoa mais jovem e que ainda não é um profissional da área, coisa que ele talvez pelo nível das outras respostas, e então dar um ban de somente uma semana.

Comment: Eu entendo sua frustração e também acho que algo deveria ser feito, mas acho importante agirmos mais com a razão do que com a emoção, devemos achar uma forma de punição padrão para um determinado tipo de "delito". Sobre ele ser jovem, acho que não justifica, quando eu tinha 16 anos não tinha as mesmas atitudes dele, 16 anos já dá pra ter uma boa idéia do que é certo e o que é errado.

Comment: Quando Em Roma, aja como os romanos. Minha opinião é que a punição tem que ser a mesma que um veterano receberia.

Comment: 4 semanas eu não sei, mas 1 semana já está acontecendo, [olha aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1166/3117) :-) Se continuar assim talvez ele consiga um ban eterno.

Answer (score 7):

Uma vez reconhecido o erro e entendidas as normas da rede Stack Exchange <sup>`*`</sup>, o usuário envolvido nessa situação deveria rever **todos seus posts** (perguntas, respostas e wiki de tags) e não deixar **nenhum deles** sem a devida citação, onde devida. Também pode interpretar e adaptar os textos/códigos alheios, escrevendo conteúdo original de sua própria criação.

<sup>`*` Na verdade, muitas delas são normas que podemos aplicar na nossa vida profissional e que nos ajudam em diversos aspectos: escrever com claridade e com uso correto da linguagem, descrever um problema/solução com detalhes suficientes, citar todas as fontes que nos serviram para escrever um texto/código, entre outras.</sup>