# Evento de reputação: "O usuário foi removido"

Tags: suporte, reputação

Hoje vi a seguinte mensagem no histórico de reputação:

[image: user-removido]

Aconteceu ontem (2014-03-12) às 21:23. Nunca vi isso. **O que é? Quem foi removido?**

Comment: Um usuário que havia positivado uma resposta sua, foi removido do sistema e, por isso, a positivação foi removida também, o que acarreta na perda de 10 pontos.

Comment: Provável causa: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/910/comportamento-incomum/1055#1055

Comment: nusss: `-255  21:23  removido  O usuário foi removido`

Comment: @Math A reputação bateu asas e voou :)

Comment: Esse mereceu uma medalha de capelo ao contrário!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso ocorre quando algum usuário que votou em você é removido. Com a remoção, os votos dele são anulados, e você perde os pontos que havia ganho (ou ganha de volta os que havia perdido, no caso dos votos contra).

Não tenho como dizer qual usuário foi removido, mas é bem provável que seja um dos envolvidos num esquema de fraude com votos [discutido no meta anteriormente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/910). [Ontem o Gabe informou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/910/comportamento-incomum/1055#1055) que de fato havia uma situação irregular, e que alguns usuários foram removidos do sistema.

Comment: `esquema de fraude com votos` isso parece notícia do congresso haha.

Comment: Prova de que os congressistas são representantes reais dos que os elegem, @perdeu. ;)