# Perda de pontos por usuário removido tem prazo de validade?

Tags: suporte

Essa pergunta é um complemento à seguinte: [Evento de reputação: "O usuário foi removido"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059/evento-de-reputa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-o-usu%C3%A1rio-foi-removido)

A perda de pontos por usuário removido tem prazo de validade? Por exemplo, se o usuário foi removido X anos depois que ele votou, ainda assim há perda de pontos?

Comment: Eu não sabia que um usuário removido podia reaver a sua conta, pensei que era criada uma nova.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que eu não fui claro! O que quero saber é se os votos de um usuário são invalidados mesmo se os votos foram dados há muito tempo, e não se os votos voltam.

Comment: Carlos você foi claro sim, eu que não li direito, falta de atenção minha.

Comment: Se bem me serve a memória tem prazo sim {{citation needed}}.

Comment: Que eu saiba, não é a idade da conta de usuário que determina isso, e sim seu número de votos - se ele votou relativamente pouco, ele é removido normalmente não importa quando, e os pontos são perdidos. Se ele votou muito, então os votos dele são transferidos pro usuário "Comunidade" antes dele ser removido, e não há perda de pontos. Não sei se existe um critério objetivo ou se é subjetivo, pois me parece que a remoção de uma conta é um evento raro, que demanda intervenção manual.