# O que fazer quando uma disputa de conteúdo recomeça?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Vendo [o histórico de revisões dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5643/revisions), notei que - quando expirou o bloqueio por "disputa de conteúdo" - o autor editou a resposta novamente para remover a citação da fonte. Não vou entrar no mérito se essa citação é ou não necessária (deveria ser óbvio, pois o conteúdo de outro autor foi transcrito literalmente), mas o fato é que o autor da resposta fez uma edição que é **idêntica** à que ele vez outras **oito vezes!** Não há qualquer comentário do autor a respeito do assunto - nem na própria resposta, nem [nessa discussão no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/910/215) (onde a mesma resposta foi questionada anteriormente).

O que fazer? Eu reverteria e colocaria a citação da fonte de volta, mas aí estaria iniciando uma nova disputa de conteúdo... Como proceder nesses casos?

**Atualização:** esse caso particular está resolvido, o autor *finalmente* concordou em manter a citação da fonte.

Comment: Pessoal sinto muito por isso eu era muito novo quando fiz essas coisas hoje me arrependo muito e estou notificando sobre a minha retirada do site não quero ser a ovelha negra do stackoverflow, tchau............

Comment: @Silvio Se você agora conhece as regras e está disposto a segui-las, não vejo por que se retirar do site. Você postou várias perguntas que irão contribuir com futuros visitantes, e isso é bom! Mas, claro, a decisão final sobre permanecer no site ou não é sua...

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, como assim se retirar do site? Por que? Pôxa, uma *edit war* não é motivo pra isso... você não sabia, teimou na sua posição, mas foi tudo esclarecido. O que você pensa fazer é conhecido como [*rage quit*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171581/what-does-it-mean-to-ragequit/171587#171587), e muita gente já passou por isso, tanto que tem até nome pra sindrome :)

Comment: Analisando o histórico, o outro usuário/editor também falhou... já no primeiro *rollback* do OP, ele tinha que ter sinalizado e/ou deixado um comentário explicando suas razões. Entrar em *edit wars* é **contra-producente**.

Comment: Ok, pessoal peço desculpas e garanto que nunca mais voltarei a fazer essas coisas..

Comment: é que eu levei essa coisas de pontos de reputação a sério demais e acabei perdendo um pouco o controle, mas não voltarei a fazer.

Comment: @Silvio sobre a resposta em questão, eu me envolvi na *edit war* de forma equivocada. Foi errado da minha parte ficar insistindo em um ponto repetidamente e sem ter a possibilidade de argumentar. Coisa do momento. Em um caso similar o correto é editar (uma vez) e sinalizar apenas. Não se repetirá.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tudo indica que esse caso em particular já está resolvido. Mesmo assim, respondo para registrar o que acredito ser o melhor procedimento em casos assim: sinalize a pergunta ou resposta para atenção de um moderador.

De fato, em situações desse tipo reverter uma edição ou confrontar o autor em comentários pode não adiantar nada, e agravar a disputa. Moderadores têm mais ferramentas para lidar com isso, como bloquear edições temporariamente ou permanentemente.