# Responder perguntas com reprodução de texto

Tags: debate

No tópico "[O que são princípios de Usabilidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27099/o-que-s%C3%A3o-princ%C3%ADpios-de-usabilidade)", existe [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27106/1592), que é a reprodução de um artigo de [outro site](http://www.dclick.com.br/2012/02/12/heuristica/).

Ao contrário do que muito já vimos, o autor da resposta  não colocou só o link para um artigo pertinente como reproduziu o conteúdo em si – o que eu achei válido.

Embora não tenha visto nada de errado com a prática em questão, pergunto: é válida essa reprodução de conteúdo para respostas?

Posso eu fazer essa clonagem de conteúdo para toda/qualquer pergunta onde ela [a clonagem] venha a se encaixar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> é válida essa reprodução de conteúdo para respostas?

Sim, contanto que:

1. O conteúdo de fato responda à pergunta onde está
2. [A fonte foi citada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/o-que-faremos-com-conte%C3%BAdo-de-terceiros-postado-sem-a-devida-cita%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
3. A fonte permite essa cópia/uso de seu conteúdo

O site onde está o artigo em questão contém o seguinte no rodapé:

> ® 2011 DClick. Todos os direitos reservados.

Isso me leva a desconfiar que talvez não seja permitido copiar os conteúdos dali.

Comment: Eu estava pensando justamente sobre isso (direito autorais), @bfavaretto. Não é possível ter controle de todas as "clonagens" possíveis – e se alguma protegida passar despercebida? Quem é o responsável: o autor ou o SO? Já vi numerosas vezes que "reproduções são proibidas sem consentimento do autor" – e quando/se isso acontecer?

Comment: Eu *acho* que quem copia é que é responsável. E mais, quem tem material copiado sem autorização é que teria de reclamar, e a SE retiraria o conteúdo do ar. Mas não sou advogado, vou escalar o problema pro Gabe...

Comment: Em off: sempre que eu leio "Gabe", eu lembro do [mito](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410000725/erbparodies/images/8/84/Gabe-newell-arms-crossed.jpg).

Comment: Que mito? Tô por fora...

Comment: Clica na palavra "mito". :P Se não entendeu mesmo assim, Gabe Newell, co-founder da Valve.

Comment: Argh, [esses links quase invisíveis](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1585/maior-destaque-na-cor-dos-links-j%C3%A1-visitados-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-texto)

Comment: Caraca! Estava pensando em sugerir! Salve, @Andrey! :P

Comment: Eu também não vejo problema algum em reproduzir conteúdo, *contanto que a fonte seja citada*. A não citação da fonte é antes de tudo uma tremenda falta de ética, mas também uma violação de direitos autorais (no meu humilde ponto de vista). Particularmente eu não entendo bem o significado de "todos os direitos *reservados*" para postagens públicas na Web como essa. Então, concordo com o @bfavaretto: se o autor original se incomodar e reclamar, é só remover o conteúdo. Caso contrário, o conteúdo é útil e bem-vindo.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Sobre quem é responsável nesse caso, sugiro dar uma olhada no [DMCA](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act). Entre outras coisas, essa lei isenta o prestador de serviço (no caso a SE) das consequências das ações dos usuários, desde que ela se comprometa a remover rapidamente (i.e. na primeira notificação, sem esperar ação judicial) conteúdo que viola direitos autorais. Ou seja, se o autor entrar em contato com a SE ela - sendo uma empresa dos EUA - vai remover sem fazer perguntas, e cabe ao usuário que postou fazer uma contra-queixa (se ele quiser).

Comment: Genial, Luiz e mgibson! Obrigadous!