# Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow

Tags: debate, licença

> **Atualização 01 (17/Dez)**: Vamos mudar a data da mudança para 01 de fevereiro de 2016. Queremos ter mais tempo para avaliar a opinião de vocês sobre os novos termos.
>
> ---
>
> **Atualização 02 (15/Jan)**: A discussão continua acalorada e acreditamos que não fomos claros o suficiente sobre os motivos e objetivos por trás da mudança, o que não ajuda em nada a chegarmos a um consenso.
> Nós continuamos acreditando que a mudança representa um avanço considerável em relação ao que temos hoje, e é muito melhor para a comunidade como um todo, mas entendemos que há vários casos diferentes e opiniões divergentes a respeito do assunto.
> Então decidimos **cancelar a mudança por enquanto**.
> Vamos voltar alguns passos, pensar com mais calma, avaliar as preocupações apontadas por vocês e definir um novo plano.

A nossa licença atual ([CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.pt)) é ideal para qualquer repositório comunitário de conhecimento. Foi um dos fatores que contribuíram para o sucesso e manutenção das nossas comunidades e nós planejamos continuar a utilizá-la para todo conteúdo em *prosa* no Stack Overflow, por toda a eternidade.

Mas ela não funciona muito bem para *código*, e a forma como ela deve ser aplicada nesses casos nunca ficou muito clara. Essa falta de clareza sempre preocupou os programadores mais atentos sobre o assunto, já que não é muito claro o que exatamente a licença exige de quem copia algumas linhas de código do Stack Overflow. Essa incerteza atrapalha a vida de todo mundo, a sua e a nossa, e nós nos sentimos na obrigação de fazer algo à respeito.

**A partir de 01 de fevereiro de 2016, todo novo código em posts estará sob a [Licença MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).**

Nós já estamos trabalhando nisso há algum tempo. Pedimos consultoria à [OSI](https://opensource.org), advogados, e debatemos o assunto internamente. Acreditamos que essa solução representa uma melhora significativa comparado com o que temos hoje.

Um resumo da nova licença::

**A partir de 01/02/2016**, todo conteúdo enviado em toda a rede estará licenciado ao público, sob as seguintes condições:

- Conteúdo que não seja código continua sob os termos do CC-BY-SA
- Contribuições de código estão disponíveis para uso sob os termos da Licença MIT
- Você não precisa incluir o texto da Licença MIT na sua base de código. Os autores concordam em permitir que os usuários do código ignorem esse aspecto da Licença MIT, desde que o código receba o devido crédito *em caso de pedido do autor* (ou do Stack Overflow, em nome do autor). Essa exceção está descrita nos nossos [Termos de Uso](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Esse último ponto é o que facilita o uso do Stack Overflow, ao mesmo tempo que garante proteções a quem cria e usa os trechos de código do site.

Para a grande maioria de vocês, tudo isso é informação desnecessária. Os novos termos da licença não mudam nada. Vocês podem continuar fazendo tudo que já faziam antes: copiar código, mexer, futucar, colocar no seu projeto e seguir em frente.

Mas, se quiserem evitar potenciais dores de cabeça no futuro, vocês podem:

1. Colocar um comentário no seu programa, com um link para o post de onde saiu aquele trecho específico, ou
2. Atender aos requerimentos normais da Licença MIT, incluindo seu texto completo na sua base de código

Você já estava fazendo o item 1 de qualquer maneira, certo? É o procedimento padrão quando você usa algum trecho de código que encontrou na internet: um comentário indicando de onde veio, como referência para o futuro caso você precise entender o que ele faz. Sob os novos termos, esse comentário passa a servir também como um reconhecimento, uma maneira de garantir que você atendeu aos pedidos de quem criou aquele trecho e te ajudou com seu programa.

**Nós queremos saber o que vocês acham dos novos termos.** Mas antes, alguns pontos:

**É simples assim mesmo?**

Sim. Nossa intenção é deixar tudo mais claro e mais fácil de agir de acordo com a licença. O novo modelo permite que você atenda à licença mesmo sem fazer nada, e só vai ter que fazer alguma coisa - dar crédito - se o autor do post pedir.

**O meu projeto é em código aberto. Posso só inserir a Licença MIT na minha base?**

Sim. Não é obrigatório fazer uso da exceção a respeito da preservação da licença. A Central de Ajuda vai ter um guia prático da nossa licença, detalhando diversos casos de uso, quando ela passar a valer em fevereiro.

**E o código que já existir no site em 01 de fevereiro?**

Nós estamos dando apenas o primeiro passo para acabar com as ambiguidades na licença do Stack Overflow. Todo código que já existia no site em 01/02/2016 vai continuar disponível sob o termos do CC-BY-SA. Estamos pensando em formas de permitir que usuários possam optar por disponibilizar seus posts antigos sob os novos termos.

**E outros sites da rede Stack Exchange?**

A nova licença vale para todo código, em todos os sites da rede, enviados a partir de 01 de fevereiro de 2016.

**Quem está por trás disso?**

Você pode agradecer, ou culpar, tanto o [Tim Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10/tim-post), [Britton Payne](http://copyrighton.com) e [Sam Brand](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/16/samthebrand). Eles também contaram com uma enorme ajuda da [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/).

**E agora?**

Tudo isso passa a valer apenas em 01 de fevereiro de 2016. Sabemos que o aviso não foi dado com muita antecedência, mas acreditamos que o novo modelo é uma melhora significativa em relação ao atual, e queremos implementá-lo o mais rápido possível. Sintam-se à vontade para nos dizer o que acham.

Comment: Minha licença predileta! \o/

Comment: Já estava comemorando a notícia, quando resolvi ler [algumas respostas no MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/177950) e... bem... já estou mudando de ideia. Parece uma coisa boba, mas de fato não é, e fazer essa mudança às pressas num fim de ano (sem aguardar um feedback adequado) só piora as coisas. Espero que voltem atrás nessa decisão.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada nestas respostas @mgibsonbr, mas acho que eles estão enganados. O problema da licença atual nem é a atribuição, o que é justo, penso eu, mas a necessidade de compartilhar todo seu código pelo mesma licença. Isso sim é um grande problema imho, e uma hora teria que ser enfrentado. Pense no seguinte cenário: eu crio um código, venho aqui e posto pedindo ajuda. Então alguém modifica este código, e eu uso esta modificação no meu. Só por isso, terei que disponibilizar todo meu código pela mesma licença do SO. [...]

Comment: E de resto as preocupações não fazem sentido, porque hoje já é da forma que não querem que seja. Veja os direitos da licença atual: Você tem o direito de: 
Compartilhar — copiar e redistribuir o material em qualquer suporte ou formato
Adaptar — remixar, transformar, e criar a partir do material
para qualquer fim, mesmo que comercial.
O licenciante não pode revogar estes direitos desde que você respeite os termos da licença.

Comment: Então desde que você publique seu material pela mesma licença e  faça a atribuição, você pode usar qualquer código da rede SE, inclusive para fins comerciais. E tenho certeza de uma coisa: se as pessoas soubessem de quão restritiva a licença da SE foi por todo este tempo, jamais a rede teria sido este sucesso. Se as pessoas acham a resposta aqui mas não podem usar sem disponibilizar o código pela mesma licença... qual o sentido disso?

Comment: @gustavox Concordo que seja um problema e que precise ser enfrentado, mas não dessa forma, e não nessa "pressa"... Eu não sei se a CC-BY-SA é considerada uma licença *copyleft* ou não quando usada em código (se for, seu 1º comentário está correto, do contrário, não necessariamente), e de todo modo acho que uma licença como a MIT ou BSD seria ideal. Mas sem essa "exceção em incluir a licença a menos que o autor peça crédito", pois isso *muda a licença*, já não é mais MIT! Com todos os problemas que isso acarreta. Por isso que digo que essa decisão precisa ser melhor pensada.

Comment: Neste aspecto, o termo da licença é o seguinte: Compartilha Igual — Se você remixar, transformar, ou criar a partir do material, tem de distribuir as suas contribuições ao abrigo da mesma licença que o original. / E se  a interpretação for mesmo esta a que cheguei, haveria infringência à lei dos direitos autorais (de graves consequências) ao usar e não disponibilizar pela mesma licença. Então acho que como primeiro passo foi uma boa decisão. Espero que também resolvam logo o problema dos posts anteriores ao ano que vem, disponibilizando uma opção para quem não quiser a nova regra... @mgibsonbr

Comment: Concordo que esta exceção não faz sentido nenhum. Só vai servir pra dar problema. Imho (sempre).

Comment: @mgibsonbr a gente vem trabalhando na questão da licença há pelo menos 6 meses (mas provavelmente mais - minha memória não é das melhores), e realmente tomamos muito cuidado de consultar especialistas quando dávamos cada passo. No final, mudar dia 01/01 é uma maneira bem simples de distinguir quais códigos estão sob a nova licença. Facilita pra todo mundo. Não é o ideal em termos de *feedback* da comunidade, mas temos bastante confiança na decisão (famous last words `:þ`)

Comment: @gustavox Eu não vou discutir esse assunto aqui porque seria chover no molhado: eu tenho minha interpretação do que é a lei dos direitos autorais, você tem a sua, a FSF tem a dela, as justiças dos diversos países tem a delas, etc. Isso é assunto pro [law.se] rsrs. Só tenho a impressão - que pode estar totalmente errada, entretanto (IANAL) - que a grande maioria dos códigos encontrados nas respostas do SO (lembrando sempre que o SO é um site de QA, não de produção de código) cairia no conceito de *fair use* (ou no equivalente dos demais países), de modo que não seria tão problemático assim.

Comment: @Gabe Eu acredito, não estou duvidando do pessoal do "Quem está por trás disso" (que certamente têm muito mais experiência no assunto que eu). Apenas achei os argumentos no MSE convincentes, só isso... Mas se a SO decidir por manter a mudança... meh! :P

Comment: O problema é esse mesmo @mgibsonbr vai depender da interpretação do juiz, e não existem muitas decisões a este respeito. Por exemplo, será que eu posso disponibilizar apenas o trecho modificado sobre a mesma licença? Qual a extensão do meu código que teria que ser disponibilizada sob esta licença? A licença MIT resolve tudo isso... Ponto para a SE imho.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Te ouviram :)

Comment: `Você já estava fazendo o item 1 de qualquer maneira, certo? ` YES! :D

Comment: Apesar de meu primeiro comentário (uso MIT em todo código que publico),  entendo um pouco a preocupação dos usuários, como descrito no link que o @mgibsonbr forneceu do "metão". Entretanto, é bom lembrar que empresas grandes precisam se preocupar com direitos autorais. Onde eu trabalho, na Atlassian, somos instruídos a não copiar e colar código da internet em hipótese alguma. Esse movimento do SO para uma licença mais permissiva no que se refere ao código, faz com que as empresas fiquem mais tranquilas com conteúdo copiado ou baseado em respostas do SO, por exemplo.

Comment: E imagine quanta gente já usou trechos de código de respostas da rede SE e fechou o código com licença proprietária... Aqui no Brasil, em tese estariam todos incursos na lei de direitos autoriais (com implicações criminais, inclusive) simplesmente porque **não observaram as regras da licença**. É claro que esta é uma preocupação em tese, porque dificilmente alguém vai procurar trechos de respostas suas em códigos alheios, e considero certo também que a SE jamais vai brigar com alguém pela utilização de trechos de respostas em códigos proprietários...

Comment: ... e é certo também que a SE não tem culpa disso, afinal a licença tem destaque no site, mas pra quem quer fazer o certo (e não o que *não vai dar problema* ) sempre que se utilizar de um trecho de código da rede SE, use no seu código (ao menos a parte necessária para a perfeita reutilização, e isso não é algo exato...) **a mesma licença**.

Comment: Tenho uma só uma ressalva, com relação à licença MIT, que é com relação ao Codereview: neste caso sim, a meu ver, a licença MIT não é mesmo a ideal, porque ao contrário dos outros sites que conheço da rede (SO e SOpt), não se tratam de coisas pontuais e específicas, mas às vezes de códigos inteiros... Neste caso, acho que o ideal seria disponibilizar uma opção como a do Github, para que o usuário pudesse escolher a licença (e as respostas seguiriam a mesma licença).

Comment: @Gabe uma actualizacao sobre as datas seria importante (no artigo do SOEN indica que a alteracao sera em Marco).

Comment: @Omni sim! Muito bem lembrado... pode editar o post

Comment: @Gabe ha ainda a questao da alteracao que foi feita, em que e **obrigatorio creditar o codigo**. Eu posso alterar a data mas acho que devia fazer um *update* com os ultimos desenvolvimentos.

Comment: @Omni Eu ia, mas considerando a recepção do último post a gente tá "repensando de novo" como e quando fazer a alteração. Vou fazer um update explicando que isso tá pendente por enquanto.

Comment: @Gabe e bom saber disso, ficamos a espera de mais actualizacoes.

Comment: @Omni Pronto! Muito obrigado pelo toque

Comment: @Gabe sugestão para a SE. Porque não deixar cada utilizador escolher qual o tipo de licença que quer aplicar ao seu código? Qualquer código postado por esse utilizador tem essa licença, qualquer edição feita ao código desse utilizador retém a licença do utilizador original. Por defeito, os utilizadores existentes tem a licença em actual vigor. Os novos utilizadores por defeito tem a nova licença. Os utilizadores podem alterar a licença se quiserem, mas código já postado retém a licença em vigor na altura.

Comment: isso quer dizer que se alguem me ajudar aqui em algum  codigo automaticamente ele vai ter licensa MIT?

Answer (score 11):

Sou da opinião que essa mudança precisa ser melhor estudada, ainda que a princípio isso já tenha sido discutido com pessoas de grande conhecimento na área (em parte porque não sabemos *em que nível de profundidade* essa discussão ocorreu). Vou fazer minha análise **de leigo** - não sou advogado, não tenho *expertise* nessa parte jurídica, vejo que aqui mesmo nessa discussão há pessoas que poderiam dar um parecer mais embasado, mas de todo modo sinto que tenho algo a contribuir, então vamos lá:

### Temos um problema?

Sim, como já bem apontado por gustavox, utluiz e outros, tanto aqui quanto no MSE:

> Se você remixar, transformar, ou criar a partir do material, tem de distribuir as suas contribuições ao abrigo da mesma licença que o original. / E se a interpretação for mesmo esta a que cheguei, haveria infringência à lei dos direitos autorais (de graves consequências) ao usar e não disponibilizar pela mesma licença. --gustavox
>
> Entretanto, é bom lembrar que empresas grandes precisam se preocupar com direitos autorais. Onde eu trabalho, na Atlassian, somos instruídos a não copiar e colar código da internet em hipótese alguma. --utluiz

Etc. Em geral vejo que a postura de quem usa o SO varia desde o *laissez faire* (foi postado pra ser usado, ninguém vai me processar... espero!) até a preocupação e análise cuidadosa dos efeitos da licença empregada (até o momento, uma licença *copyleft* - CC BY-SA). Seja quando se pergunta (estou postando código da minha empresa na internet, será que: 1. posso? 2. quem ler poderá copiar?) ou quando se usa uma resposta (se eu simplesmente copiar e colar esse código que recebi, estarei fazendo algo de errado?).

De modo que todo avanço é sim muito bem vindo, em especial se começarmos a tratar código como código e não como obras de outras naturezas (é estranho usar Creative Commons pra código, da mesma maneira que é estranho usar GPL pra imagens, música etc - ainda que [alguns o façam](http://forums.wesnoth.org/viewtopic.php?t=2015)). E principalmente se a mudança for no sentido de facilitar o uso das respostas recebidas em projetos reais sem tanto medo das consequências.

### Quão grande é esse problema?

Aí, já não sei dizer ao certo. O Stack Overflow é um site de **perguntas e respostas**, não de compartilhamento de código. O fato de muitas perguntas conterem código não muda isso, o que no meu entendimento tem um impacto profundo no que acontece quando alguém copia não *a resposta* mas sim *o código contido na mesma*:

1. Esse código se originou onde?

   Se eu faço uma pergunta sobre "como usar o método X na linguagem Y?" e alguém me responde citando trechos da própria documentação oficial dessa linguagem, ou mostra exemplos extraídos de algum outro lugar e compartilhados aqui com o consentimento do autor original, então esse código não é "obra derivada" da resposta! Pelo contrário, a resposta é que é obra derivada desse código... Se o código original podia ser usado livremente, também o poderá ser o código da resposta - desde é claro que seja *a única* coisa da resposta a ser copiada (pois tudo o mais agregou valor ao código e a modificação passa a estar sujeita aos termos da CC BY-SA).

   Por outro lado, se eu posto um código defeituoso, e alguém me ajuda a consertar o erro, o código final é obra derivada tanto do meu código original quanto da pessoa que respondeu (ou seja, está sob a CC BY-SA). Bem como quando eu pergunto "como fazer X?" e alguém me responde com código original. Nesses (e outros) cenários o problema permanece.
2. Esse código está sob o limiar de originalidade?

   A ideia do ["limiar de originalidade"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiar_de_originalidade) é que somente trabalhos originais (e não meros trabalhos) podem qualificar-se como propriedade intelectual. A expressão original refere-se à lei Americana, mas há ressalva semelhante na lei Brasileira, por exemplo, e acho seguro assumir que o mesmo ocorre em outros lugares. Veja esse trecho da ["lei do software"](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/LEIS/L9609.htm):

   > Art. 6º Não constituem ofensa aos direitos do titular de programa de computador:
   >
   > III - a ocorrência de semelhança de programa a outro, preexistente, quando se der por força das características funcionais de sua aplicação, da observância de preceitos normativos e técnicos, ou de limitação de forma alternativa para a sua expressão;

   Eu posso explicar de mil maneiras como funciona o quicksort (e cada explicação seria uma obra protegida à parte), mas há muito menos formas de expressá-lo em código que ainda seja: 1) eficiente; 2) legível; 3) respeite a sintaxe da linguagem e as convenções de nomenclatura e disposição do código ("preceitos normativos e técnicos"). Não estou dizendo que uma cópia *ipsis litteris* seria aceitável, contudo, mas dependendo da simplicidade do problema tratado - algo que possa ser feito com um *one-liner*, por exemplo - mesmo a cópia pura pode não constituir infração da licença (eu não espero por exemplo que nenhuma *regex* que eu já escrevi seja conteúdo protegido).

Há outros fatores que gostaria de discutir, mas aí já entro em terreno [mais] perigoso, então prefiro deixar quieto... O que quero dizer é que há muitas razões que contribuem para os usuários do SO se sentirem seguros para utilizar todo ou parte do código contido nas respostas (mas não a resposta em si) ainda que formalmente eles não tenham o direito assegurado de fazê-lo. Essa é talvez a razão pela qual não só o SO quanto todo fórum de discussão e outros sites tenham tido sucesso até o momento como fonte de ajuda envolvendo código, apesar da "bagunça".

### Como se tem lidado com esse problema?

Metade da resposta já foi dada: muitos simplesmente *ignoram* o problema. Eu inclusive, pois como sócio de uma microempresa tenho perfeita consciência do quão vulnerável é minha posição - uma ação judicial movida por alguém com mais recursos, *ainda que no final ganha por mim*, poderia me arruinar no processo... Se eu for deixar o receio de um evento notadamente pouco provável - de alguém aleatoriamente me processar devido a umas poucas linhas de código - me atrapalhar de fazer o meu trabalho e/ou gastar energias demais contingenciando para isso, então posso jogar a toalha agora mesmo!

(sério, eu tomo muito cuidado pra não incorporar nada não só no meu código mas em todo meu *workflow* que possa vir me trazer problemas depois, mas trechos de código *de escopo reduzido* tirados de blogs, fóruns ou do SO - apresentados com o intuito claro de serem copiados e reutilizados -  estão longe de me tirar o sono, com ou sem resguardos legais)

Já as empresas mais consolidadas, que têm mais a perder, parecem dedicar mais energias à análise do problema, e se muitas aceitam o uso do Stack Overflow é porque estão confortáveis com o modelo de licenciamento tal como está agora. Ainda que o mesmo esteja longe de ser perfeito...

### Resolver o problema ou criar um outro?

Para o pessoal do primeiro grupo - o que ignora o problema - a mudança no licenciamento não terá tanto efeito (em particular porque ela parece ser pra melhor). Já pro segundo, essa mudança - *qualquer mudança* - significa *mais energia* gasta para se reavaliar a viabilidade de usar códigos do Stack Overflow. O argumento da equipe tem sido que "agora vai ser MIT, então o licenciamento vai simplificar e não complicar", mas note três coisas:

1. O que está descrito na proposta não é MIT - mas sim um "MIT modificado" (sem a exigência da citação de fonte), uma ["licença crayon"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1445/3530) por assim dizer. Há vários problemas em potencial nisso, como a ambiguidade (se a interpretação dessa licença modificada estiver pouco clara, quem sofre são os autores que disponibilizaram seu código no SO sob essa mesma licença) e o fato dessa proposta envolver tanto a licença em si quanto os termos de uso do Stack Overflow.

   - Esclarecendo: na minha interpretação, se Alice copia um código do SO, ela tem de concordar com seus termos de uso; se Bob copia o código de Alice, ele só tem que concordar com a licença do mesmo (MIT com exceção ao crédito). Se o autor posteriormente requisitar crédito, como a SO vai cobrar de Bob - que não é usuário do site e portanto não está sujeito aos seus termos de uso - que cumpra uma exigência que **não estava presente** quando ele recebeu o código de Alice?

     Posso estar enganado na minha interpretação, mas ainda é um bom exemplo dos problemas que uma licença modificada podem trazer. P.S. [Essa resposta no law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/429/3766) dá uns *insights* interessantes, inclusive criticando [a forma como o Stack Overflow espera que citemos as fontes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319/215) (algo que sempre me incomodou aliás).
2. Por que *substituir* uma licença por outra? Por que não usar *dual-licensing*, como sugerido [nessa resposta do MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271112/177950)? Assim quem já estiver usando o código via CC BY-SA após ter se preparado para tal poderá continuar a fazê-lo sem ter que refazer toda sua análise jurídica, e quem antes não podia pelas restrições *copyleft* poderá avaliar novamente se agora vai dar pra usar (assumindo que se licencie como MIT original, sem essa exceção bizarra).
3. Ao mesmo tempo que a remoção da restrição *copyleft* simplifica o reuso das *respostas*, ele a princípio complica a situação das *perguntas*: se antes eu postava meu código no SO mesmo sabendo que o mesmo se tornaria *copyleft*, talvez porque tinha segurança de que ninguém ia copiá-lo pra usar em um produto proprietário, agora tenho que levar em conta que todo código postado vai se tornar efetivamente *copyfree*. Ou seja, ganha-se de um lado, perde-se do outro...

   Pessoalmente, como defensor do *copyfree*, não só não me importo com isso como até gosto da ideia de que códigos "não livres" vão ganhar uma desvantagem a mais. Mas isso é só minha opinião: os defensores do *copyleft*, por outro lado, vão enxergar nisso um passo pra trás. E há também quem simplesmente queira [maior controle sobre o conteúdo que produziu](http://blog.codinghorror.com/are-you-a-digital-sharecropper/).

   E como já apontado, alguns sites seriam mais afetados que outros por essa mudança, o principal deles sendo o codereview.SE.

### Minhas sugestões

De novo, como leigo não posso falar com autoridade, mas com base na análise acima (que em sua quase totalidade é simplesmente uma compilação de ideias de outras pessoas) minhas sugestões por ora seriam as seguintes:

1. Deixar de lado essa exceção problemática, e requerer sim a inclusão do texto da MIT em todo código que utilizá-lo. Isso em geral não é um problema tão grande: já vi projetos que na sua licença afirmam que "esse projeto contém código licenciado via MIT", disponibilizam o texto da MIT junto com a licença do todo, e em cada trecho onde ela se aplica colocam uma referência curta para a fonte, afirmando que foi "licenciado via MIT".

   Não sei dizer estritamente falando se isso é uma prática aceitável ou não, mas considere-se que o código nem sempre é incluído sem modificações, e seria impraticável discriminar dentro do próprio código o que é original e o que é modificado, sobretudo se um código mais extenso inclui outros trechos menores dentro do mesmo, de autores diferentes ainda por cima. Um comentário curto com referência para os detalhes externos *tem* que ser suficiente, e nesse caso não há porque não fazer da forma certa.
2. Usar o modelo *dual-licensed*, e não substituir uma licença pela outra. O post completo (incluindo os códigos) estaria sob a CC BY-SA, e cada trecho de código não trivial estaria *também* sob a MIT.
3. Considerar aplicar a mudança só pras respostas, deixando as perguntas como estão. Qualquer código presente na pergunta e que seja de interesse de terceiros muito provavelmente cairá naquele caso em que a origem do mesmo não é o autor da pergunta, ou ainda no que carece de formas alternativas pra sua expressão.

   Se isso for por demais restritivo, de minha parte pelo menos está tudo bem usar MIT em tudo. Pessoalmente, sempre evitei postar código no SO que não estivesse disposto a liberar como software livre, às vezes até criando [MVCEs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) completamente fictícios em vez de usar meu código verdadeiro ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15453662/520779), [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15453678/520779)), o que aliás torna a pergunta mais genérica e mais interessante para outras pessoas que não o autor...

Comment: Bom, se eles ainda não te ouviram, deveriam. Excelente resposta com  ótimas sugestões. + 1

Comment: Tens ai muitos pontos bem relevantes. Ainda me lembrei, será que não vai haver muita gente a apagar perguntas e respostas e a deixar de responder por causa da nova licença?