# Eu posso utilizar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas do SOpt para fazer trabalhos de faculdade?

Tags: suporte, licença

Eu posso utilizar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas do SOpt para fazer trabalhos de faculdade (como fonte de dados para montar uma apresentação em PowerPoint por exemplo)?
Se sim, como deve ser citada as fontes e a maneira de referenciar os autores para dar créditos aos mesmos? Eu devo colocar os nomes dos usuários que responderam e o autor da pergunta e também o link da pergunta ou resposta, ou até mesmo as fontes que os autores das respostas usaram para elaborar tal resposta?

Como exemplo veja esta pergunta "[O que é inteligência artificial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86869/27190)", foi feita pelo usuário *SneepS NinjA* e respondida pelos usuários *Luiz Vieira* e *mgibsonbr*.
Tanto quanto a pergunta e as respostas são ótimas, e eu poderia usa-las para fazer um trabalho ou um seminário a respeito de inteligência artificial na disciplina relacionada ao conteúdo.

Também devo citar o site como fonte?

Seria até uma maneira de divulgação do **Stack Overflow em Português** caso seja permitido usar o conteúdo do site desta forma em instituições de ensino.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No rodapé aqui do site:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

O link do "attribution required" leva ao blog do Stack Overflow que explica como se faz isso.

Tradução:

> Todo conteúdo contribuido ao Stack Overflow ou outro site da rede Stack Exchange sites é licenciado como **cc-wiki** (também conhecido como **cc-by-sa**), com a intenção de ser compartilhado e remixado. Inclusive fornecemos todo nosso conteúdo em forma de *data dump*.
>
> Mas nosso licenciamento cc-wiki, ainda que intencionalmente permissivo, requer atribuição.
>
> Atribuição — Você deve atribuir o trabalho da maneira específicada pelo autor ou licenciante (porém não de maneira que sugira que eles endossam você ou seu trabalho).
>
> Esclarecendo o que significa atribuição. Se você republicar nosso conteúdo, requeremos que você:
>
> 1. **Indique visualmente de alguma maneira que o conteúdo veio da Stack Overflow ou da rede Stack Exchange**. Isso não tem que ser de maneira escandalosa, pode ser uma caixa de texto discreta.
> 2. **Faça um *hyperlink* direto à pergunta original** no site de origem (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345).
> 3. **Mostre o nome dos autores** para cada pergunta e resposta.
> 4. **Faça um *hyperlink* direto no nome de cada autor** a sua página de perfil no site de origem (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> Por "direto" quero dizer que cada *hyperlink* deve apontar diretamente para nosso domínio em HTML padrão visível mesmo com o JavaScript desabilitado, e não usar encurtadores de links ou outra forma de obfuscação ou rediração. Além disso, os links devem ser `nofollowed`.
>
> Basicamente, esse é o espirito de atribuição justa. Atribuição ao site, e mais importante e em primeiro lugar, aos individuos que contribuiram de maneira tão generosa para criar esse conteúdo!
>
> De qualquer jeito, espero que isso esclareça qualquer confusão -- sinta-se livre para remixar e reutilizar como achar melhor, desde que um esforço sincero e de boa fé seja feito para dar a devida atribuição ao conteúdo!
>
> <sup>Por Jeff Atwood, Co-Fundador (Emeritus)</sup>

O uso da licença cc-wiki está sob avaliação para mudança a uma licença MIT, mas isso não muda nada em relação à necessidade de **atribuir devidamente o conteúdo encontrado aqui no site**. Vide [Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/201)

Comment: Só uma coisa que não ficou clara. É necessário realizar as quatro referências ou usando somente uma já atenderia a licença **cc-wiki**?

Comment: Pra mim está bem claro: são as 4. @Randrade Algo como: *Este conteúdo foi retirado do site Stack Overflow em Português, da pergunta "O que é inteligência artificial?" (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86869/o-que-%C3%A9-intelig%C3%AAncia-artificial),  realizada pelo usuário SneepS NinjA (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12032/sneeps-ninja)  e respondida pelo usuário Luiz Vieira (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73/luiz-vieira*.  E, no caso, para a do mgbison seria outra citação.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Adicionando outra resposta porque a referência abaixo é praticamente acadêmica.</sub>

Topei hoje com esta pergunta no Metão: [*We should make books of our best content!*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273911/185667)

Na resposta da Monica Cellio tem um link muito interessante para este meta post da comunidade sobre judaismo: [**Mi Yodeya Publications**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1568).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Eles já publicaram 4 livros digitais com o conteúdo seleto do site, sendo um deles também em papel. Se for para seguir um padrão Stack Exchange, os PDFs disponibilizados ali certamente servem como excelente referência.

## IMPORTANTE

#### O uso da logo do site foi autorizado pela Stack Exchange pois é material com *copyright*.