# Como compartilhar minhas próprias respostas?

Tags: suporte, licença

A partir de [01 de fevereiro de 2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/20615) o SO passa a utilizar a [licença MIT,](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) e isso foi bastante discutido em vários lugares da rede *Stack Exchange*. Não é sobre isso minha dúvida, e sim sobre como compartilhar uma resposta de minha autoria?

Pergunto isso pois de vez em quando tenho a necessidade compartilhar algumas respostas em outros sites/blogs. Mas preencher todos os [requisitos para compartilhar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) é "chato", ainda mais que a resposta é algo seu.

Então, minha dúvida é:

**Preciso atender a atribuição necessária para compartilhar minhas próprias respostas que foram dadas no site?**

Comment: **Deixo como opinião:** Acho "*Stack Overflow* empresa" fizesse uma revisão nisso, do meu ver o link já é mais que o suficiente, ou então deem uma "ferramenta" pra poder colocar autor de pergunta/resposta referencia ao site e a pergunta de maneira pratica. Sobre ser uma postagem sua própria, posso até parecer estar falando algo "destrutivo", mas que usou os conhecimentos pra responder foi você, no máximo eu faria o artigo e postaria um link "como exemplo" no artigo, sendo como se tivesse usado o artigo pra chegar a resposta. Afinal quem escreveu foi você e ainda querem burocratizar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, depende do que você quer dizer por "compartilhar".

Basicamente, se você quer *reproduzir o conteúdo* de um post (seu ou não) em outro lugar algo assim já seria suficiente pra satisfazer os requisitos de atribuição:

> [Como eu disse][1] lá no SOpt:
>
> > Texto da resposta
>
> [1]: link pro post

Se você quer só usar o post como referência, não há requisito nenhum. Ele só se aplica sobre a reprodução de conteúdo, não de conhecimento ou informação.

E a licença MIT é ainda menos rigorosa. Além disso, ela vale principalmente sobre uso de código do site em outros programas.

Eu diria que você provavelmente não tem com o que se preocupar.

Comment: Então se eu quiser colocar um código de uma resposta, por exemplo, eu preciso apenas referenciar o link de onde foi tirado? Aquilo de pergunta, autores, resposta, etc, que o blog do SO diz não precisa?

Comment: @Randrade Em essência, sim. Principalmente se a resposta for sua.

Comment: ok, obrigado. Aproveitando, existe algo [como isso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4917/20615)?