# Link do Stack Overflow em minha página

Tags: debate

Ao colocar o link do site Stack Overflow(PT) em minha página, estou violando alguma coisa ou não?

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: Se existe algum problema em utilizar o link do SO na página dele, no próprio site, tipo como referência. Acho que não, mas depende do que você vai linkar com o SO @bigown

Comment: Possível duplicata: [Como compartilhar minhas próprias respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4916/3117)

Comment: @Math, esse link não responde a minha pergunta. Eu perguntei se tem algum problema de eu colocar o link do SOpt em minha página e se estou violando alguma coisa, essa foi a pergunta.

Comment: Você está perguntando sobre divulgar o SOpt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O SOpt é de acesso livre (leitura para toda a internet e participação a quem se registar).

Para além disso há até medalhas para incentivar divulgar links do SOpt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ou seja:** podes partilhar links à vontade.

Comment: Para deixar mais claro: essas medalhas só se aplicam a links para perguntas e respostas gerados pela função "compartilhar" disponível abaixo de cada uma. Se o link for para a home do site (talvez seja isso que o pnet tem em mente), não conta para as medalhas (porque o link não inclui o código do usuário).