# Como lidar com traduções automáticas de conteúdo?

Tags: debate, tradução, conteúdo

[Já foi debatido anteriormente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs) se podemos ou não postar conteúdos traduzidos. Embora a discussão ali seja antiga (dos primeiros dias do beta privado), hoje entendo que não há problemas em postar conteúdos traduzidos (do SO ou de qualquer outro site), desde que a fonte seja citada, que direitos autorais não sejam violados, e que isso não seja feito em série simplesmente para ganhar reputação fácil.

No entanto, temos visto conteúdos colados diretamente do resultado de traduções automáticas, como [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/27833/2). Esse tipo de texto fica sempre estranho, os tradutores automáticos geram muitos erros de português e frases sem sentido. Portanto: é válido postar conteúdos gerados por tradutores automáticos? Postagens desse tipo de conteúdo sem edição/ajustes merecem votos contra?

Answer (score 14):

Postar conteúdo traduzido parece, para mim, uma das idéias do site ser em Português. Existem muitos profissionais que não dominam ou preferem não se aprofundar em outros idiomas.

Como a maioria das documentações são em inglês, o OP pode ter dificuldade de entender ou até mesmo ter interpretado errado.

Mas para postar um conteúdo traduzido, que seja traduzido por alguém que conheça a cerca do tema, para que escreva dando sentido a cada frase e a todo o contexto.

Se fosse para traduzir automaticamente até o navegador sugere, mas para se gerar conteúdo de qualidade deve ser algo direcionado e humanamente traduzido.

Acredito que, se traduzir simplesmente uma resposta seria interessante sim, como disse o @Andrey, marcar como citação e citar a fonte, ou simplesmente traduzir a parte mais importante para sanar a dúvida e posteriormente indicando o caminho para a informação original e completa no idioma de origem.

Portanto acredito que a tradução é válida e até bem vinda, desde que bem traduzida.

Comment: Excluir uma resposta por ser de baixa qualidade é um tanto drástico (votos negativos já têm esse propósito de filtrar o bom do ruim).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Concordo contigo, eu pensei em algo como o suspenso das perguntas, onde ela ainda pode ser editada para reaparecer, só não sei se o framework funciona assim, pois nunca vi o caminho de uma resposta sinalizada

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Editei a pergunta para remover a sugestão de exclusão. Obrigado pela dica :D

Answer (score 9):

Pondo de forma simples: se usar tradutores automáticos for permitido e incentivando, então não há motivo algum para o Stack Overflow em Português existir e todo mundo que tem dúvidas de programação deveria utilizar um tradutor desses eficar sempre no SOEN. Mas eles são longe do ideal e infinitamente inferiores a uma tradução humana. Não acho que sejam melhores que fazer uma postagem em inglês no site.

Duas situações onde usar um tradutor seria ok:

1. Você conhece inglês e quer postar a tradução de um texto razoavelmente grande (mais que um parágrafo). Nesse caso é ok usar a ferramenta para produzir uma base do texto em português, mas em seguida é **necessário** revisar corrigindo todos os erros e reformulando as frases sem sentido.
2. Como bem mencionou o brasofilo, se você não entende português e quer responder uma pergunta com um texto original seu. Nesse caso é uma boa pedida por uma nota de rodapé explicando e pedindo que algum membro revise o texto. Note que isso faz menos sentido para perguntas, já que seria necessário um conhecimento mínimo da língua para entender o que se passa. Ainda assim, é um caso de uso se você não fala nem inglês nem português.

Em resumo: não use por preguiça. Se é para citar conteúdo, melhor não traduzir que por algo automático.

Comment: Donde infiro, para responder minha última pergunta: sim, tradução automática merece downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Sou extremamente contra a postagem de artigos automaticamente traduzidos porque é injusto com a comunidade.

O maior objetivo do site é criar um acervo de qualidade o que, por melhor que seja a ferramenta de tradução, é impossível de se obter automaticamente.

Um usuário que simplesmente copia, traduz e cola um texto aqui dificilmente terá conhecimentos no assunto (isso se tiver lido o que copiou) para debater qualquer comentário feito à resposta ou mesmo para revisar a tradução de forma apropriada.

No mercado paga-se relativamente bem por traduções técnicas por não é fácil. E mesmo assim livros renomados de editoras consagradas como a O'Reilly dão suas deslizadas. Dos que eu já fiz posso citar [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22482/250) e [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23737/250).

O primeiro não foi muito trabalhoso, mas exigiu consulta a várias fontes para criar uma redação de fácil entendimento sem falar bobagem. Já segundo foi extremamente trabalhoso porque antes mesmo de fazer a tradução eu tive de aprender sobre o assunto, testar os códigos, interpretar as imagens, complementar lacunas deixadas pelo autor original para que o texto ficasse mais compreensível e ainda estilizar todo o texto, destacando os termos importantes com a sintaxe do Markdown que venhamos e convenhamos se torna bem inconveniente em textos complexos.

Pior! Isso desbalanceia parte do propósito do sistema de reputação. Já vi vários casos, aqui e fora daqui, de respostas grandes que careciam de informações básicas ou até mesmo que diziam bobagem e ainda assim era reputadas positivamente por aquele típico usuário adepto do *TL;DR... Mas votei mesmo assim*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não acho correto copiar texto sem dar a entender que é uma citação. O ideal é usar o `>`:

> Em design gráfico e editoração, Lorem ipsum é um texto utilizado para preencher o espaço de texto em publicações (jornais, revistas, e websites), com a finalidade de verificar o lay-out, tipografia e formatação antes de utilizar conteúdo real. Muitas vezes este texto também é utilizado em catálogos de tipografia para demonstrar textos e títulos escritos com as fontes.
>
> Retirado de [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum)

Na [resposta citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/27833/2) o usuário até citou a fonte mas não usou o `>`, podendo dar a entender que ele mesmo escreveu aquilo. Citações existem para isso! O ideal seria alguém editar a resposta.

*Copie 49 parágrafos e escreva apenas 1 se quiser, mas os 49 coloque em forma de citação (`>`) para deixar claro que não foi você quem escreveu. E claro, cite a fonte!*

Comment: Ué, eu já editei a resposta! ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto É que eu entrei no link que você botou que aponta para a revisão, por isso não vi. =)

Comment: Ótima ideia! Realmente isso vai esclarecer de que se trata de uma citação/tradução. Ótimo para usuários menos experientes.

Comment: Acredito que o ponto não é esse. Não haveria problema em si com fazer uma tradução. O problema está quando ela é **automática**. Elas tem algum valor melhor do que por diretamente em inglês aqui no site? Penso que não.

Comment: Ah, é, concordo com @GuilhermeBernal, é bem tosco colar o Google Translate aqui, pra isso que se coloque o link `GTranslate://url.do.artigo`. . . . Exceção feita àquele camarada gringo que deu uma resposta original e genial sobre o COBOL.