# Central de Ajuda: Posso traduzir conteúdo de outro site no SOpt? Como?

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Como discutido em [O que você pensa sobre a tradução de perguntas do Stack Overflow em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7637/5878) há a intenção de ser criada uma página na Central de Ajuda tratando de como pode ser feito o processo de tradução de publicações de sites em outros idiomas para o SOpt.

Como, no geral, não houve discordância e também a pedido no Nicolas, estou abrindo está pergunta para tratarmos do texto a ser colocado na respectiva página. Sugiro que cada um que possa contribuir com alguma sugestão de texto publique-a na forma de resposta a esta pergunta de forma a facilitar a votação.

Algumas discussões existentes que podem influenciar no processo:

- [Há de fato um modo pessimista de ver as respostas traduzidas do SOen?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7656/5878)
- [Vamos fazer um esforço para usar uma escrita neutra nas traduções?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7555/5878)
- [Uma feature de tradução semelhante ao Quora seria útil?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7676/5878)
- [Tradução de termos técnicos intraduzíveis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6969/5878)
- [Deveremos manter algum padrão linguístico ou não?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3/5878)
- [É válido traduzir uma resposta do StackOverflow em inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/5878)
- [Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/735/5878)
- [Como lidar com traduções automáticas de conteúdo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1795/5878)

Comment: Página: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english

Answer (score 11):

## Posso traduzir perguntas/respostas de outros idiomas para o Português?

Sim, claro, mas faça com consciência. O [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) surgiu justamente para tentar suprir uma necessidade de conteúdo técnico acerca de programação na língua portuguesa, então fazer a tradução de conteúdo de outros idiomas para cá será muito bem-vindo.

Alguns pontos deverão ser considerados quando for efetuar uma tradução:

1. **Faça sob demanda.** Nem todo conteúdo que existe em outros idiomas, por mais interessantes que possam parecer em seus respectivos sites, serão bem aceitos aqui. São comunidades diferentes com necessidades e demandas diferentes. Antes de traduzir, certifique-se de existir demanda para tal. Fazer múltiplas traduções sem demanda somente buscando ganhar pontos de reputação poderá ser considerado [spam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion);
2. **Tenha domínio do conteúdo traduzido.** Fazer a tradução de textos é sempre um processo complicado, principalmente porque diferentes idiomas possuem vícios de linguagem diferentes. Ao traduzir uma publicação, certifique-se que compreendeu o que foi tratado e que conseguirá retratar exatamente o que foi discutido;
3. **Faça a localização do conteúdo**. Assim como tratado no item anterior, tome muito cuidado com as expressões utilizadas na publicação. Uma expressão utilizada no inglês pode não fazer sentido se traduzida literalmente para o português, então não faça apenas a tradução do conteúdo, mas também a localização do mesmo. Certifique-se também de não prejudicar a publicação traduzindo o que não [precisa ser traduzido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6969/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-termos-t%C3%A9cnicos-intraduz%C3%ADveis);
4. **Sintetize.** É comum uma pergunta possuir múltiplas respostas interessantes, então, ao invés de traduzir todas em diferentes respostas em português, busque sintetizar tudo o que foi discutido em apenas uma resposta;
5. **A publicação traduzida ficará associada à sua conta** e isso implica em pontos positivos e negativos. Ao passo que você ganhará pontos de reputação ao criar publicações interessantes, esteja ciente que poderá, também, perder pontos de reputação ao traduzir conteúdos de forma equivocada;
6. **Tenha ética**. Por mais que o conteúdo ficará associado à sua conta, você não possui autoria sobre a mesma, então certifique-se que na tradução você estará dando os devidos créditos a quem produziu o conteúdo original. Certifique-se também de citar o link do conteúdo original na sua publicação;
7. **Siga o código de conduta.** Certifique-se que a publicação que está criando está de acordo com o [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct) da comunidade;
8. **Utilize uma linguagem neutra.** Busque utilizar uma [linguagem mais neutra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7555) e inclusiva durante as traduções;
9. **Na dúvida, não traduza.** Pergunte antes! Se ficou em dúvida em como fazer a tradução de algum conteúdo ou se é um conteúdo válido para ser traduzido para o português, não arrisque. Você poderá perguntar no [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) ou discutir com outras pessoas na [sala de chat oficial](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha);

Comment: Gostei bastante dos pontos elencados :) 
Só acho que não ficou claro o que seria "demanda". Só consegui pensar como "resposta a uma pergunta", que outro tipo de "demanda" haveria?

Comment: Dito isso, também acho que seria bom fazer jus ao item 8 nessa página (Ex: trocar o "seja ético" por "tenha ética") .

Comment: @carla bem notado. Sobre a demanda, seria no sentido de fazer a tradução quando a pessoa perceber a ausência de conteúdo em português, não ficar de espreita nas novas perguntas no SOen e trazer todas para cá para fazer volume e ganhar reputação.no item 6 ainda coloquei "ao seu usuário", "você não é o autor", "créditos ao autor", consegue ver um jeito de reescrever com mais neutralidade todo esse item?

Comment: Bacana, acho que poderia colocar isso então, parece deixar mais claro o propósito. Paradoxalmente, falando o que não fazer, deixa uma ideia mais clara então do que eu poderia fazer. =]

Comment: 5. A publicação traduzida ficará associada à sua conta...
6. Tenha ética. Por mais que o conteúdo fique associado à sua conta, você não possui autoria sobre o mesmo, então certifique-se que na tradução você estará dando os devidos créditos à quem produziu o conteúdo original. Certifique-se também de citar o link do conteúdo original na sua publicação;
8. Utilize uma linguagem neutra. Busque utilizar uma linguagem mais neutra e inclusiva durante as traduções;
9. ... ou discutir com outras pessoas....

Comment: @carla Gostei, já editei a resposta :D Obrigado

Comment: Esse texto é tradução de algo ou você criou tudo do zero?

Comment: (Sorry for using Google Translate) Obrigado! Você poderia me informar se a página está pronta para ser adicionada à Central de Ajuda? (Por favor note: desde que eu não sei Português eu vou usar o conteúdo como ele é.)

Comment: @Maniero Criei com base nas discussões que achei no meta sobre o assunto