# Podemos perguntar significado de certos termos?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Sempre quando estamos falando sobre programação, seja nos estudos, nas conversas e etc, nos deparamos com alguns termos/palavras que talvez possamos interpretar mal.

Quando digo interpretar mal, me refiro ao espaço vago que fica quanto ao significado de um certo termo, por mais que acabamos usando-os também.

Há um tempo eu foquei meus estudos na orientação a objetos. Com isso, li vários artigos sobre o assunto. Até que em um destes artigos tinha um método da classe denominado `popula(...)`. Vi as instruções do método e continuei lendo o artigo. Até aí, tudo bem! Não era o foco entender o termo em si, mas sim o método.

Hoje, novamente, me deparei com o termo e, como estava com tempo livre, resolvi formular uma pergunta para entender tal termo. Veja na íntegra: [Qual o significado do termo “popular” no contexto de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354621/qual-o-significado-do-termo-popular-no-contexto-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Os colegas da comunidade logo comentaram solicitando mais detalhes sobre a pergunta. Foi aí que eu editei a pergunta complementando-a com tais detalhes ([veja na revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/354621/revisions)).

Ainda assim, como pode observar, minha pergunta virou alvo de **votedowns**, até que foi fechada pela moderação ([@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)):

[image: Notificação de fechamento da pergunta]

Junto ao fechamento da pergunta, recebi a singela recomendação do moderador:

[image: Comentário do moderador]

Considerando o ocorrido, trago tal questão a debate: **Perguntas sobre significado de certo termo/palavra relacionado à programação se encaixa no escopo da comunidade?**

Não me refiro exclusivamente à minha pergunta. Digo isso no geral. É normal vermos/ouvirmos termos até mesmo "aportuguesados" vindo de pessoas com os mais altos níveis de conhecimento. E para um iniciante, como eu, acredito que seja normal ficar confuso.

---

Junto à tecnologia, vieram inúmeras palavras que não existem nos nossos dicionários/vocabulário. Não me importo com a forma com que essas palavras chegam a eles, mas me importo em compreendê-las.

Um exemplo clássico é a palavra "*digitar*". Foi introduzida no nosso vocabulário há pouco tempo. Até então, o termo correto era "*datilografar*". Mas tal termo limita-se às antigas "*máquinas de escrever*".

---

Voltando ao meu caso, gostaria de reiterar a pergunta:

**Perguntas sobre significado de certo termo/palavra relacionado à programação se encaixa no escopo da comunidade?**

---

Antes de responder, considere ler e revisar as seguintes perguntas:

> encontrei um termo chamado PSR na area de PHP, mas o topico não foi muito esclarecedor em definir o real significado da palavra PSR

Fonte: [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32295/o-que-significa-psr)

---

> eu não entendo o significado da palavra Assets

Fonte: [O que significa Assets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/o-que-significa-assets)

---

> Qual é o significado da palavra Polyfill e a que se refere dentro do dia-a-dia da programação especificamente?

Fonte: [O que é Polyfill?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857/o-que-%C3%A9-polyfill)

---

> Qual é o significado de Stream afinal de contas?

Fonte: [O que é stream?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227339/o-que-%C3%A9-stream) (3 perguntas mescladas)

---

> De onde surgiu e o que significa esse termo?

Fonte: [O que é memoização? [duplicada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175412/o-que-%C3%A9-memoiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o/175413#175413) (foque na resposta. Essa sim é digna de estar na comunidade [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)).

---

Acho que já ficou explícito minha indignação com o fechamento da minha pergunta.

Se estes exemplos não foram suficientes para comparar à minha pergunta, tem muitas outras. Basta [buscar os termos relacionados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=significado%20termo%20palavra) na comunidade...

Answer (score 11):

Podemos.

Desde que o termo tenha um significado especial em desenvolvimento de software. Se o termo precisa de uma explicação técnica. Se pode ser obtido através de um dicionário e tem o mesmo significado de outras áreas aí não vejo porque estaria no nosso escopo, se estiver então qualquer palavra pode ser usada como pergunta. Somos uma comunidade técnica de programação e afins, não de linguística. Precisaria ter uma necessidade específica na área, ter algo que exija uma descrição que não está no dicionário, ou que o uso não seja óbvio quando usamos na nossa área.

Obviamente que isso cabe interpretação. E é claro que o leigo tem mais dificuldade de avaliar isto.

> Há um tempo eu foquei meus estudos na orientação a objetos. Com isso, li vários artigos sobre o assunto. Até que em um destes artigos tinha um método da classe denominado popula(...)

Isto indica que o termo é usado no código não que ele seja técnico.

> Os colegas da comunidade logo comentaram solicitando mais detalhes sobre a pergunta

Sim a pergunta estava muito mal formulada e apesar de usar a a palavra contexto no título não dava contexto.

> Junto ao fechamento da pergunta, recebi a singela recomendação do moderador:

E a recomendação não deixou claro que o termo pode ser facilmente encontrado no dicionário referência de português na internet? E que o significado é óbvio e adequado para a nossa área?

> É normal vermos/ouvirmos termos até mesmo "aportuguesados" vindo de pessoas com os mais altos níveis de conhecimento

Nós somos uma comunidade técnica de programação. Quando a pessoa é iniciante na língua portuguesa, aí a comunidade mais adequada é a https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/. Nós vemos todos os dias usuários do SOpt com dificuldades para programar porque não sabem o português (entre outras coisas, como a matemática por exemplo). Não acho que devemos resolver esse problema. Precisamos ficar no nosso foco que é programação. Se pode esta, pode qualquer pergunta do dicionário, e quem sabe sobre receitas culinárias, afinal os programadores devem saber cozinhar um pouco também, ou devem saber porque o Samsung não está batendo uma foto.

> O que significa PSR?

Não achei no dicionário: https://dicionario.priberam.org/PSR. Me parece absolutamente técnica e só um programador pode responder. Só acha em documentação específica da área.

> O que significa Assets?

Não tem no dicionário: https://dicionario.priberam.org/assets. E me parece que o termo tem um significado especial em programação. Procurando no Google não achei nada nas primeira páginas que se referisse ao uso em desenvolvimento de jogos.

> O que é Polyfill?

Procurei e não achei: https://dicionario.priberam.org/pollyfil. Lendo ali parece que há um significado próprio, e de maneira alguma é uma definição de dicionário, explica um mecanismo técnico.

> O que é stream?

Também não achei: https://dicionario.priberam.org/stream. É um recurso muito usado na programação, e tem uma necessidade de explicação absolutamente técnica, como pode ser visto na postagem lá, não é uma explicação de dicionário que vai resolver.

> O que é memoização?

Mais uma que não tem: https://dicionario.priberam.org/memoizar.

A pergunta *linkada* é péssima, e a resposta não é das melhores e por bem está fechada. Mas note que teve que recorrer à Wikipedia em inglês, e o artigo é todo sobre programação e não sobre algo geral. É um termo da **nossa** área, e não um termo em português, ou mesmo inglês, que por acaso é usado na nossa área sem significado especial.

Veja [O que é memoization?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/101). Uma explicação técnica e contextual foi dada, aqui tem algo útil para o programador.

E [Como implementar memoização em uma função PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104014/101) não fala em termo, nem possui a *tag* para isso. E não é por acaso.

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=significado%20termo%20palavra

Olhando os primeiros resultados que realmente pediam o significado de termos parecem todos sobre programação. Se algum não for, deveria ser fechado. E o fato de não terem sido fechados é só uma falha da comunidade, se tem algum que seja só uma definição linguística e não gere confusão para o programador que entende nossa língua e sabe usar um dicionário.

Enfim, se usar a lógica de que esta pergunta é sobre programação, a próxima pergunta será:

> Li em algum lugar que a pessoa está "escrevendo um código", então venho aqui perguntar para programadores o que significa "escrever"

O mesmo poderíamos falar sobre "deletar" que todo mundo dizia que não existia. Por muito tempo não fui ver no dicionário, quando fui ver, tinha, não sei quando entrou, mas se entrou não é um termo puramente técnica, e que a sua definição no dicionário é suficiente para todos entenderem o que é. Não há uso específico na nossa área. O que inviabiliza o argumento (que por sinal também é um contra argumento à postagem do autor):

> Um exemplo clássico é a palavra "digitar". Foi introduzida no nosso vocabulário há pouco tempo. Até então, o termo correto era "datilografar". Mas tal termo limita-se às antigas "máquinas de escrever".

Alguém pode discordar, mas não parece que a sua pergunta seja de programação, que mesmo depois de edições não está na melhor forma (e por isso talvez tenha os negativos e que foram dados até antes dela). A pergunta original mostra confusão linguística do AP e não dúvida sobre programação. Havia uma resposta que tentava dar uma definição formal de dicionário. As discussões (já apagadas) lá foram nesse sentido, não havia direcionamento para que fosse um assunto de programação.

> Acho que já ficou explícito minha indignação com o fechamento da minha pergunta.

Sim, ficou explícito que a dúvida aqui não é sobre se aceitamos significado de termos ou não, a postagem é sobre a indignação da sua pergunta ter sido fechada.

Comment: Tantos **Não achei no dicionário** poderiam ser achados buscando as palavras **em inglês** nos **dicionários em inglês**. Em resumo: busquei o conhecimento da palavra **comum** entre programadores e que **em grande parte** dos dicionários de português não tem seu significado. Então, um **programador** que, normalmente, usa tal palavra, poderia formular uma resposta explicando o sentido (como foram feitos alguns comentários), mostrando exemplos e etc... Sobre o dicionário: ele está para dúvidas de português (e outras) da mesma forma que a documentação está para o programador. [...]

Comment: *"- Podemos. Desde que o termo tenha um significado especial em desenvolvimento de software."* Pelo que o dicionário citado na sua resposta explica: "***[Informática]**  Preencher com conteúdo (ex.: depois de criar o gráfico, é preciso populá-lo com os dados).* Esse texto seria um excelente início de resposta na minha pergunta. Mas ainda tem um porém: *"- Obviamente que isso cabe interpretação.* Após o comentário do Bacco, entendi bem o significado. Só que a pergunta não vai ficar lá para futuros interessados no significado do termo, pois "interpretaram como fora de escopo". Pergunta removida.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual o significado do termo “canônico” no contexto de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260464/qual-o-significado-do-termo-can%C3%B4nico-no-contexto-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1) Achei em todos os dicionários que busquei, por mais que alguns estendam o significado (que acaba batendo com sua resposta na pergunta).

Comment: @LipESprY essa trisca a linha, mas ainda tem um significado específico para informática e programação e a resposta mostra isso.

Comment: E *popular* não tem significado específico para informática e programação quando empregado como verbo, **como cita o dicionário em questão**?

Comment: @LipESprY, não, é exatamente o que está no dicionário, sem nenhuma especifidade, nada que o dicionário já não tenha dito. Aparentemente você ainda não entendeu o problema, mas não sei mais como explicar, e na verdade depois das atitudes recentes nem tenho interesse mais, respondi com boa vontade, não espera receber retaliação por não responder o que desejava.

Comment: Desculpe-me se fui rude (no geral). Já me dou como "satisfeito" e peço que, por favor, não tome tudo isso como retaliação. Fiz este último comentário baseado na semelhança de tais peguntas. A final, abri essa pergunta buscando um **debate**. Acredito que em um debate é normal contradições de opiniões e ideias. Considerando que não vá ter reflexos futuros, vou votar para fechamento desta. Meus cumprimentos!

Comment: @LipESprY não estou falando do comentário.

Answer (score 3):

### Também já tive esse tipo de dúvida

Hoje estou muito menos ativo do que gostaria, mas a algum tempo atrás tive dúvidas da mesma natureza da que você apresentou.

Sinceramente eu também não entendia essa e outras "definições" aqui do SOpt. Levei alguns meses para ter uma ideia bem superficial delas, então vou compartilhar um pouco dessa minha experiência.

[*Não acho que esse seja o caso da sua pergunta especificamente, mas vale o adendo:*]

Cheguei à conclusão de que, apesar das abrangentes respostas, explicações e recorrência desse tipo de questionamento, os critérios adotados pela **COMUNIDADE** possuem uma pitada de subjetividade que exige a vivência **recente**, pelo menos **razoávelmente ativa** e **construtiva**.

E é aqui que coisa começou a clarear: Comunidade. O SOpt é uma comunidade virtual e naturalmente está em constante evolução, mas o objetivo da comunidade é o mesmo: ser referência de conteúdo técnico [em português] sobre desenvolvimento de software.

Uma mesma pergunta feita a dois anos e meio atrás pode não ser bem recebida pela comunidade de hoje e o contrário também é verdade. Até mesmo em um intervalo menor, dependendo de como a pergunta for formulada e qual a intenção impressa nela, a aceitação pode ser completamente divergente.

Algumas questões já abordam esse ponto por várias perspectivas diferentes, como você pode ver [nesse post bem antigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs).

### Sua pergunta

Por todos os motivos já expostos e talvez outros mais, entendo que a sua pergunta realmente não parece atender a um dos critérios mínimos da comunidade, que seria estar dentro do contexto.

Um dos times com o qual já trabalhei usava o termo `bacon` para referir-se a um método/classe/objeto qualquer cujo nome é irrelevante para o que está sendo discutido ou apresentado, e até escrevem pequenos trechos de código de exemplo com esse indivíduo. É tão somente uma sátira dos [*Foo e Bar*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139830/foo-e-bar-tem-algum-significado-especial) da vida. Apesar de soar estranho e das dúvidas que deve surgir em novos colaboradores, não faria sentido abordar isso como pergunta aqui no SOpt (diferentemente do caso 'FooBar' que está largamente difundida nos exemplos e até documentações oficiais de soluções).

Popular, povoar, preencher, alimentar ou hidratar são variações do que já vi por aí como nomes para métodos com a intenção que estou julgando ser o caso do seu 'problema', mas [desconsiderando as ponderações de clean-code] o nome do método em questão não está relacionado a uma técnica ou ferramenta de desenvolvimento de software, mas sim a uma ação qualquer dentro dele então não acho que seria útil aqui, mas certamente geraria assunto para algumas horas [no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

### Então...

Acredito que [a resposta do Maniero](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7559/podemos-perguntar-significado-de-certos-termos/7561#7561) já deu a resposta para todos os seus questionamentos específicos, porém vou tentar contribuir com alguns pontos para reflexão que podem te ajudar a - de fato - compreendê-las *by heart*:

1. Em geral, quando alguém da comunidade reage um tópico, a intenção é contribuir com a comunidade (não necessariamente com a pessoa), seja com uma crítica, uma pergunta, uma observação, um voto ou uma moderação;
2. Ser ativo na comunidade ajuda a amadurecer como membro da comunidade. Continue participando e possivelmente em breve você estará familiarizado com a cultura;
3. Entendemos sua indignação, mas isso não muda o fato de que a pergunta parece não se adequar aos requisitos atuais da comunidade. Se não estiver convecido, pergunte, exponha, questione e entenda o que a comunidade lhe retorna;
4. Se isso não for possível, pelo menos aceite que o interesse da comunidade não é gerar discussão (como em uma rede social), mas sim prover conteúdo técnico (como foi falado antes);
5. Caso considere uma opção, ignore o tema sobre o qual discorda e aproveite/foque nos que lhe agrega valor. Os dois lados (a comunidade e você) saem ganhando =).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: "*- Uma mesma pergunta feita a dois anos e meio atrás pode não ser bem recebida pela comunidade de hoje e o contrário também é verdade.*" é, acho que essa pergunta era pra ter sido feita há um tempo mesmo. Agora reflita o seguinte: Uma pessoa fica em dúvida do significado do termo mencionado quando relacionado à informática/programação. Daí vai no google e busca fundamentos para o entendimento. O que seria mais interessante: a) o usuário cair no SOpt com uma boa resposta; b) cair em diversos dicionários que nem sempre tem o termo? Obrigado pela resposta! ;)

Comment: A) , com certeza. O único problema é que o termo em questão não está relacionado à informática/programação. _Bacon_ também não estaria. Usar durante a programação não o torna parte da informática.

Comment: acho que você ainda não entendeu o real significado do termo em questão. Quando empregado como verbo, está diretamente ligado à informática. Tanto que TODOS os dicionários que documentam tal termo enfatizam a relação com a informática. Veja as respostas na [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5731/4692).

Comment: Hum... a resposta que você linkou tá show. A pergunta lá tá no lugar certo também. Mas concordo com você: estar no dicionário não é um critério sólido. Posso estar enganado, mas o que entendi ainda permanece: é um **problema de português** sobre um termo usado na informática. Viu a parte que comentei sobre "Hidratar"? Tem o mesmo sentido e as respostas linkadas reforçam que se trata do mesmo contexto da situação exemplificada.

Comment: Aí que tá, Diego. Se é um problema de português, pq as outras perguntas citadas não são tratadas como problemas de inglês, já que são termos em inglês? Comentei isso na resposta do Maniero. Dicionário, seja português ou inglês, está aí da mesma forma que a documentação das linguagens, ferramentas e afins...

Comment: @LipESprY, perfeito. Seu ponto está claro. Mas veja pelo seguinte ângulo: como está em uma das perguntas referenciadas, `Memoization é usar uma tabela de cache para evitar ter que recalcular o valor de uma função mais de uma vez` <- é uma técnica para resolver um problema. Ponto. Agora na outra: `..."popular" é um verbo que significa "preencher com conteúdo"...` <- é uma ação trivial, não uma técnica ou ferramenta. Por essa linha de raciocínio, também seria válido "por que falamos/escrevemos 'declarar' uma variável?", "o que é um bloco de código?" e afins. Entendo que isso não é razoável.

Comment: Isso foi o que quisemos dizer com "problema de português".

Comment: Ambos são considerados uma técnica / ação. Certo? *popular dados é importar do banco de dados (ou afim) e preencher alguma coisa com esses dados. Seja uma tabela, um objeto, uma variável ou afins.*

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88024/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-lipespry).