# Pergunta à procura de opiniões reaberta?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

A seguinte pergunta foi fechada com o motivo "principalmente baseadas em opiniões":

### [Nomes de identificadores - inglês ou português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/301/1)

Mais tarde no mesmo dia, a mesma foi editada de forma a alterar o seu conteúdo, tornando-a viável para obter uma resposta correta:

### [Devo escrever meu programa em inglês ou português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/301/2)

Ontem, a pergunta atingiu o número de votos necessário para ser reaberta.

Isto deixa-me confuso, pelo que venho aqui discutir o assunto de forma a que consiga entender o que fazer com perguntas deste género:

- A pergunta está com o título já indicado, que por si só dá logo indicação que vamos estar a trocar opiniões.
- Contudo, dando o beneficio da dúvida, podemos sempre ler o conteúdo da pergunta de forma a melhor entender o que está a ser perguntado:

  > Levando-se também em consideração que todo programador deve ter noções básicas de inglês, qual é o método preferido para a escolha do idioma que eu devo usar ao programar?

  O paragrafo que complementa o título, geralmente o paragrafo que apresenta uma pergunta, contínua a demonstrar uma forte dependência na opinião pessoal para se obter respostas.

  Por outro lado, também se pode observar uma forte sugestão a que a resposta correta seja "Escrever tudo em Inglês", que é verdadeiramente o que aconteceu nas respostas que li.

Com esta curta análise, questiono-me como pode uma pergunta primariamente baseada em opiniões ser reaberta, obter respostas e estando já com 18 votos no total geral!

---

**Porque não consigo "computar" isto:**

1. A minha principal confusão parte de um principio básico que pode ser lido em [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

   > You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
2. Sei e sou da opinião que algumas perguntas devem ser mantidas para enriquecer o site enquanto o mesmo dá os primeiros passos, mas afirmo a posição que tem sempre que existir sem margem para duvidas uma resposta correta ou ficamos com uma "salada russa" sem qualidade nenhuma.
3. Temos a seguinte pergunta META que visa definir o que está ou não está "on-topic" nesta fase inicial do site:

   #### [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

   Onde podemos ver que:

   > Produtividade pessoal e técnicas de administração do próprio trabalho.

   Está com 5 votos a negativo.

   Se a pergunta em questão deveria ser encaixada num outro tópico, por favor, qual e porquê?

<sup>Que fique claro que não tenho nenhum problema com o autor da pergunta ou a pergunta em si. Estou efetivamente a tentar entender o conceito em uso para gerir este tipo de perguntas.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**A minha visão:**

A pergunta ainda não está escrita da melhor forma possível mas ela foi suficiente para produzir resultados razoavelmente objetivos. Algum grau de subjetividade sempre pode existir, isso nunca foi negado. Desde que essa subjetividade traga algo útil e benéfico para tornar a internet melhor. Claro que tem respostas ruins que não foram bem votadas (talvez tiveram o voto do autor original para incentivar quem respondeu a pergunta dele)

O meu entendimento é que o SOpt será **um pouco** mais permissivo do que o SO. Se isso não for o que a comunidade quer, não terei problemas com isso.

Fui um dos que reabriu a pergunta até para ver o que acontece. Não me pareceu que a intenção é iniciar uma discussão, que é o principal problema de questões subjetivas. Eu consigo ver uma resposta razoavelmente objetiva sobre o assunto. Provavelmente eu deveria ter editado antes de reabrir como fiz agora.

Não vou conseguir achar agora, mas já vi o Joel defendendo esse tipo de pergunta. Claro que é possível eu ter interpretado erroneamente se ela se caixa em todos os critérios. Também já vi o Jeff dizendo, se não me engano no Meta do Programmers, que às vezes é bom esperar algumas respostas para ver se as pessoas entenderam e conseguem responder a pergunta antes de fechá-la (nem eu sei bem se isso é bom, mas é algo para se pensar).

Respondendo aos pontos:

1. O que está escrito na FAQ **não é o nosso texto**, é quase um *placeholder* copiado **do SO**, nós teremos que definir o que terá lá. Isso ainda não foi definido, até onde eu sei.
2. Isso já está decidido definitivamente? Eu até concordo com a posição em sua essência mas não sei se todos concordam. Quero lembrar que uma quantidade imensa das perguntas do SO tem respostas não tão únicas assim e isso não é exatamente um problema. Concordo que é preciso estabelecer uma linha, acho que ela ainda não foi estabelecida.
3. Não acho que esse assunto tenha relação com o que está no tópico ou não, mas de qualquer forma não vejo essa pergunta exemplo se encaixando no item apresentado. Vejo como uma técnica de programação e portando no tópico. Não vejo muita diferença para [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-variaveis-globais-sao-do-mal) ou [Quais as implicações de não declarar variáveis em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/841/quais-as-implicacoes-de-nao-declarar-variaveis-em-php) (estão um pouco melhor redigidas, claro)

Isso não é minha posição definitiva. Estou aberto para redefinição e qualquer apontamento que estou errado, tranquilamente vejo isso como uma possibilidade.

Talvez a real questão é se vamos ser tão rígidos ou não quanto a isso. O Gabe deu alguns parâmetros em [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com) e [Como construir o site que você quer ser quando crescer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-construir-o-site-que-voce-quer-ser-quando-crescer) que nós ainda **estamos discutindo**. Não estou dizendo que devemos seguir as diretrizes colocadas ali, até onde eu entendo, elas não foram impostas.

Vejo um debate entre a rigidez encontrada principalmente no SO, que eu sempre fui contra, e o que parece ser uma visão mais aberta do pessoal do SE, declarada pelo Gabe onde os principais critérios são:

> - **Essa pergunta torna a internet um lugar melhor?**
> - **Ela aumenta ou diminui o número de programadores que podem se beneficiar do site?**

Destaco alguns pontos:

> - Perguntas menos rígidas sobre boas práticas ou como aprender mais sobre um assunto. Desde que essas perguntas não envolvam somente discussões sobre opiniões pessoais. Questões amplas, não-específicas, não costumam dar certo no Stack Exchange.

e

> - **Essa pergunta vai ajudar outros programadores?** Se a resposta for sim então melhor que sejam permitidas, sempre observando os tipos de perguntas que continuam a ser benéficas para o site, e quais estão criando problemas.
> - **Edite e encoraje.** Encoraje novos usuários sempre que possível. Se você vir um post incompleto, faltando algo que você saiba, evite só deixar um comentário falando que o post está errado. Se você tiver tempo, tente algo como: “Eu vi que faltavam alguns detalhes sobre os quais eu tenho conecimento, então eu editei o post para adicioná-los. Espero que ajude”. A qualidade dos posts é fundamental para o sucesso do site, então é preciso que os novos usuários sejam encorajados a sempre melhorar.

Para não ficar "em cima do muro", aceito o que o Gabe colocou, **minha posição** é que podem ser aceitas perguntas mais abertas, sem exagero, sem dar a possibilidade de discussão ou opiniões sem base.

Mas não quero ver os especialistas se afastarem por causa disso. Eu teria uma outra pergunta: Será que todo o barulho feito no SO, não foram causados por poucas pessoas? Eu vejo alguns dos maiores especialistas não se importarem com esse tipo de pergunta.

A sua pergunta é muito pertinente e quero ouvir a opinião de todos. Infelizmente está faltando mais participação dos membros. Seria ruim, 3 ou 4 pessoas decidirem o que vai acontecer.

Comment: Muito interessante essas abordagens. Claro que perguntas desse tipo *podem* gerar opiniões, mas também boas propostas. Depende do nível de quem responde. Por exemplo, todo mundo sabe que o padrão em Java é usar `CamelCase` e não `underline_para_nomes`. Isso é uma boa prática quase unânime, mas ao mesmo é bem subjetivo e é diferente em outras linguagens. No caso específico da pergunta sobre identificadores, eu gostaria muitíssimo que alguém propusesse um padrão nacional para nomear elementos de código ou pelo menos gostaria de saber de alternativas que eu não conheço.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo plenamente, acredito que por mais que este tipo de pergunta gere respostas boas, se o nosso direcionamento é ser objetivo, considerando que o SO Português é um site Q&A e não um Fórum para debates, devemos inibir este tipo de questionamento, visto que em outros casos, perguntas já foram fechadas por também terem as mesmas características, por que essas tem que ser diferentes? Acho que devemos criar um padrão aqui, se for liberado qualquer tipo de pergunta, no sentido de ser um problema ou discussão, ok, independente do que for decidido, democraticamente é claro, isso tem que ficar bem claro e deve ser seguido em todos os casos, não somente em casos isolados.

OBS. Essa é minha opinião, não tenho objetivo de contrariar ninguém, apenas estou expondo meu ponto de vista.