# Não temos moderadores?

Tags: debate

Ao explorar o site durante o beta privado, uma dúvida me surgiu:

**Nós não temos moderadores?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que [aqui não é o stackoverflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com), mas no site-pai existe uma página que exibe os moderadores do site. Na verdade, qualquer site da rede SE, como o SuperUser ou o Ask Ubuntu tem [páginas](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators) [similares](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators).

Mas ao abrir [a página correspondente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) aqui no SOPT, ela aparece vazia!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No momento não temos moderadores nomeados ou eleitos, apenas os moderadores da equipe mesmo (no caso o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) é quem pode moderar de forma efetiva por causa da língua) que não são listados nessa página.

Acredito, se o processo for igual aos outros sites, que no momento que estivermos saindo do beta privado serão nomeados moderadores temporários para ajudar o trabalho. Nesses próximos dias o Gabe dá conta. E quando o site se formar em pelo menos 90 dias de beta aberto, aí eleições serão chamadas para definir moderadores definitivos. Os moderadores que podemos chamar "da comunidade" aparecerão nessa página quando forem definidos.