# Questões que falam de linha de comando podem ser aceitas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Recentemente respondi a uma questão que perguntava de um software especifico, porém a questão falava especificamente de `CMD` (linha de comando usada no Windows).

**Questão:** [Ocultar nomes dos arquivos na hora da compactação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50660/3635)

Inicialmente a questão mostra-se fora do escopo, como relatado pelos demais usuários e por isto está suspensa, pois aparentemente fala do `7-zip`, porém tanto a resposta quanto a questão não pedem realmente algo com o `7-zip`, mas sim com o `CMD`, ou seja um comando que pode ser usado em qualquer "script" `.bat`, no caso a minha resposta foi o seguinte comando: `> NUL:` o que é uma comando de `cmd` e assim como outras perguntas/respostas semelhantes são comandos.

Alguns usuários afirmaram que por se tratar de uma resposta cujo a fonte é o http://superuser.com a resposta era mais off-topic ainda, porém notei que há algumas questões que foram bem aceitas pela comunidade por se tratarem de `.BAT` ou terminal [`Unix-like`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operacional_tipo_Unix), mesmo que a pergunta não fala-se diretamente de um script `.BAT` e sim do uso de um comando que pode ser usado em terminal (e que claramente pode ser reaproveitada em scripts):

- [Problema com SUDO "must be setuid root"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50738/3635)
- [Como buscar por arquivos antigos no Linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50692/3635)
- [Windows Ping deve retornar somente os valores de resposta dos pacotes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42535/windows-ping-deve-retornar-somente-os-valores-de-resposta-dos-pacotes)
- [Como transformar a saída de um comando numa variável no CMD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41942/como-transformar-a-sa%C3%ADda-de-um-comando-numa-vari%C3%A1vel-no-cmd)
- [Deletar arquivo por linha de comando com tipo diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11852/3635)
- [Acessar remotamente outra máquina unix com o Vim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32507/3635)
- [Pegando Output History do Terminal no Ubuntu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31421/3635)
- [Existe um "sudo" para Windows?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21655/3635)

Está última questão por exemplo [Existe um "sudo" para Windows?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21655/3635) pergunta sobre `sudo` no Windows, apenas a resposta foca em um script `batch`, mas apenas como uma "dica".

### O que quero dizer é:

Devemos fechar questões (incluindo antigas) cujo a resposta é um comando usado em `terminal` ou `cmd` e não um script realmente?

Comment: [+1 nova pergunta para a lista](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50738).

Comment: @renan obrigado

Comment: Vou comprar um monitor novo para programar, quantas linhas verticais ele deve ter por polegada para melhor legibilidade do código fonte, considerando a distância de 60cm entre eu e a tela? (Obviamente que é dentro de escopo, afinal a dúvida é 100% voltada à programação). /s

Comment: @Bacco Entendi rs, na verdade é dentro do escopo para alguns e fora para outros, na verdade a minha questão é o que devemos fazer com a questões que estão "fora do escopo" porém ainda "ativas", existem casos e casos ao meu ver, realmente só estava querendo formar uma opinião sobre o assunto e nunca afirmei que algo estava realmente dentro do "escopo" a afirmação nunca existiu por parte de ninguém. A minha pergunta na verdade foca que muitas questões "parecem" estar fora do escopo. :) Ao menos foi isso que eu tentei me fazer entender.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fique tranquilo, pois deu pra entender sim. Só quis deixar mais evidente o centro do problema para os leitores em geral perceberem como não é tão simples aceitar algo simplesmente por que vai ser usado para programar.

Answer (score 8):

A questão é maior que isso, falar ou não em *batch* não é o que define se a pergunta está dentro do escopo. [Quando falei sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50660/ocultar-nomes-dos-arquivos-na-hora-da-compacta%c3%a7%c3%a3o#comment102936_50660) naquela pergunta, eu estava pensando alto sobre o motivo do fechamento. Na verdade, eu demorei pra perceber que o problema ali é mais simples: a pergunta não é sobre programação.

Você mesmo citou algumas perguntas envolvendo *batch* e que não são sobre programação. A do `sudo` no Windows eu achei um exemplo interessante. Claramente não é sobre programação. Mas eu fui olhar a pergunta e vi que até tinha votado a favor dela e de algumas das respostas. E hoje discordo do meu próprio voto. Já vou explicar por quê.

Considerando a nossa [definição de escopo](/help/on-topic), o único item que dá margem a aceitar perguntas assim é o "ferramentas comuns entre programadores". Certo, terminais são usados com frequência pela maioria dos programadores. Mas o terminal nada mais é que uma interface para executar programas. Numa leitura estrita, aceitar perguntas sobre terminal significa aceitar perguntas sobre qualquer um desses programas. E no meio disso tem um monte de perguntas que divide opiniões.

O que temos hoje é uma baita confusão. Não existe muita coerência entre o que está aberto e o que está fechado, então é fácil encontrar exemplos para usar como "precedente" em qualquer argumentação. Acho que a maioria dos usuários deve concordar que se existisse um [Super User](http://superuser.com) em Português, ele seria o lar dessas perguntas. Elas parecem fora de lugar em um site que se diz *sobre programação*.

Acontece que não existe um Super User em Português, e [aqui não é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%c3%83o-%c3%89-o-stackoverflow-com). Isso fez com que gente que no fundo gostaria de fechar essas perguntas acabasse tolerando pelo menos uma parte delas. É o meu caso. Só que agora o site já tem um ano de beta público e o que eu vejo é que essas perguntas parecem cada vez mais alienígenas. Eu não acho que valha a pena debatermos, dentro do universo "terminal", o que seria aceito e o que não seria. É mais fácil dizer que nada vale. Claro que sempre haverá exceções, mas uma ou outra, e não a bagunça generalizada que vemos hoje nessas perguntas.

Acho que a Stack Exchange deveria começar a pensar seriamente em criar um Super User em português. Seria um site com potencial de público até maior que o nosso, eu tenho certeza. Até porque os usuários nem precisariam ser tão *super* assim para perguntar lá, como no SU original. Isso abrigaria perguntas gerais sobre o uso de software e hardware, incluindo essas perguntas que aqui parecem fora do lugar.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, só uma duvida que eu acho que ninguém respondeu ainda, devemos fechar questões antigas semelhantes (depois de analisar)? Obrigado

Comment: Acho que ainda não chegamos a um consenso sobre esse tipo de pergunta (apesar da minha opinião e da proposta do bigown de SUpt). Mas se a maioria concordar que essas questões estão fora do escopo, eu fecharia as antigas também.

Comment: Entendi, como ainda não tem uma resolução o melhor é aguardar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Toda vez que vejo esses debates sobre um assunto ser permitido no site eu sinto que, a favor ou contra, as respostas tendem a se fixar em pontos relevantes mas pouco determinantes. Além disso, o debate constantemente acaba orbitando o que o SOen fez ou deixou de fazer. Isso também é importante, mas não pode ser determinante.

Vejo muita discussão sobre qual seria o nível *exato* de granularidade da definição de escopo, de forma a permitir que apenas as perguntas boas sejam aceitas. Uma regra mais específica tende a ser menos permissiva e gerar mais casos fora dela. Por outro lado, uma regra muito ampla é difícil de ser aplicada quando necessário. Tudo isso, como sabemos, vai gerar **Caos e Destruição™**.

Não quero dizer que esse debate é inútil. Longe disso. Mas ele não deve ser o determinante. Pra mim, grande parte dessas discussões perde vista do seu *propósito*. Onde esse debate quer chegar? Que problema ele quer solucionar? Qual deve ser o resultado final?

O propósito é criar uma regra ou ajudar o site? Se o propósito é ajudar o site, qual dessas abordagens tem o maior potencial de conseguir isso? Pode parecer que eu estou reescrevendo o óbvio, e que todo mundo aqui já sabe disso, mas é incrivelmente fácil perder isso de vista e começar a se preocupar mais com a perfeição da regra que com o problema que ela deveria solucionar. As vezes qualquer regra pode só piorar o problema. As vezes o problema sequer existe.

Acredito que todo mundo aqui tem uma resposta boa pra pergunta anterior... O propósito é <strike>criar uma re</strike> **ajudar o site!** Concordo. E, como todos sabemos, o propósito do site é... hum... Eu não acho que há nada próximo de um acordo em relação a isso. É uma pena mas, de qualquer maneira, seria impossível haver um. O jeito é tocar em frente.

Na minha opinião o propósito do site é "ajudar o máximo possível o maior número de programadores". O propósito não é "emular o SOen". Não é "coerência absoluta entre as perguntas". Não é "ter várias perguntas avançadas/intermediárias/básicas". Não é "ter o mais coerente, abrangente e perfeito conjunto de regras da internet". O propósito é **ajudar programadores**.

Mantendo isso em mente, e usando as perguntas citadas na pergunta:

- Todas tem upvotes. Apenas 2 tem 1 downvote. Todas tem pontuação positiva.
- Todas tem respostas. Só uma tem respostas sem votos. 5/8 tem respostas aceitas.
- Todas, mesmo as suspensas, são problemas de verdade. Quase todas, na minha opinião, são bem formadas, claras e bem escritas.

O único lugar onde elas "falham" é em não atender *totalmente* à expectativa de escopo do site. Digo "expectativa de escopo" porque, concretamente, nosso [on-topic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) diz:

> problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software

E sim, essa guia é incrivelmente ampla. E essa é a ideia. Tanto que ela é a mesma existente no [SOen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Não há nada de errado com uma regra pouco específica. Se a sua abordagem for "como interpretar esta regra de maneira a chegar no meu objetivo", ao invés de "como aplicar esta regra", ela serve o seu propósito. Nosso site não tem um código criminal, tem uma *magna carta*. É uma diferença filosófica, mas importante.

Isso me leva à segunda parte, sempre trazida à tona nessas discussões, de que "se a gente permitir perguntas de lista, o que impede alguém de casar com uma mesa de jantar?" (ou algo do tipo). Deixando de lado a discussão sobre se esse argumento é ou não falacioso, também é possível prover uma guia simples se tivermos em mente o **propósito** do site.

Sob o meu ponto de vista, se o site é para programadores, as perguntas devem ser feitas **e** respondidas por programadores. Então podemos olhar para as perguntas e pensar "qual  a probabilidade de um programador responder isso? Quantos programadores seriam capazes de responder isso?". Uma pergunta sobre cálculo da alíquota de imposto, ou lei de propriedade intelectual, mesmo quando tem a ver com programação (como exemplificado pelo bigown) caem fora do domínio geral de computação. Uma contadora ou advogada seriam capazes de dar respostas muito melhores que programadores.

Estas perguntas de linha de comando caem dentro do domínio de computação. A chance de uma programadora responder é bastante alta. A utilidade dela para outros programadores é bastante alta. A pergunta ajuda programadores. Se ajuda programadores, ajuda o site. Se ajuda o site e está dentro das regras, eu não vejo problema.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, principalmente do final, fez eu expandir os meus horizontes de pensamento e espero que faça isto para os outros usuários.

Comment: Ninguém falou nem em "caos e destruição", nem em "emular o SOen", nem em perfeição de regras. Nenhuma regra é perfeita, mas clareza ajuda muito. É preciso pelo menos *tentar* traçar uma linha em algum lugar. Então tudo que tem a ver com computação e que provavelmente um programador sabe responder deve ficar aberto? Eu não gosto da ideia, mas se for isso que a comunidade quer, tudo bem. Nesse caso, vou perguntar se casar com uma mesa de jantar resolve um problema no meu pente de memória.

Comment: @bfavaretto Provavelmente não. Pentes de memória são historicamente mesadejantarfóbicos.

Comment: Acho que mesas de jantar preferem aquelas escovinhas [papa-migalhas](http://www.catalogodachina.com.br/escova-papa-migalhas-reservatorio-p-395.html).

Comment: Como posso instalar uma memoria RAM no meu PC? É *on-topic* Gabe? Então podemos olhar para as perguntas e pensar "qual a probabilidade de um programador responder isso? Quantos programadores seriam capazes de responder isso?".

Comment: Eu diria que quase todos os programadores saberiam responder a isso, diz respeito ao desenvolvimento de software como dizem perguntas sobre Sistemas Operativos e linha de comandos.

Comment: @JorgeB. É meio triste que a resposta ao que eu escrevi seja ficar tentando encontrar "pegadinhas" pra tentar invalidar o que eu falei, ao invés de efetivamente tratar do problema. De qualquer maneira, se essa pergunta ocorresse, além de ela estar alguns passos mais longe do desenvolvimento de software do que uma pergunta sobre ambiente de sistemas operativos, ela não é uma pergunta de software, e acho que isso é uma boa medida. Dito isso, se alguém fizer a pergunta, e ela tiver uma boa resposta e for bem votada, ótimo.

Comment: @Gabe não é tentar encontrar "pegadinhas", é tentar fazer ver que, (a meu ver) temos de manter um escopo que REALMENTE tenha a ver com programação. Se essas perguntas começassem a ser aceites tenho a certeza que ia afastar a maioria dos programadores. Afinal a ideia do SOpt é ser para programadores e pessoas interessadas em programação? Ou uma central de ajuda a trabalhar com Sistemas Operativos? Ou tudo junto. Eu ainda não percebi se nós, comunidade é que decidimos isso, ou se é o SE, representado por ti, que decide?

Comment: Se é o SE que decide é diferente. Eu sempre fiquei na ideia que o SOpt teria o privilégio de poder escolher o escopo do site. Pelo que vejo a maioria não concorda com perguntas deste tipo. Alias até surgiu a ideia do SUpt por causa disto mesmo, e pelo que me parece a proposta está a ser muito bem recebida pela comunidade.

Comment: Vamos falar do problema. O que vemos é uma falta de consenso sobre essas perguntas, alguns votam para fechar e outros preferem mantê-las abertas. Gosto de pensar que isso expressa a opinião das pessoas em relação àquilo que elas querem que o site seja, e não que quem vota para fechar esteja necessariamente seguindo às cegas regras ditadas por fulano ou cicrano (embora isso também exista). Então temos uma comunidade dividida. Eu espero que esta discussão aqui no meta sirva para indicar se a comunidade pende para um ou para o outro lado. Isso ficando claro, decide-se o destino das perguntas.

Comment: Já fomos obrigados a aceitar aquelas perguntas de lista (pelo shog se não me engano) apesar de quase ninguém estar de acordo com elas... E o discurso continua sempre o mesmo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Seu comentário não visou nada do que você disse. Ele só tentou encontrar um caso bastante particular (e quase extremo) pra descaracterizar o que eu falei. O SOpt, como qualquer outro site da rede, tem autonomia para definir bastante sobre si mesmo, e isso acontece na maioria das vezes. Não significa que o site é independente e que pode ir de encontro ao que a SE mantém para o site. E discordo absolutamente que a "maioria não concorda com perguntas desse tipo". Basta ver como elas são recebidas.

Comment: Pergunta: se a proposta do SUpt for adiante e essas perguntas tiverem acesso ao sonho da casa própria, todos viverão felizes para sempre? Eu acredito que sim, pelo menos no que diz respeito a este debate em particular.

Comment: @Gabe falei mesmo o caso extremo para refutar o "qual a probabilidade de um programador responder isso?". Acho que não é por ai o caminho. O caminho é mesmo por perceber se a comunidade aceita bem essas perguntas ou não. Agora, isso pode ser uma faca de 2 gumes... Quantas questões "amplas de mais", "não é claro o que está perguntado", etc são respondidas, são positivadas e são fechadas? Serão essas boas perguntas? deverão permanecer no site? A "comunidade" está de acordo com essas perguntas?

Comment: Eu não sei se compreendi errado, mas o que me deu a entender é que o Gabe disse seria sobre questões que geralmente são aproveitadas na área da programação, por exemplo um comando de terminal que possa ser executado "dentro de um aplicativo" e não para o programador, mas posso ter entendido mal.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim. Mas esse é um **se** enorme (não pelo potencial da proposta, mas porque outro site em PT precisa passar pelo nosso crivo, e eu não sei qual seria o resultado)

Comment: @Gabe só uma última questão esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50738/problema-com-sudo-must-be-setuid-root pela tua forma de analisar deveria ser aceite no site, certo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que você entendeu errado :)

Comment: A mim essa pergunta me parece bem fora do escopo dum site de perguntas e respostas de PROGRAMAÇÃO. Talvez num site de informática, Sistemas Operativos, Super User, sei lá...

Comment: Além do mais ao aceitar esse tipo de perguntas, o SOpt ia acabar por se transformar num site de ajuda e não de programação. É o meu ponto de vista.

Comment: @JorgeB. e demais eu já falei tudo o que eu tinha para falar na minha resposta, eu não vou insistir porque já aprendi que é improdutivo, nós estamos errados, nós somos teimosos e eu poderia citar aqui uma lista de defeitos que nós temos e fazemos de errado. Eu só queria mesmo é dizer que o SUpt surgiria de qualquer forma. É a segunda vez que tento ele. A primeira não era para sair mesmo. Foi um erro eu ter tentando criar versões de vários *sites* de sucesso em inglês. **O SUpt não é *spin-off* do SOpt**. É outra coisa que por acaso interessa também aos usuários do SOpt.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não acho ruim discutir estas coisas. Eu dei meu ponto de vista sobre o site, pra que ele serve e como deveria funcionar. E seus comentários iniciais não tentavam expor ou progredir a conversa, mas se valiam de uma interpretação conscientemente errada para tentar descaracterizar o que eu falei. Não é assim que esse assunto vai ter solução. Além disso não há nada intrinsecamente ruim, ou errado, com o SOpt permitir perguntas que seriam mais voltadas a um eventual SU. A separação dos sites não necessariamente foi um processo bem sucedido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que você entendeu certo. Eu quis dizer coisas que sejam relevantes para o programador no decorrer comum do ato de programar. As coisas tangenciais que nós sabemos e aprendemos que nos fazem avançar na área. Instalação e memória não tem muito a ver com isso, e é uma descaracterização do que eu disse.

Comment: "Eu dei meu ponto de vista sobre o site, pra que ele serve e como deveria funcionar. E seus comentários iniciais não tentavam expor ou progredir a conversa, mas se valiam de uma interpretação conscientemente errada para tentar descaracterizar o que eu falei." É a tua interpretação @Gabe. Eu tentei fazer ver o meu ponto de vista. Não é preciso ser muito iluminado para ver isso. Se eu quisesse descaracterizar o que disseste não continuava a responder...

Comment: Como disse @Gabe, é a minha opinião e acho que a de quase todos aqui. O ter alguns votos e algumas respostas não quer dizer nada por si só. De qualquer forma já deixei a minha opinião bem clara. Se querem tornar o SOpt num fórum de informática, força nisso, mas quando isso acontecer não contém comigo. Sinto muito orgulho em pertencer a esta comunidade, e manter a qualidade do site, e a comunidade a "dirigi-lo" para mim é o essencial.

Comment: Gabe, eu reli sua resposta e não consigo enxergar que esteja falando de "coisas que sejam relevantes para o programador *no decorrer comum do ato de programar*". Acharia até melhor que não estivesse, porque acho que esse critério complica muito as coisas (ver a resposta do @bigown e meu primeiro comentário aqui, onde falo sobre traçar uma linha mais clara).

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que foi no momento que ele disse "se ajuda o programador", é algo implícito e não explícito, não estou defendendo nada só explicando o porquê deste entendimento do meu ponto de vista. Claro que podia estar mais explícito e concordo com quase todos os seu pontos de vista, a ideia é só tentar dar uma ideia de analisar a questão conforme a utilidade, não que isso seja uma regra hoje ou que venham ou não ser amanhã, soa apenas como uma sugestão por parte dele. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pode ser que seja necessário mais explícito, mas acho que "ajudar o programador **enquanto ele programa** seria excessivo. No final das contas, tudo que eu quis dizer é que perguntas de linha de comando ajudam programadores *a programar*. Se ajudam a programar, são úteis para programadores, podem ser respondidas por outros programadores, então sim. Acho que elas devem ser aceitas no site. O bfavaretto discorda, porque ele diverge do **propósito** do site que eu tenho, o que não tem problema nenhum.

Comment: @Gabe sobre a parte de programar foi exatamente o que eu quis dizer é concordo contigo também, apesar de ainda estar formando uma opinião mais concreta, pois todas opniões me parecem ter propósitos bons :)

Answer (score 4):

Concordo com tudo na resposta do @bfavaretto. Mas tem algo mais que devo dizer sobre o debate.

Isto já foi discutido antes aqui no meta e ficou definido (não tão claramente definido) que o uso de softwares está fora de cogitação, que era *off-topic*.

Nem mesmo se você circunstancialmente for usar este software para desenvolver o seu software. Se abrirmos esta brecha qualquer pergunta poderá ser feita aqui.

"Estou fazendo um software de química que quero saber como calcular a massa do elemento..."

"Estou desenvolvendo um instalador para meu software e está dando problema quando tento instalaro WarCraft que é necessário para meu software"

"Como renomeio o ícone de um software que eu desenvolvi?"

"Qual a alíquota do imposto do produto na circunstância X do ERP que eu estou criando?"

"Como processo uma pessoa que copiou o software que eu desenvolvi?"

"Como chamo o software X na linha de comando. Estou fazendo isto em *batch*"

A única coisa que estas perguntas têm em comum com programação é que o autor disse que vai usar o assunto em programação. Este tipo de problema é bem [conhecido na rede](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about).

O fato de você dizer que vai usar em programação não é suficiente para tornar um assunto *on-topic*. Se fizer isto, qualquer assunto é *on-topic*. E se ficar escolhendo quais assuntos não relacionados com programação são *on* ou *off*, fica arbitrário. Ou liberamos qualquer coisa e mudamos o nome do *site* para "Stack Exchange em Português" ou nos focamos de verdade em programação.

A decisão se uma pergunta é boa para o *site* ou não pode ser ser baseada na existência de uma palavra na pergunta.

Pense como seria ridículo uma pergunta ser fechada porque o assunto é claramente *off-topic*, aí vai alguém lá editar colocando que vai usar em programação de alguma forma. Aí tem que reabrir porque aí é *on*. Mas o autor reverte a edição porque ele não vai usar em programação e ele não conhece o "truque" de dizer que é programação para tornar *on*. Então a pergunta volta ser *off*. É a mesma pergunta.

É tão ridículo fazer isto quanto é dizer que só porque a palavra "melhor" foi usada em uma pergunta ela deva ser fechada por ser "baseada em opiniões". Tem que analisar o contexto do uso da palavra. Se realmente a pessoa quer saber qual é o melhor subjetivamente, ou se a pergunta só escolheu mal a palavra usada. Não podemos ser robóticos na análise.

A pergunta tem que ser analisada pelos méritos próprios. Não pode se valer de artifícios para definir o que fazer com ela. Mesmo que esteja escrito que é para programação, se você tirar isto, a pergunta ainda é de programação ou deixa de ser? Isto é que vale. Se uma pergunta tem a necessidade de explicitar que ela é de programação é porque ela **não é**. Perguntas verdadeiramente de programação deixam isto claro implicitamente.

Nem preciso mas vou reforçar que o erro cometido em outras perguntas não justificam que novos erros sejam cometidos. Muito menos devemos usar uma falha, a exceção, da comunidade em analisar bem alguma pergunta para dizer que isto é a regra.

Eu entendo que nem sempre é fácil analisar. É compreensível que erros aconteçam, que opiniões diferentes sejam colocadas. Mas é preciso ter uma regra. E de fato não podemos considerar que tudo é preto no branco. Mas isto só reforça o que eu disse que cada caso precisa ser analisado por si próprio. Não dá para criar uma regrinha de que se tiver uma palavra ou expressão na pergunta ela é *on-topic*. A regra é um pouco mais complexa que isto.

Bem, um dos motivos de haver algum interesse em ter essas perguntas é que elas não podem ser feitas em outros lugares. Provavelmente não poderemos admitir todos os assuntos na rede, nem mesmo em inglês parece que isto vai acontecer. Mas podemos ter *sites* para alguns assuntos. E eu segui a sugestão do bfavaretto. Está criada uma proposta de *site* em português. Participe!

## [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues)

Veja mais detalhes e [participe do debate aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101).

Comment: Sim o problema naquela nossa conversa foi quase este "Tem que analisar o contexto do uso da palavra". Algumas questões que usei de exemplo houve o seguinte argumento: "mas ali fala de programação". Se considerarmos a resposta chegar em um contexto de *on-topic* (ao invés de pergunta) então a minha resposta naquele *momento* foi válida, pois não se referenciava ao software, mas sim a uma instrução que é usada em `.bat`, NÃO estou falando que isto é justificativa e nem que outros erros me deram a brecha...

Comment: ...o que eu tentei deixar claro naquela nossa conversa foi que as perguntas usadas de exemplo, tiveram um pequeno trecho que apresentava algo de `.bat`, mas que não era o foco da pergunta ou nem necessáriamente fazia parte do contexto, eram mais para *dicas extras*, volto a tornar que não usei de justificativa nenhuma e que apenas estava tentando entender o contexto, mesmo quando ficou claro que as demais perguntas (como *você mesmo* disse agora) não foram devidamente analisadas e por uma simples frase *"vou fazer um .bat"* fez aparentar ser algo de *on-topic*...

Comment: ...portanto é isto o que eu quis dizer na conversa anterior, as demais questões abriram a oportunidade para *EU* (ou qualquer outro) responder achando que estava certo e o não fechamento delas reforçou isto, não fui eu o culpado, mas sim a **falta de analise** (como você mesmo disse) é que seria a real culpada da situação e foi isso que eu tentei justificar, em outras palavras: Eu não estava defendendo manter a questão, mas tentando explicar a situação. Espero que compreenda e obrigado pela sua resposta.

Comment: Não disse que você era culpado de nada. Apenas fiz um alerta para você entender a situação. Se ninguém alertar todo mundo fica agindo de boa fé mas criando situações que vão sendo perpetuadas até que se torna difícil resolver. Em nenhum momento eu disse que você estava agindo de má fé.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, apenas respondi ao trecho *Nem preciso mas vou reforçar que o erro cometido em outras perguntas não justificam que novos erros sejam cometidos.*,  soa (não só pra mim, mas para qualquer um que vier a ler) que *eu* estava confuso e que *eu* estava insistindo no erro.

Comment: Não sei se insistindo seria o termo, insistência é quando você sabe e faz assim mesmo. Quando não se sabe não é insistência.

Comment: Sobre o *trecho* (*o erro cometido em outras perguntas não justificam que novos erros sejam cometidos*): Quando eu respondi aquela pergunta seria o ERRO, mas quando eu comecei a conversar contigo (lá nos comentários), já não fazia parte do erro e estava claro que eu havia entendido o ponto e que o **foco da conversa** que eu tentei colocar era totalmente outro, mas acho que não me fiz claro devido ao foco *daquela pergunta* que talvez lhe confundiu e no momento que abri está questão já ficou bem claro que o problema é outro e o seu *trecho* distorce soa para outros que lerem como outra coisa.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que essa questão levantada seja um pouco mais ampla, existe também a extrapolação temática em outros momentos, como perguntas relacionadas configuração de dbs, apache, servidores, etc.. qualquer coisa que tenha alguma ligação ou possa ter com programação. Vendo dessa forma, seria muito complicado julgar quais perguntas fogem o escopo.

Eu acho que perguntas sobre tópicos que sejam de certa forma "longe" de programação, são validos desde que a pergunta tenha um contexto programável, ou seja, a pergunta precisa exprimir a "vontade" de usar aquilo com algum script/código, mas não necessariamente a resposta precisa ser um código.

Comment: É quase este o ponto que eu quero chegar.