# Votos a favor e votos contra no META. O que o voto significa para você?

Tags: debate, meta

Aqui no META, queria ver aqui se existe algum consenso nos votos, que tipo de "regra" você usa para dar o seu voto seja ele positivo ou negativo:

Por que acho importante discutir isso

Primeiro porque vi um comentário [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com#comment15695_698) e isso me chamou a atenção e fui procurar nas definições: [O que é o "meta"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Quando passamos o mouse em cima das setas, tem uma definição muito breve apenas "esta resposta é útil" ou "esta resposta não é útil".

Onde quero chegar com isso?

Quero que me digam se votos refletem a "**utilidade percebida**" isso não caminha junto com **"Os votos expressam acordo ou desacordo com a opinião passada na resposta"**.

Porque eu posso **não concordar** e mesmo assim achar a resposta **útil** e ai eu voto up ou voto down?

Talvez um ponto que gera dúvidas seja este:

> Nas publicações com a tag recurso-solicitação, a votação indica concordância ou discordância

É somente nessa tag que o voto significa concordância ou discordância, e nas demais é a utilidade percebida?

Comment: O que significa talvez não possa mais ser exposto, por imaturidade de alguns. Por exemplo, era uma prática comum comentar o por que de um downvote. Hoje em dia, se tiver que votar contra ou a favor, penso que é melhor ficar anônimo mesmo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters O que eu considero uma pratica ruim, pois se você cobra explicações, mas não explica, tecnicamente não esta sendo descompadecente? Compreendo que possa haver (há) perseguição, mas que é mais importante? receber conselhos, debates e criar um bom conteúdo, ou não se incomodar com 2,3 que possam reclamar?

Comment: Participar ativamente de uma comunidade é isso, você terá seus seguidores, mas também tera perseguidores, é igual Musica, tem as pessoas que gostam de Rock, tem as que gostam de Pagode, cara um tem uma personalidade. O que deve ser feito é aprender a respeitar o próximo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters errado, se você achar que deve comentar, comente. Não fique com medo de represálias.

Comment: Sinceramente eu não sei como julgar os votos aqui, e acabo tratando da mesma forma que no SO.

Answer (score 7):

> A pergunta original não tinha referências ao meta, mas perguntava sobre votos de forma feral. Já que agora ela referencia apenas ao meta, vou dividi-la em duas partes para não perder todo meu trabalho.

## No meta

No meta, os votos não tem a mesma conotação do site principal (do qual falo no próximo tópico), ou podem ter diferentes significados dependendo do tipo de pergunta.

Há um certo consenso de que os votos no meta são uma demonstração de que você concorda ou não com o que foi dito, não tendo necessariamente relação com a qualidade, formato, utilidade, etc.

Isso ocorre principalmente em discussões sobre o site, pois diferente de um problema técnico, elas geralmente tem como conteúdo a opinião dos usuários sobre um assunto.

Algumas conotações dos votos são:

- Apoio, votando positivo em alguma sugestão, pedido ou bug.
- Crítica, votando contra algo que você simplesmente não gostou de ter lido
- Utilidade, votando contra ou a favor de uma resposta de suporte ao uso do site
- Manifestação, votando contra ou a favor a um comunicado oficial do nosso querido gerente de comunidade

Enfim, depende do tipo de resposta você tem uma conotação diferente.

Entretanto, se para você o sentido do voto não for óbvio, deixe um comentário expressando sua opinião.

Assim como os votos, comentários e respostas no meta são diferentes do site principal. Aqui você não só pode, como deve deixar comentários e respostas expressando opiniões.

## No site principal

Se coloque no lugar de quem, num dia qualquer, acessa determina questão e lê suas respostas tentando encontrar a solução para algum problema.

Ao se deparar com a resposta aceita, automaticamente vem à mente algo como: *"se resolveu para o outro cara, deve resolver para mim também"*.

A maioria das pessoas, acredito eu, vai parar por aqui. As mais atentas e que conhecem o site, podem ainda bater o olhos nas outras respostas para ver se tem alguma outra opção ou comentário sobre o conteúdo.

Quando eu uso o SO em busca de uma resposta, primeiro eu quero resolver o problema, mas depois também desejo me certificar de que não existe alguma alternativa melhor ou mais recente, dos efeitos colaterais ou de possíveis armadilhas.

Pode ser que haja uma resposta bem votada que não está aceita. Mentes curiosas vão tentar entender o motivo.

As respostas negativas em geral nem serão lidas. Se houver uma única resposta e o saldo dos votos for negativo, pode ser que em alguns casos você até olhe para ver se tem alguma informação útil, mas em geral considera-se como se não houvesse resposta.

Até aqui, tudo funciona como esperado e a satisfação do visitante vai ser proporcional com a quantidade de perguntas com respostas boas.

Por outro lado, se houver uma resposta positiva, mas com qualidade ruim ou que não funciona, então eu vou me frustar lendo e tentando aplicar uma solução que só vai me causar problemas no futuro.

Também pode ser que uma resposta boa esteja negativada e assim passa despercebida, deixando de ajudar a quem pode. O usuário não perde tempo, mas também não fica feliz por não achar uma resposta.

Um caso à parte são respostas sem votos. Um visitante pode ficar na dúvida de vale a pena ler ou aplicar a resposta. Uma resposta de votos é como algo que não passou pelo crivo de ninguém. Corre-se o risco de perder tempo lendo algo ruim? E se depois eu me arrepender de ter usado ou aprendido algo útil?

Resumindo:

- Respostas úteis positivas levam mais gente para a solução e tornam o mundo um lugar melhor
- Respostas ruins negativadas filtram conteúdo e economizam nosso tempo
- Respostas ruins positivas são frustrantes
- Respostas úteis negativadas perdem a chance de ajudar a quem poderia
- Respostas sem votos causam tensão

Por isso, vote cedo e frequentemente.

Se houver ressalvas, mas achar que a conteúdo pode ser útil em algum contexto, deixe um comentário explicando o motivo. Por exemplo: *pode ser útil no caso X ou Y, mas tome cuidado com Z*.

Eu costumo fazer isso e dificilmente gera conflitos, pelo contrário, geralmente a pessoa arruma a resposta e então posso remover o comentário também.

Outra dica, se achar que faltou alguma informação, é adicionar um link para outra resposta ou artigo que complemente o assunto.

Comment: Não poderia estar mais de acordo +1.

Comment: Você se apercebeu que a pergunta se refere a votar em respostas a perguntas no META? E que a dúvida incide principalmente nas tags `debate` e `novo-recurso`?

Comment: Muito boa resposta, mas creio que se resume ao saldo dos votos, tem usuários que dizem que olham para ambos, ex.: 8/-5; tecnicamente na sua analise o saldo é 3, se caracterizando uma resposta boa/regular, mas os que tem acesso a ver 8/-5 vão disser ruim. Eu olho o saldo, e gosto de le o máximo possível, e analiso mais o conteúdo do que o próprio voto.

Comment: @ramaral até eu me esqueci desse pequeno grande pormenor... utluiz se puderes rever a tua resposta.

Comment: De facto o intuito da pergunta não estava muito claro no inicio, por isso o meu comentário para chamar a sua atenção para o facto de ela se referir ao meta.

Comment: Eu só acrescentei no título para evidenciar, mas no corpo já tinha "meta" desde a [versão 2](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/4788/revisions) (dia 21, ainda sem respostas). Mas realmente estava discreta a informação, por isso passou despercebida.

Comment: De qq forma, acredito que editada ela esteja suprindo ao que foi perguntado, a parte original serve de complemento.

Answer (score 3):

## Opinião

No site principal, em geral, espera-se que uma opinião venha acompanhada de fatos ou referências que deem suporte a ela. Se achamos que uma opinião técnica oferecida em uma resposta está errada, o voto negativo está aí pra isso.

No Meta, vários dos assuntos que tratamos são pura opinião "eu acho isto", "eu acho aquilo outro". Claro que se queremos convencer os demais, bons argumentos e exposição de fatos ajudam bastante. Votar + ou - é um jeito rápido de dizer *"Bom isso!"* ou então *"Que horror!"*

## Discordância

Reza a lenda que no Meta o voto negativo nas perguntas devia ser usado somente quando discordamos de um pedido de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso). E, claro, além das razões tradicionais que aparecem ao passar o mouse encima da setas de votação:

> + Esta pergunta mostra esforço de pesquisa; é útil e clara
> - Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil

e

> + Esta resposta é útil
> - Esta resposta não é útil

Nosso meta aqui é muito tranquilinho, não tem a avalanche de pedidos de suporte, discussão e novos recursos que tem no nosso *big brother* Stack Overflow. As demonstrações de preguiça, cara-de-pau e ignorância total pipocam de hora em hora lá no SOen Meta. Voto negativo voa fácil em qualquer tag. E lembrando também que tem sempre um monte de gente dando *feedback* e tentando ajudar.

## Reputação e a Vergonha do -1

No Meta **não existe reputação**, a gente pode tomar um milhão de votos negativos/positivos que isso não afeta em nada; a reputação aqui fica sincronizada com a do site principal. Só as medalhas funcionam por separado.

Particularmente, acho fantástico quando tem alguma coisa que discordo completamente e posso fazer -1. Em geral aqui no Meta faço +1 como manifestação de apoio por trazer um assunto novo pra discussão ou por ajudar com seu precioso tempo pra uma resposta "meta".

Como tem gente que acha que -1 é uma ofensa pessoal e uma mancha terrível no currículo, até aqui, onde o voto não significa *nada* em termos de reputação, de vez em quando saem coisas do tipo "VOCÊ ME VOTOU NEGATIVO, te odeio!". Tudo bem, a Terra continua dando voltas sem se importar um pepino com nossos egos feridos.