# Qual foi o problema ao publicar minha resposta?

Tags: debate

Essa publicação é referente há alguns pontos do [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) onde recentemente publiquei resposta numa pergunta de um usuário novo de lá, [Maior ou menor de idade [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/511175/maior-ou-menor-de-idade/511177#511177) contudo fui o primeiro a responde-la e segundo o usuário, teria sanado seu "problema". Fiz uma pré-descrição explicando o que foi inserido e/ou removido do código para que pudesse funcionar de forma correta.

Recebi **1** voto a favor! maravilha.. porém 30min depois um dos *Moderadores* ou *Usuário Antigo* fez basicamente a mesma resposta, inserindo apenas `//comments` no código e uma pré-descrição mencionando informações dadas por terceiro(a)s, e, em seguida minha resposta recebeu **-2** downvote e o *"um dos"* recebeu **4** votos a favor até então. Minha questão é: O que diferencia a resposta dele pra minha? se pelo próprio autor da publicação foi válida e que comentou minha resposta, ela estando correta e de certa forma agradecendo por "ter funcionado", quer dizer, eu não só fiz colar um código que funcionasse, em minha pré-descrição citei onde estava localizado o problema e em seguida corrigi explicando.. (não detalhadamente, mas de forma compreensível e clara)

O que não entendo é o porquê recebi downvote se minha resposta resolveu o problema do usuário.. no meu ver não estava fora de contexto, o código funcionava perfeitamente, expliquei o que foi alterado/inserido, etc.

#### Obs

vale ressaltar que esta publicação não é para denegrir ninguém da comunidade, pelo contrário é para tornar tudo mais claro, pode ser que eu esteja errado, que tenha algum ponto que passou por mim despercebido, talvez.. não sei! só desejo entender o motivo.

Comment: "Resolver" o problema e ensinar a pessoa o mais correto são coisas bem distintas. Não posso falar porque recebeu negativos porque não fui um dos que deu. A dele ensina melhor. Se você acha que sua resposta está quase igual a não ser pelos comentários talvez os negativos sejam justificados, afinal há diferenças importantes na outra resposta que faz ela não só funcionar, como estar certa. Ela faz um *parse* na idade para não funcionar por coincidência. A sua não faz e pode ser isso que levou as pessoas negativarem. Você continua achando que isso não importa.

Comment: O AP geralmente é a pessoa menos indicada para dizer se algo está correto, se ele soubesse ele não precisaria perguntar. Tem um comentário meu tentando explicar isso para o AP e demais, mas parece que não surtiu efeito. Note que a outra resposta também recebeu negativo, então tinha alguém revoltado circulando por ali.

Comment: Provavelmente um ou mais dos downvotes foi devido a primeira versão da resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/511177/1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi, neste caso até as versões anteriores fazem diferença na resposta? tenho uma leve dificuldade ao revisa-la, por exemplo, acabou de publicar a resposta, re-leio ela e noto que falta algo, ai em seguida a edito, conforme isso vou formulando.. a partir de hoje só irei publicar quando no meu ponto de vista realmente estiver "esclarecida".

Comment: Bom, tem uma coisa que já falamos a anos aqui no site, não é porque você sabe resolver uma pergunta ruim que significa que ela mereça ser respondida, é algo bem complicado de entender de primeira, mas tem coisas que são erros de digitação simples, que nem valem para futuras perguntas, outras são esquivocos e por fim existem as mal elaboradas, que podem merecer respostas no futuro, se editadas. Então se a pergunta se enquadra em um possivel tipo de fechamento é melhor votar ou sinalizar para fechar e não responder, saber diferenciar os tipos de perguntas é importante.

Comment: O principal objetivo do Stack Overflow deve(ria) ser tornar o site em um repositório de conhecimento e não dar assistencialismo a qualquer errinho repetitivo, ou ficar depurando códigos gigantes ou incompletos ou improváveis de serem executados.

Comment: Compreendo, valeu a sua atenção de verdade mesmo isso acaba sendo bastante útil mesmo, a minha situação para insistir em dar respostas é mas a questão de me por no mesmo lugar e entender e já passei e passo por isso todos os dias, mas você mencionando isso faz com que eu pense que a pessoa que faz a pergunta deve cumprir o papel dela (aqui no site, seguindo os conceitos e regras)

Comment: @gleisin-dev lembrando que sempre pode editar e elaborar uma resposta já postada também. Com poucas linhas a mais dá pra explicar o que aconteceu entre os ( )s do console.log. Muitas vezes a diferença está nos detalhes, e não no tamanho da resposta.

Comment: entendi @Bacco obrigado a atenção e retornos, me atentarei das próximas vezes..

Comment: @Bacco e me desculpe as insinuações, meu objetivo nunca foi te ofender, apenas entender por um outro lado.. mas mesmo assim desculpe se acabei apontando algo, ofendendo você ou toda sua carreira/experiência aqui nas comunidades.

Comment: Eu disse o que eu disse com base na pergunta, acho justo me posicionar. Só é legal nas próximas se por do outro lado, pra evitar maus entendidos. Tem jeitos e jeitos de falar sobre as coisas né. Perguntar é bom, insinuar já fica esquisito, mas tomando por base o mecanismo todo do site, quase tudo tem espaço para diálogo e melhorias. Não precisa pedir desculpas (mas já estão aceitas, se fizer questão), e da minha parte nenhum ressentimento. Espero que da sua tambem não.

Comment: @gleisin-dev, não é verdade que sua pergunta não seja bem vinda na comunidade, na verdade agradecemos a sua contribuição e participação e aguardamos mais. Aqui no meta, os votos não tem a mesma conotação do site principal. Os votos no meta são uma demonstração de que você concorda ou não com o que foi dito, não tendo necessariamente relação com a qualidade, formato, utilidade, etc... mais informações podem ser obtidas em [Votos a favor e votos contra no META. O que o voto significa para você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4788/137387).

Comment: @gleisin-dev e mais caso você tenha dúvidas quanto ao posicionamento da comunidade sobre alguma de suas publicações, queira ajuda para identificar problemas em perguntas ou respostas, queira aprimorar algum de seus conteúdos, queira debater sobre um código, obter dicas/orientação ou apenas bater papo fique a vontade para usar [nossa sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: @AugustoVasques agradeço a disponibilização amigo! vai ser bastante útil..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto aqui é pra esclarecer alguns pontos, eu ia por em comentário, mas iria ficar confuso:

- *fui o primeiro a responde-la*

Velocidade de resposta é irrelevante para o site. O que importa é o conteúdo.

- *segundo o usuário, teria sanado seu "problema".*

Também é irrelevante. Não somos um helpdesk, é importante que o site seja um repositório de conhecimento para um público amplo.

- *Fiz uma pré-descrição explicando o que foi inserido e/ou removido do código para que pudesse funcionar de forma correta*

A única explicação que vi lá foi do ternário, que em nada tinha relação com o problema da pergunta.

- *porém 30min depois um dos Moderadores ou Usuário Antigo*

Aqui fica claro que você está condicionando a diferença de votos por isso (sendo que é um desvio do verdadeiro motivo da diferença), e isso me motivou a postar uma resposta aqui. Sobre os votos, tratarei disso logo a seguir.

- *fez basicamente a mesma resposta, inserindo apenas //comments no código e uma pré-descrição*

Não é a mesma resposta, inclusive chega a ser ofensiva a comparação. Eu respondi em cima do código original do autor, e detalhei tudo que era relevante ao problema original.

Você trocou coisas que em nada tinha a ver com o assunto, como o operador condicional, que chamou de ternário.

- *mencionando informações dadas por terceiro(a)s*

Sim, e com os devidos créditos. Mencionei só o que realmente importava, e concentrei numa resposta abrangente e detalhada

- *e, em seguida minha resposta recebeu -2 downvote*

Não. Um dos downs já estava antes de eu responder.

- *o "um dos" recebeu 4 votos a favor até então*

Aqui, novamente se esquiva de aceitar que sua resposta não está boa, e precisa atribuir o problema a outras pessoas, ou sugerir qualquer irregularidade. Se quiser fazê-lo, a rede tem o formulário de contato e a empresa pode investigar com tranquilidade. Insinuar aqui não é uma coisa agradável.

Fazendo como fez aqui, ganhou meu negativo no meta.

- *Minha questão é: O que diferencia a resposta dele pra minha? se pelo próprio autor da publicação foi válida e que comentou minha resposta, ela estando correta e de certa forma agradecendo por "ter funcionado", quer dizer, eu não só fiz colar um código que funcionasse, em minha pré-descrição citei onde estava localizado o problema e em seguida corrigi explicando.. (não detalhadamente, mas de forma compreensível e clara)*

Já explicado acima.

- *O que não entendo é o porquê recebi downvote*

Talvez por não cumprir o objetivo do site, fazer uma postagem estilo "helpdesk". Postou um código que só resolve o problema do autor, mas não serve para aprendizado. Tanto é que simplesmente o autor usou e agradeceu num intervalo de 4 minutos.

Da próxima sugiro gastar a energia da postagem aqui do meta na documentação do site, e tentar entender o objetivo da rede. Se produzir boas postagens terá meu voto também.

Inclusive, se dois downvotes em uma resposta duvidosa são motivo de postagem no meta, vai cansar de postar quando for "um dos" mais pontuados, pq downvote sem motivo aparente e sem explicação qualquer um de nós que tem muitas postagens recebe de monte. Ou você acha que comecei com mais pontos que você?

### Pra não deixar de dizer:

[Sou um dos primeiros do site a ter a medalha Espirito Esportivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship?userid=70) que é para aqueles que votam positivo em respostas concorrentes.

Inclusive, nessa aí teria tido positivo meu se eu achasse que valia. Na minha humilde opinião, o down não foi incorreto (mas nada é definitivo, você sempre pode editar o post elaborando, que a pergunta volta para o topo do site para todo mundo revisar votos e tudo o mais).

Espero ter esclarecido parte das dúvidas (mas não posso falar por todos votantes).

Comment: PS: mais um detalhe: desde que fui eleito moderador, parei de ganhar pontos praticamente, pq não dá tempo de ficar respondendo coisas. Ou seja, meus ups vieram bem antes do diamante. O diamante me atrapalha nisso, não ajuda. Tudo tem histórico, basta analisar.

Comment: Nada relacionado com o problema em discussão, mas agora que olhei de novo o ranking das medalhas, fico triste de ver que tão poucos ganharam a "espírito esportivo" em tantos anos de site, com essa quantidade de users.

Comment: Eu queria que tive a de ouro para o Espírito Esportivo que é proposta antiga que a SE não faz (é prioridade que "arredondar cantos" pra "melhorar a UX" do site). Se ele tivesse talvez não tivesse meia dúzia de usuários que ganhariam e todos que ganharia seriam os que se preocupam com o site.