# Stackoverflow não é uma boa opção para quem quer começar a programar!

Tags: debate

Quando resolvi tentar a sorte com programação, a questão que mais me incomodou foi: por onde começar?

Vejo muitas perguntas sobre "por onde começar" que recebem feedback negativo por induzir o utilizador a emitir uma opinião baseada na sua experiência de vida (programador tem vida???) e com toda razão, de acordo com os princípios do StackOverflow, é negativada/fechada.

A imagem que tenho em minha mente é de um boxeador profissional lutando contra uma criança, e sem misericórdia!

Negativar a pergunta não seria o mesmo que mostrar um cartão vermelho ao aventureiro?

Se por essas bandas não é permitido fazer esse tipo de pergunta , então aqui também não encontraremos respostas para elas, logo perdemos uma mar de possibilidades, pessoas experientes e capacitadas para ajudar o próximo Mark Zuckerberg a encontrar o seu caminho.

Todos nós começamos assim, seja em qualquer área, temos pelo menos uma fonte de informação, seja uma pessoa, um livro, um tutorial, etc... e Stackoverflow não pode de maneira alguma ser essa fonte porque não aceitamos perguntas do tipo.

**Update:**
A crítica não é sobre o sistema de votos e nem o que ele representa para a comunidade, mas sim o uso desnecessário. Vejo o downvotes com algo negativo para alguém que está começando e quer apenas uma opinião ou discuti-las com alguém. Veja esse [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111182/o-que-usar-no-primeiro-projeto-php), é um utilizador novo que recebeu votos negativos. Para quem já está acostumado com a comunidade é visto com bons olhos, um sinalizador de que algo está errado e precisa ser melhorado, mas não para um novato. Penso que o melhor seria fechar a pergunta e indicar a central de ajuda para que a sua participação na comunidade seja melhorada. De cara receber votos negativos não é solução.

Comment: Filipe Moraes, concordo que todos usuários novatos tem que ser bem-vindos. Mas esse  negócio de "deixar de negativar por dó" ou dar positivos por dó só vai fazer com que a pessoa não aprenda com os erros. Existem perguntas de iniciantes que são boas, e existem as que são ruins. Estamos avaliando as perguntas e não as pessoas (no caso, eu faço assim, mas infelizmente, nem todos fazem)

Comment: Amigo, quando iniciei na programação me surgiu várias dúvidas por onde começar também. Porem a questão é que você deve levar em consideração que o site stackoverflow é um site para tirar dúvidas específicas de programação e mantém suas regras específicas, não é um site para quem quer aprender programação. Acho que para começar você deva pensar em algum curso e quando tiver dúvidas e problemas específicos de programação para resolver pense em stackboverflow.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é deixar de negativar por dó e sim apenas esclarecer e fechar o tópico. Para quem está iniciando, isso pode ser levado para o lado pessoal e não pela qualidade da pergunta.

Comment: Por exemplo, perguntas como esta [Porque muitos recomendam C# sendo que é tão inseguro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111070/por-que-muitos-recomendam-c-sendo-que-%C3%A9-t%C3%A3o-inseguro)  tem que ser negativada para servir de exemplo como não se dever perguntar. Porque alguns usuários não leem o tour ou "como perguntar" quando entram pela primeira vez no site.

Comment: @MiguelBatista você diz: "é um site para tirar dúvidas específicas de programação e mantém suas regras específicas, não é um site para quem quer aprender programação...", logo não é um lugar para quem está iniciando e quer saber por onde começar, é para quem já tem pelo menos uma noção por onde ir!

Comment: [Contraponto](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3800/91)

Comment: E quem disse que devia ser? Chegou a ver escrito em algum lugar **Site de Tutoriais Para Novatos**?

Comment: @brasofilo nunca chamei o stackoverflow de "Site de tutoriais para novatos" e nem a pergunta leva a esse entendimento. A comunidade é para todos, de todos os níveis! A questão aqui é como alguém que posta pela primeira vez é recebido quando, seja por não entender o conceito tal como ele é, seja por não ter lido a central de ajuda, posta pedido de opiniões e como não sabemos se o problema é falta de leitura o má compreensão, bastava sinalizar a pergunta e indicar a central de ajuda. Negativa-lo pode sim ter uma má interpretação justamente por inicialmente não está claro o conceito.

Comment: Me lembro de quando comecei com Java, frequentava outros fóruns de língua portuguesa. Qualquer pergunta era arrogante e laconicamente respondida com um link para a especificação no site da Sun. Uma simples pergunta sobre o método split() e surgia um "expert" aconselhando a não ser preguiçoso e ler todo o javaDoc da classe String antes de fazer uma pergunta estúpida. Não é preciso dizer que hoje esses sites estão às moscas. Quando descobri o SO (inglês) nunca mais precisei me valer deles para obter ajuda. Hoje eu tenho o prazer de ajudar e instruir quem está começando

Comment: o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111182/o-que-usar-no-primeiro-projeto-php usado como exemplo ai deu pagina nao encontrada aqui

Comment: segue outro exemplo de uma pessoa nova aqui que já pensa em sair http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115117/matriz-5x5-com-portugol/115179?noredirect=1#comment240405_115179 porque já fez 4 perguntas e até agora o melhor indicador esta com zero, demais perguntas tudo negativada

Comment: @SneepSNinjA dei uma olhada no perfil desse utilizador e vi que alguns votos negativos realmente não fazem sentido, entretanto em relação a pergunta (que você colocou o link no seu comentário), eu concordo com os votos negativos, ele simplesmente pediu para alguém fazer o trabalho. Ele diz que o SOpt não parece uma comunidade e ele tem razão, o SOpt por si só não é uma comunidade, para ser tal depende do comportamento das pessoas que aqui frequentam...

Comment: @SneepSNinjA ...logo se torna uma comunidade quando os seus utilizadores se comportam de maneira adequada, ou seja, o comportamento dele esperando que outros resolvam o problema sem qualquer esforço (pelo menos é a ideia que tenho ao ler a pergunta) não colabora para que o SOpt seja uma comunidade, ele falhou na sua parte, tudo é questão de acão-reação. A questão aqui abordada é quando nós vemos um esforço da parte do utilizador, mesmo que esse esforço não esteja de acordo com as regras, mas ele - o esforço - existe e para esses tenho toda a paciência e vontade de ajudar.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes no link o rapaz queria "aprender" da para ver pela foto do perfil que a pessoa precisa de ajuda até para formular a pergunta, ele precisava de ajuda com a pergunta, de ajuda com o pseudo código e de ajuda com o algoritmo, e ninguém se propos a ajuda em ABSOLUTAMENTE NADA, não da para medir um esforço de pesquisa nesse caso porque no google não tem a resposta pronta como em muitos casos o tem, não da para julgar se o rapaz simplesmente transferiu a lição de casa para o SOPT ou se ele primeiro passou horas tentando entender sobre a lição, mas as pessoas o julgaram e down vote

Comment: o SOPT é uma ótima opção para quem esta começando aprender programação, sim, mas a pessoa não consegue se sentir bem aqui se não souber: gramatica, semântica, concordâncias, não contrariar um membro que tenha muitos pontos pois sofrerá efeito cascata de down vote, se alguém poderoso bater o martelo irá chover coxinhas votando junto com ele, mesmo se o que o poderoso disser seja algo passível de contestação, e acho que já mencionei isso, se o @Gabe usar uma conta fake de usuário comum poucos irão ouvir o que ele tem a dizer.

Comment: Minha sugestão é negativar somente a partir de 100pts de reputação. Até porque quase 100% das perguntas negativadas de novatos são fechadas.

Answer (score 39):

## O Stack Overflow é uma ótima opção para quem está começando aprender programação.

Claro que ele não é um curso, não é um tutorial, muito menos é um livro. Um site não vai substituir essas coisas. Mesmo que conseguisse, não deveria.

O SO não é uma boa opção para quem não consegue formular uma pergunta. O SO não é bom para pessoas que não tem domínio da sua própria língua, de conceitos matemáticos básicos (não estou falando de decorar fórmulas e regras), quem não consegue se expressar, quem não liga para comunidade e acha que regra boa é sua regra, ou quem só quer abusar da boa vontade das pessoas.

Praticamente nunca vi alguém aprendendo participar aqui de forma legítima e acontecer o que está sendo afirmado na pergunta. Pode ter acontecido um caso ou outro, mas que a comunidade se mexeu para consertar.

O que eu vejo muito são pessoas que **não conseguem participar de uma comunidade**, que **não conseguem se comunicar** tentando dar um de lutador de boxe sem saber lutar num lugar onde as pessoas não querem lutar.

E **não estou falando que ele não sabe programar**, esta falta de conhecimento é boa para o site, produz perguntas bem interessantes.

Negativar pergunta não é o mesmo que mostrar cartão vermelho para ninguém. Este tipo de mentalidade é que causa a dificuldade. O dia que as pessoas entenderem que o negativo é apenas uma forma de classificar conteúdo ruim e que pode ser melhorado, que não é algo pessoal, tudo ficará melhor.

É verdade que o sistema não colabora em informar isto mais claramente para as pessoas. Já falei várias vezes e a SE não parece estar interessante em melhorar a comunicação disto. A própria SE trata um pouco o negativo como algo ruim. Mas ela nem minimiza o problema, nem abole o negativo (o que seria algo bem ruim).

De que tipo de pergunta estamos falando? De perguntas simples, básicas, de iniciantes? Desde que elas sejam bem escritas elas são permitidas e até incentivadas aqui.

As escritas de qualquer jeito, que a pessoa não consegue dizer o que quer saber, ou quer opiniões sem sentido que não vão ajudá-la aprender nada, ou ainda que ela quer tudo pronto, quer que façam um tutorial completo para ela, de fato não encontra espaço aqui. Na verdade onde elas são feitas, costumam ficar às moscas ou recebem respostas tão ruins que era melhor que ninguém tivesse respondido.

Quando a pessoa quer ir contra tudo e contra todos, quando ela vem para lutar e não para aprender, o que ela vai conseguir é uma luta, não aprendizado.

Eu acho curioso que é comum essas pessoas pediram para dar a ela o que ela não dá para as pessoas quem podem lhe ajudar. Às vezes o discurso faz parecer que as pessoas estão aqui para ajudar como um trabalho remunerado ou uma punição.

As pessoas que vão fornecer ajuda só querem não ter que trocar a fralda da pessoa que pede ajuda. Quem quer ser ajudado tem que se ajudar primeiro, tem que mostrar que merece ajuda. As pessoas não tem boa vontade com quem não tem boa vontade. Mas as pessoas são tão despreparadas que não conseguem perceber isto, elas só conseguem olhar para o próprio umbigo. Elas não conseguem reconhecer a maravilha que está ocorrendo aqui e que ela vai desperdiçar a oportunidade se não souber conviver com isto.

O sistema não é perfeito mas foi muito bem pensado para atender bem quem realmente quer aprender do jeito certo. Espaço para aprendizes tem bastante, para aventureiros não tem muito não.

O Mark Zuckerberg sabe se comunicar muito bem. Ele sabe fazer as perguntas certas do jeito certo. Nem precisamos de pessoas com tanta capacidade (aqui que dê para discutir a capacidade dele), mas não dá para tentar arrumar solução para analfabetos funcionais ou teimosos ao extremo.

O sujeito só pode ter um caminho se ele se comprometer a aprender. E isto passa por saber razoavelmente (nem precisa um domínio completo) dos conhecimentos básicos que todos ser humano deve ter para conseguir viver em comunidade e trocar informações intelectuais.

Eu não sei qual é a solução definitiva, mas pessoas experientes e capacitadas estão perdendo muito tempo tentando guiar pessoas que não querem ou não tem capacidade de aprender. Elas primeiro precisam aprender a aprender.

Eu sei que algumas pessoas não vão gostar desta resposta, mas eu sou realista. O mundo não é cor-de-rosa.

Quem quiser, pesquisa todas as respostas que dou, a maioria são para novatos que não sabem o básico de programação (alguns até acham que sabem).

## Adendo após edição da pergunta

Eu vejo que o fechamento causa tanto ou mais problema quanto o negativo.

Se a pessoa quer opinião, discussão, será fechado mesmo.

É raro eu negativar o conteúdo de um usuário novato. Mas não tenho um critério claro sobre isto. Quando pode parar de tratá-lo diferente? Eu evito um pouco o tratamento diferenciado também, até porque é difícil administrar isto. No fim acaba criando outro tipo de confusão. Eu sei que daria para fazer melhor, mas é melhor não entrar nesse assunto.

Estamos aqui esperando a proposta de uma solução melhor.

Só estou respondendo em cima do que está escrito. Não consigo especular sobre as intenções da pessoa além do escrito. Acho que assim até funciona melhor.

Comment: Acho que fui mal interpretado, apesar de achar muito boa a sua resposta. Não estou criticando o excelente trabalho que toda a comunidade faz no stackoverflow, é magnífica e posso dizer que muito aprendi. O que acho crítico é a forma como é utilizado o botão negativo para pessoas que buscam orientação nos seus primeiros posts, não falo de pessoas que querem tudo na mão, mas alguém que realmente que correr atrás e se aventurar, não no sentido que foi colocado na sua resposta, mas de forma séria. Como tudo na vida, sem orientação de quem por lá passou, é sim uma aventura.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes aí temos um outro problema, é o dos votos em cascata.

Comment: achei uma ótima resposta e merece + 1.

Comment: O exemplo que utilizei de um lutador de boxe, não representa a comunidade mas sim o fato de usar votos negativos para quem busca orientação, um simples sinalizar para fechar é o bastante, negativar na minha opinião em nada ajuda e para quem está começando e não entende o significado disso, pode sim ser mal interpretado.

Comment: Existem negativos dados errados, mas normalmente é pelo exagero onde já foi negativado, mas é raro a pessoa ganhar negativo só porque ele não aprendeu ainda. Fora os poucos casos de erro (que não sei como resolver) só vejo negativos em coisas ruins mesmo. Em coisas que a pessoa não conseguiu ter uma pergunta respondível. Por mais que ela seja bem intencionada, e cada um tem uma definição do que é isto, se não dá para responder, tem que ser fechado. E negativado quando aqui não serve pra nada no site. Não vai ajudar nem mesmo os novatos.

Comment: Minha percepção é que muda pouco pra quem não conhece o site se está fechado ou não, se foi negativado ou não. O cara quer tudo do jeito dele, seja por ignorância, seja por arrogância. E ele não entende que o negativo e o fechamento não é uma punição pra ele. É onde entra a falta de informação do sistema. O sistema é muito 8 ou 80 também, mas isto é outro assunto. Quer ajudar sua pergunta? Mostre casos de novatos que fizeram boas perguntas e forma negativos.

Comment: Bigown a questão não é ser novato, talvez seja essa causa de ser mal interpretado. Estou a falar de um passo antes, de alguém que resolver iniciar e não sabe bem por onde começar. Todos nós começamos assim, seja em qualquer área, temos pelo menos uma fonte de informação, seja uma pessoa, um livro, um tutorial, etc... e stackoverflow não pode de maneira alguma ser essa fonte porque não aceitamos perguntas do tipo.

Comment: Se for isso, já foi discutido antes. Aqui não é lugar mesmo. Aqui é lugar para o caso da pessoa ter dado o primeiro passo. Embora de certa forma, cai no problema que eu falei. Quando a pessoa não consegue fazer uma pesquisa básica para achar informação mínima inicial, ele não vai conseguir aprender nada de programação que é muito mais difícil. Na minha época não tinha internet. Mal tinha livro sobre o assunto e a gente achava informação sem ajuda de ninguém. O que existe para que não sabe nada estão nas *tag wikis*. Mais que isso vai perguntar o que? Só imagino uma pergunta que cabe assim.

Comment: É que a pergunta obviamente está falando de outra coisa completamente diferente do que está nesse último comentário, se ela tivesse perguntado sobre isto, eu taria votado como duplicata porque isto já foi perguntado anates.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes a solução para esse tipo de coisa (perguntas opinativas, que solicitam experiencia)  é o chat, local mais informal na qual as pessoas expressão suas opiniões, O SO é o que sempre foi e sempre sera um local para duvidas concretas sobre um assunto especifico.

Comment: Se a realidade é que a maior parte das pessoas, principalmente que chega no site pela primeira vez, continua a ver downvotes como desmotivadores, não há nada de *realista* em insistir que a reação delas é errada, e que não há nada que possa ser feito pra melhorar a situação.

Comment: É tudo culpa do Facebook com aquele mundo onde "não gostei" não existe :P

Comment: @brasofilo mas aqui não é Facebook, uma pergunta não é um post aleatório e o downvote não pode representar de maneira nenhuma o nosso gosto pessoal. A culpa é somente de quem utiliza mal (e bem mal) o voto negativo.

Comment: cara, acho que alguns usuários aqui do so deveriam ser menos "grosseiros" nas suas respostas. O Filipe Moraes pelo que vi está apenas tentando esclarecer algo que não está claro para ele. Aí muitos ao invés de tentar ajudar com respostas objetivas e claras ficam tentando dar "lições" ou "tutoriais de como as coisas devem ser feitas". Parabéns por perguntas assim Filipe, elas acrescentam muito na mecânica no site. O Bigown é um dos exemplos que vejo que a comunidade tem de usuários prestativos que servem de molde para outros.

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva obrigado pelo incentivo Diego e obrigado também pela sua atitude!

Comment: bigow http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115117/matriz-5x5-com-portugol/115179?noredirect=1#comment240405_115179 achei uma boa pergunta, já era bem definida antes mesmo de edita-la, quando vejo uma pergunta desse tipo penso que 1-Novato em programação, 2-Novato na comunidade, 3-**Não sabe onde pisa** e a comunidade acaba desmotivando ele com os votos negativos, ninguém parece estar disposto a ajudar a pessoa a se ajudar, transformar essa pessoa em um bom colaborador do SOPT

Answer (score 25):

Pelo que li, acho que a pergunta toca num assunto um pouco diferente do que foi respondido até agora. Ao meu ver a pergunta é referente a alguns tipos de perguntas que são mais comuns e mais úteis para iniciantes, como os tais pedidos de "como começar" que o Filipe Morais citou, e que podem estar recebendo uma resposta firme demais da comunidade.

Um dos posts mais citados do Meta é o: [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/12).
A ideia por trás dele é que se o SOen fosse o bastante para atender à comunidade de língua Portuguesa, não precisaríamos do SOpt. E isso não é apenas uma questão de idioma.

Por um lado esse post é muito bem sucedido. Nós não corremos para adotar as mesmas regras, não nos prendemos a todos os modelos do SOen e nosso site teve a chance de se adaptar ao que a comunidade precisa.

Por outro lado, aquele post falhou - ao meu ver - em conseguir descreditar a ideia de que o SOpt *tem que virar isso, ou aquilo*. Não que fosse fácil, já que o Stack Overflow está sempre ali como uma lembrança do que é o sucesso. Mas crescer sem ter um destino bem definido, sem muita ideia do que ia acontecer foi um privilégio que o SOen teve, e que seria muito, muito proveitoso se nós nos permitíssemos ter o mesmo privilégio.

Digo isso porque a meu ver, o tipo de pergunta a que o @FilipeMoraes se refere ("por onde começar") já nasceu mal vista, aqui no SOpt. E acaba sofrendo a reação bem forte - de bastante downvotes atrelados ao fechamento, como ele sugere [nesse comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818#comment15951_4819). Não acho que essas perguntas sejam mal vistas, e tenham esse destino, por infrigirem alguma regra do site. Acho que elas são rechaçadas por não se encaixarem no "arquétipo" que temos do que o site deveria ser - que é profundamente derivado do que o SOen é **hoje**, e ignora muito do que o SOen **já foi**, para atender às necessidades da sua comunidade à época.

É difícil discordar do que o @bigown disse. Algumas pessoas tentam complicar ao máximo sua participação site. Algumas vão criar problemas, algumas não vão se adaptar. Algumas pessoas vão abusar ao máximo da boa vontade de todos vocês. Todo mundo aqui já viu um usuário assim, e ficou perplexo com a falta de dedicação, ou compreensão, ou até respeito, que alguém pode ter pelas pessoas que **estão tentando ajudar**.

Mas já não sei se concordo com a afirmação dele de que [são poucos os casos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818#comment15952_4819) em que uma pergunta respondível recebe downvotes. Então [fui olhar os dados](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt)!

- **Número de perguntas no site:** [36883](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/431504/numero-total-de-perguntas)
- **Número de perguntas negativadas:** [1193](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/431503/numero-total-de-perguntas-negativas)
- **Número de perguntas negativadas com pelo menos 1 resposta positiva:** [793](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/431512/perguntas-negativas-com-pelo-menos-1-resposta-positiva)

E, realmente, perguntas negativadas com boas respostas são só uns 2% do total de perguntas que temos... Mas representam um alarmante 66% de todos os casos de perguntas negativadas. Isso não é raro, nem pouco. Dois terços das perguntas que parte da comunidade considera ruim tem respostas bem recebidas por outra parte da comunidade. A [lista de respostas](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/431516/lista-de-respostas-positivas-em-perguntas-negativas) tem algumas que ninguém em sã consciência consideraria ruim.

Então o que está acontecendo? De onde vem essa dissonância entre o que consideramos digno de resposta e o que consideramos bom? Com um número tão grande e tão frequente de casos, faz sentido acusar algum grupo de iniciantes que "não sabe como o site funciona"?

É algo que nós precisamos começar a pensar à respeito, e procurar uma solução. Não podemos nos esconder atrás de "isso já foi discutido antes". Uma comunidade não pode simplesmente se dar por satisfeita com uma decisão tomada no passado, e deixar buscar novas maneiras de melhorar. Se fosse pra ser assim, o Meta não existiria. O Stack Overflow não existiria...

Como a [Ana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17/ana) disse esses dias no [SciFi SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8086/16777) (sobre sinalizações de chat, mas o princípio se aplica aqui:

> Um grupo que está constantemente reavaliando suas normas -- a maneira como eles se comportam como um todo -- é sinal de uma comunidade saudável. Comunidades só funcionam bem se seus membros tiverem a oportunidade de influenciar todo o conjunto.
>
> [...]
>
> Sinalizações nunca são o problema, ou a solução. Elas sempre representam uma oportunidade de melhorar enquanto comunidade.

Acho que temos uma situação parecida. Nosso site está mandando um sinal bem claro de que talvez não estejamos fazendo todo o necessário para atender à nossa comunidade da melhor maneira possível. E atender às necessidades da comunidade da melhor maneira possível é a razão do Stack Overflow existir.

Não acredita em mim? Eis como o [Joel Spolsky apresentou a ideia do Stack Overflow ao mundo](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html), em 2008:

> Pelo visto programadores não lêem mais livros. O mercado de livros de programação é minúsculo se comparado ao número de programadores.
>
> Ao invés disso, seguem programando por tentativa-e-erro e, quando não conseguem resolver alguma coisa, vão pesquisar no Google.

Esse é o **motivo** da nossa existência. Entender que as coisas mudam, e as necessidades mudam com elas. E que programadores não tem mais que ler esse ou aquele livro, ou passar dias trancafiado numa biblioteca - como eu fiz, porque sou velho o suficiente pra isso - pra conseguir acessar o melhor conhecimento.

Se você quer mesmo que a nova geração de programadores aprenda direito, o melhor a fazer não é se preocupar com o quão preguiçosos eles são ou deixam de ser, mas em ter certeza de que eles têm as melhores soluções pras suas perguntas. **Boas respostas** fazem a diferença.

E atualmente nós estamos desperdiçando diversas **boas respostas**, por que não gostamos de quem fez a pergunta. Acho que precisamos conversar sobre isso.

Comment: Quando vim trabalhar na Atlassian todos me disseram que leva pelo menos 6 meses para se acostumar com o básico do trabalho. Um dos donos disse que em média leva um ano para se tornar um funcionário produtivo. Tudo isso se deve à carga cognitiva que você precisa absorver em um ambiente muito complexo e eles entendem isso. Infelizmente, aqui muitas vezes nós estamos querendo que os usuários consigam aprender tudo sobre o site desde o primeiro contato deles.

Answer (score 13):

Eu consigo compreender sua frustração e, infelizmente, isso tem sido um problema para a comunidade e que muitas vezes passa despercebido pelos usuários mais antigos.

Percebo que nosso site está tendo alguma dificuldades em receber novos usuários e alguns às vezes demonstram ter a impressão de que é quase uma comunidade fechada.

É algo que pode ser praticamente invisível, passar totalmente despercebido, mas sinto que nossa comunidade poderia ser bem maior (sem perder a qualidade) se houvessem leves mudanças de atitude de todos nós.

Note que não estou apontando possíveis culpados nem soluções, mas posso adiantar que os moderadores estão, em consenso, preocupados com isso.

Por outro lado, minha opinião pessoal é que o problema é acentuado no nosso site porque, na média, brasileiros tem um pouco mais de dificuldade em aceitar críticas (comentários ou votos negativos) e mais facilidade de falar o que dá na telha, o que deixa as pessoas chateadas com mais frequência.

## Carga cognitiva

Quando comecei a trabalhar na Atlassian todos me disseram que levaria pelo menos 6 meses para se acostumar com o básico do trabalho. Um dos donos disse que em média leva um ano para se tornar um funcionário produtivo.

Tudo isso se deve à carga cognitiva que os novatos precisam absorver em um ambiente muito complexo e em mudança constante. Todos entendem isso e os gerentes e colegas são bastante pacientes. É algo reconhecido em todos os níveis.

Infelizmente, aqui no SOpt muitas vezes nós estamos esperando que os usuários consigam aprender tudo sobre o site desde o primeiro contato deles.

Eu sei que muitos não fazem nem o tour, muito menos lêem os tópicos "Como perguntar" ou "Como responder". Porém, como já aprendi, esse tipo de introdução **não é nem de perto suficiente** para compreender como realmente o site funciona na prático.

Lembre de quando você mudou de emprego pela última vez. Quanto tempo levou para se sentir confortável no novo ambiente?

Minha sugestão é:

> **Considere os novatos do site como seus novos colegas de trabalho!**

Antes de negativar ou ser "duro" com alguém ao ver uma pergunta ou resposta ruim, clique ali no nome do usuário e veja há quanto tempo ele está no site, quanto ele tem de reputação, quantas perguntas e repostas ele já fez, etc.

Então, nivele sua atitude de forma proporcional. Usuários com alguma pontuação ou contato frequente geralmente vão encarar melhor votos negativos e críticas, no mínimo eles vão fazer algum barulho aqui no Meta.

Por outro lado, usuários que nunca "arriscaram" perguntar ou responder provavelmente serão muito mais sensíveis a qualquer atitude ou comentário.

Comment: Vejo o downvotes com algo negativo para alguém que está começando e quer apenas uma opinião ou discuti-las com alguém. Veja esse exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111182/o-que-usar-no-primeiro-projeto-php é um utilizador novo que recebeu votos negativos. Para quem já está acostumado com a comunidade é visto com bons olhos, um sinalizador de que algo está errado e precisa ser melhorado, mas não para um novato. Penso que o melhor seria fechar a pergunta e indicar a central de ajuda para que a sua participação na comunidade seja melhorada. De cara receber votos negativos não é solução

Comment: Sei que no mundo perfeito, todos deveriam ler a central de ajuda antes de postar seja o que for, mas infelizmente não é o que acontece, mas também negativa-lo não ajuda a melhorar a questão, pelo menos para esses que estão mesmo a começar!

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Mas Não custa nada pro usuário novo ir no help e da uma lida no tour. Eu quando entrei no site, primeiro fiquei feliz por ver que era so todo em português e que não precisaria usar tradutor, segundo fui ver como funcionava de fato. Alias, todo forum que entrei até hoje, sempre vou primeiro nas regras ou observo um tempo como funciona. O fato da pessoa não ir no help quando o site é praticamente inteiro em português é preguiça, olha a cultura do brasileiro, que quase nunca lê manual de nada. Um pouco mais de boa vontade e os downvotes seriam evitados.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Acho que você está certo. Algumas pessoas negativam e também votam para fechar, o que na minha opinião é algo redundante e desnecessário.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe concordo, a preguiça só morre de fome! Mas o Stackoverflow é um conceito diferente, é algo novo (pelo menos em português) que pode ser mal compreendido. O problema é que não sabemos se a origem do problema é falta de leitura da central de ajuda ou se é uma má interpretação da mesma. Logo negativar alguém que teve o trabalho de ler mas que compreendeu mal é um mal começo!

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Concordo com você, mas se isso está se tornando um problema recorrente, então nós também precisamos mudar. Não podemos ter a mentalidade de que se funciona para alguns tem que funcionar para todos.

Comment: Outra coisa, StackOverFlow não é livro, não é professor, não é blog, não é fórum, não é video-aula, não é apostila, não é gerente, não é faculdade. Se o aventureiro quer ser programador, ele não o será fazendo uma pergunta, nem 10 nem 100, mas sim quando estudar [Ciência da computação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: A comunidade tem regras. A pergunta mencionada aqui é ampla, não tem como você fugir disso. Você já leu as regras? A regra é clara, se tem muitos negativos, algo está errado. Existem inúmeras discussões sobre esse voto negativo, em vários contextos. A resposta do @bigwon está clara, o cidadão tem que ter o mínimo de entendimento do que ele está fazendo. Existem perguntas amplas, pergunta fora do escopo, perguntas entendíveis. E outra coisa, até velho de casa quando faz pergunta sem lógica, recebe negativo

Comment: @durtto ter no currículo ciência da computação não faz de niguém um programador. Não desmereço que o fez, mas achar que é ou que é mais do que os outros apenas por um curso, é uma mentalidade lamentável. A questão aqui não são pessoas que não respeitam regras mas sim pessoas que podem perceber mal o conceito dessa comunidade e isso é comum. Como não sabemos se é uma má compreensão ou apenas preguiça, sinalizar a pergunta e indicar a central de ajuda seria sim uma boa alternativa. O downvote para alguém que posta pela primeira vez é totalmente desnecessário.

Answer (score 8):

> Vejo muitas perguntas sobre "por onde começar"

É verdade, há muitas, e boa parte delas poderia ser respondida com a mesma resposta. Seria uma resposta genérica, sobre os caminhos possíveis para se começar a aprender. Provavelmente seria tão genérica que uma parte da resposta se aplicaria a como começar a aprender qualquer coisa, não só a programar. Se uma resposta assim existisse no site, várias perguntas poderiam ser fechadas como duplicata dela.

Eu acho que seria bom ter uma resposta assim no site, mantida pela comunidade. Isso pode até ser artificial: criamos uma pergunta com resposta wiki e todos trabalhamos na resposta para deixá-la redonda e atualizada. Mas se a comunidade achar que não encaixa, podia ser em outro lugar também. Seria importante ter algum link pra quem faz a pergunta, e um link que "todo mundo" conhecesse e disseminasse.

Não vou entrar na discussão sobre negativos e fechamento porque acho que já foi discutido bastante, aqui e em outras discussões do meta. Quem sabe em outro momento, em outro post. Só quis propor um caminho que pode ajudar os novatos que têm esse tipo de pergunta – geralmente bem vaga e com pressupostos equivocados.

Comment: Acho a sugestão bem similar ao esquema de usar o tag-wiki para informações generalizadas, ou canônicas, sobre um assunto. Acredito que pode funcionar. Só temos que ficar atentos a qual seria o escopo dessa "resposta geral sobre como começar", pra que ela não acabe lentamente numa resposta única pra tudo

Comment: @Gabe com a diferença que seria bem mais visível que um tag wiki.

Comment: Yep. Por isso acho uma ótima ideia

Answer (score -3):

Ao analisar, principalmente, a versão norte americana do stackOverflow (onde achei por bem excluir minha conta), percebo que a comunidade (de lá pelo menos) é uma comunidade com um alto grau de arrogância e intolerância a quem sabe menos. Basta uma palavra "errada" , e você já presencia uma torrente de comentários com o intuito de inflar seus próprios egos e "humilhar com categoria (muitas vezes com baixaria)" a pessoa com dúvida.

Eu me pergunto: Qual o intuito desta comunidade ? 
 seria criar uma "elite dos sabe tudo" e excluir sumariamente todo o resto ? Ou se tornar um lugar receptivo para os que tem dúvidas, fazendo uso de sua capacidade de categorizar para criar um "faq" eficiente e, ao mesmo tempo, aceitar todo o tipo de dúvida , com respeito a instrução de cada um ? Pois para mim parece a primeira e, de fato, parece se tratar de uma comunidade fechada ( no caso, que tende a se fechar). Eu acho que toda a dúvida é bem vinda e que o respeito é uma obrigação.

Eu particulamente evito ao máximo recorrer ao stackOverflow (seja de qualquer país) pois percebo esse traço de arrogância e intolerância em todos. Mas as vezes nossas dúvidas não estão solucionadas em lugar nenhum e nos vemos na obrigação de levantar a questão (seja ela desde profissionalmente relevante até as dúvidas mais fundamentais e meras curiosidades interessantes). Tento não usar o stack pois ele me deixou com trauma, mas de vez em nunca posto a dúvida aqui na versão brasileira que até o momento foi mais receptiva e educada nas interpelações.

Answer (score -11):

Bem, este é um site profissional.

Imagine um StackOverflow para médicos ou advogados. Não seria errado que os membros presumissem que os demais integrantes estejam no mínimo cursando Medicina ou Direito há um bom tempo, ou que já sejam médicos ou advogados. Perguntas do tipo "estou com dor de cabeça, o que eu faço?" ou "Quero me separar e tirar todos os bens do meu marido/minha esposa" não seriam muito bem aceitas.

Comment: Esse não é um site profissional. É um site sobre programação, para programadores, de todos os níveis ou graus de interesse.

Comment: "presumir" é uma estratégia complicada pra ser usada na Internet... bom, na vida real também...

Comment: ué minha gente estou enfadado de ler que temos que ter paciência com os mais novos, e agora o rapaz toma 13 down por expor sua "sugestão" do motivo que isso acontece, pode ser que não seja esse o verdadeiro motivo ok, mas a ausência de votos já indicaria isso, o down deveria ser menos usado nesse caso, primeiro porque ele não esta fora de contexto tem verdades implícitas na resposta, apesar de não ser um "site profissional" a parábola ilustra uma realidade entre algumas pessoas da comunidade sim, mesmo que minoria, mas existem pessoas com exatamente essas atitudes da parábola postada.

Comment: Outro dia, alguém perguntou no SO: "porque o Facebook tava lento?". Definitivamente não é uma pergunta pertinente à profissão, e ninguém pode dizer que negativar uma pergunta como essa seria sintoma de antipatia com novatos.

Comment: Programação não é uma profissão? Pode ser que não seja regulamentada (nem deve ser!), pode ser que haja muitos amadores praticando (o que é ótimo), mas um pouco de respeito pela atividade vai bem.