# Stack Overflow é um bom lugar para se estudar?

Tags: debate

Já faz algum tempo em que eu estou entrando no SOpt quase todos os dias, e o acompanho por algumas horas. E recentemente comecei a frequentar o Meta. Por conta desses dois fatos, eu reparei que existe um certa tensão entre os usuários que querem uma resposta e os usuários que querem aprender/ensinar/melhorar.

E também andei reparando no esclarecimento das perguntas e respostas, que muitas das vezes não são tão claros assim.

A questão é que eu visito todos os dias com o intuito de aprender, já que não trabalho mais com desenvolvimento, mas também não quero ficar longe desse universo.

Então, levando em consideração as falhas de perguntas e repostas, e levando em considerações as discussões do Meta, eu me pergunto. **O SO é um lugar saudável e bom para se aprender? Ou é apenas um lugar para se buscar ajuda?**

Comment: Relacionado (leia a resposta do @Maniero): [Stackoverflow não é uma boa opção para quem quer começar a programar!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818/stackoverflow-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-uma-boa-op%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-quem-quer-come%c3%a7ar-a-programar)

Comment: Eu diria que é um dos melhores, se não o melhor, lugar para se estudar, sem tirar o mérito de professores e livros, obviamente. Outras fontes de pesquisa você terá que confiar quase que cegamente no autor. Uma publicação em um blog, por exemplo, não dá ferramentas para avaliação e réplica, então quase que se tem o conteúdo como verdade absoluta. No SOpt há centenas de pessoas que utilizam e entendem do assunto em questão que colaboram para gerar o melhor conteúdo possível (isso no mundo ideal, pelo menos).

Comment: Sim, eu concordo com você @Woss, o que eu me questiono é se a falta de esclarecimento das perguntas ou respostas pode fazer com que a pessoa que está iniciando possa entender e/ou aprender as coisas de forma equivocada. Como respostas corretas mas que usam códigos de 10 anos atrás, elas estão certas mas ultrapassadas. Isso seria saudável para quem está iniciando? Pois ele vai assumir que as coisas são feitas daquela forma.

Comment: @Sumback Seria ingênuo dizer que isso não ocorre no site, claro, mas a plataforma dá ferramentas para que se contorne isso. Há por exemplo, um tipo de recompensa que pode ser oferecida solicitando a atualização das respostas. "Mas um usuário iniciante não saberá que está desatualizada", pois é, por isso que a participação da comunidade é importante. Hoje sofremos em diversos pontos porque somos poucos usuários (no total), menos ainda os que são ativos e menos ainda² os que sabem ser ativos com qualidade. Isso não deve tirar o mérito da plataforma.

Comment: O site é um repositório de conhecimento, definitivamente não é um site de ajuda. Isto deveria ser melhor destacado, muita gente chega e confunde o site com helpdesk (aqui a postagem tem que servir para várias pessoas, o objetivo não é simplesmente satisfazer o autor da pergunta). Em outras palavras, é um "site **que** ajuda", não "**de** ajuda". Mesmo a pessoa não tendo postagens fechadas, uma lida no [Guia de Sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) é bem esclarecedora (para todos os usuários, não só os novos).

Comment: @Sumback é o que mais reclamo. Tem muita coisa ruim, até aqui, eu concordo com o Woss, mas isso vale mais para o conteúdo antigo, o novo é menos confiável, tem casos, mas em geral não é mais avaliado como antes, os bons profissionais daqui quase sumiram ou reduziram a atividade. Mas é verda quem tem gente que odeia o SO porque ele dá esse poder, tem muita gente que quer ser a verdade absoluta, não quer ser criticado (adequadamente). Já tive debate com pessoas que não gostam do SO e no fundo eles dizem isto mesmo, não com essas palavras porque fica claro que eles são os vilões :D

Comment: Mas não acho que seja um lugar pra estudar, é pra ajudar estudar. A fonte primária deve ser outra e aí vir aqui pra solidificar, questionar, continuar o estudo. Livros ainda deveriam ser a fonte primária. Algumas das melhores perguntas qui é alguém questionando o livro. Claro pessoas sem noção não vão gostar daqui. Isso é outro problema, não sei se é o foco desta pergunta, até porque aí acho que seria duplicata. Tem um ponto importante, aqui ajuda muito estudar, mas não ser o estudo como um todo e não para resolver problemas que a pessoa não consegue até porque não quer estudar.

Comment: @Maniero Então, para concluir, o que seria melhor, uma reposta eficiente ou uma reposta didática? (A eficiente não "ensina", mas mais pessoas tem "condições" de responder. E a didática "ensina", mas ai ficaria nas mãos de quem é mais especialista e/ou experiente no assunto. Isso, ao meu ver)

Comment: Acho que depende, cada pergunta tem um contexto.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente aprendi e ainda aprendo muito respondendo perguntas e lendo outras respostas, primeiro no SOen, depois aqui. Concordo com o Maniero que não é um lugar para "estudar" (as fontes primárias devem ser outras, como ele disse), mas certamente pode ser um ótimo lugar para se aprender (digo "pode" porque aí depende do estilo de cada um).

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, concordo. Mas quando alguém faz alguma pergunta colocando só o código e o erro, e a resposta é só outro código com a solução e marcado como resolvido, fica um pouco complicado de entender. Eu mesmo vejo várias respostas aceitas sem nem entender o que elas fazem.

Comment: @Sumback O que eu quero dizer é que existe como aprender aqui. Que existe também conteúdo ruim, existe, até em maior quantidade que conteúdo bom. Mas aí já é outra discussão :)