# Qual a etiqueta para lidar com usuários que fazem muitas perguntas?

Tags: debate

Antes de qualquer coisa, nada contra quem faz muitas perguntas. Isto é um demonstrativo de que a pessoa está buscando conhecimento e tal.

Mas e se o usuário faz muitas perguntas, dando a entender que ele encara o SO como um local que vai resolver todo e qualquer problema que ele tiver? Tenho percebido que alguns usuários que postam perguntas na [tag r](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) possuem este comportamento. Eu não tenho provas disso, mas parece que eles tem uma ideia do que querem e, sem ao menos tentar resolver o problema ou fazer alguma pesquisa mais detalhada, vem ao site para que a comunidade resolva para eles.

Portanto, minha pergunta é o que fazer em casos assim? Atualmente tenho ignorado perguntas reiteradas dos mesmos usuários, o que não é difícil de fazer numa tag de nicho como [r](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Mas será que a melhor saída seria educar o usuário para que ele mostrasse algum esforço para resolver o problema? Em caso afirmativo, como isto poderia ser feito?

Ou isto que relatei acima é *pet peeve* meu? Não é um problema em si, mas apenas uma coisa que eu particularmente acho que não deveria ser feita?

Comment: Tem uns caras aqui que postam no site antes mesmo de abrir a IDE.

Comment: Eu não vejo problema. Principalmente se forem questões um pouco mais conceituais e genéricas. O SOen ajudou na centralização da informação. Se você tem uma pergunta sobre programação é bem possível que você encontre respostas de forma fácil no StackOverflow. Estamos conseguindo centralizar essa informação aqui no SOpt. Até as duplicatas - em parte - tem sua importância.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Toda pergunta deve ser analisada individualmente. É inclusive bom dissociar a pergunta de seu autor, para não corrermos o risco de fazer um pré-julgamento.

Se a pergunta é boa e pode ajudar muitas pessoas, independente de o autor ser uma pessoa esforçada e interessada ou apenas um *code monkey* muito inquisitivo, ela deve receber votos positivos. Mas se a pergunta é ruim, tanto faz se ela foi feita pelo Derpino Augusto que começou a faculdade ontem ou pelo Jon Skeet, ela deve ser negativada.

Agora, o que torna uma pergunta ruim? Você falou em esforço, portanto, note que o botão de voto negativo tem como título HTML o seguinte, ênfase minha:

> Esta pergunta **não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa**; ela não é clara ou não é útil

Baseado nisso, e se utilizarmos apenas este filtro básico para decidir como votar, coisas boas vão acontecer:

- As boas perguntas irão ajudar muitas outras pessoas, fazendo com que a rede cresça e tenhamos mais gente por aqui se ajudando.
- As más perguntas receberão muitos votos negativos, e quem as faz será automaticamente bloqueado pelo sistema e impedido de fazer novas perguntas.

Simples assim. Se quiser ajuda para votar nessas perguntas, acho válido trazer um conjunto delas para discutir no Meta, para que o efeito Meta atue sobre elas.

Comment: Eu estava encarando as más perguntas como no SO, porém após ler [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com) - que não é atualizada desde 2014 - comecei a responder perguntas que não possuem duplicatas, mesmo as que não mostram nenhum esforço de pesquisa. Pois pensei que o SOpt deve criar uma base de conhecimento grande o suficiente e atrair mais membros antes de limitar algumas perguntas. Porém, algumas tags estão caminhando nesta direção mais rapidamente do que outras... Talvez seja assunto de outra pergunta Meta...

Comment: Infelizmente o voto está perdendo a credibilidade como parametro pra indicar qualidade ou falta dela, tem algumas perguntas mal formuladas, mal acentuadas e confusas que recebem votos positivos quase que instantaneamente após negativarmos. Tem muita gente tratando o upvote como "like" e isso é ruim para o site.

Comment: @Articuno e o pior: o site tem um mecanismo que faz com que muitas postagens negativas do mesmo autor em seguida disparem um _trigger_  com uma mensagem solicitando mais capricho e dando um intervalo de tempo para o autor postar novamente. Só que aqui, o voto "assistencial" (pra não ser indelicado) simplesmente acabou com esse recurso.

Comment: Façam uso do efeito meta, pessoal. Tragam as perguntas até aqui para dar visibilidade e a comunidade votar nelas.